# Tips for golfing in C++

Tags: code-golf, tips, c++

What general tips do you have for golfing in C++?

I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to C++ (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

(Tips that apply to C as well can be found in [Tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2203) - but note that some C tips don't work in C++.  For example, C++ *does* require function prototypes and return values.)

Comment: Many of the [tips for golfing in C](/q/2203) are also applicable to C++, so please assume that readers are familiar with that question; only post here if you have something that isn't also a valid C golfing tip.

Comment: @TobySpeight Probably because they have the same url besides the question ID.

Comment: C and C++, even if not 'golfing' type, are right and easy (if one consider the right subset of C++)

Answer (score 29):

The ternary conditional operator `?:` can often be used as a stand in for simple `if`--`else` statements at considerable savings.

It is of special value in that it can be used to select alternate lvalues as in

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(int c, char**v){
  int o=0,e=0,u;
  while(--c) ((u=atoi(v[c]))%2?o:e)+=u;
  std::cout << "Sum of odds " << o <<std::endl
            << "Sum of evens " << e <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Replace `std::endl` with `'\n'` that saves 5 chars

Comment: @MukulKumar Well, yes. But for the purposes of demonstrating *this* tip I left everything except the ternary-conditional un-golfed for clarity.

Comment: But `std::endl` isn't "ungolfed", it's just bad style / gratuitous flushing of `cout` even when that's not needed.  `endl` is the same as `<< '\n'` plus a flush; it's a different layer of stdio that handles conversion from `\n` to the native platform line ending (e.g. CRLF on DOS) for text streams.  If you were golfing or optimizing, you'd put the first `\n` into the 2nd string literal: `"\nSum of evens "`

Answer (score 28):

Sometimes you can save two characters by using the fact that static storage duration variables (that especially includes all global scope variables) are automatically zero-initialized at the beginning (unlike automatic variables where you have no such guarantee). So instead of

```
int main()
{
  int a=0;
  // ...
}
```

you can write

```
int a;
int main()
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Some compilers (e.g. GCC) support [multi-character constants](https://web.archive.org/web/20161010172930/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2(v=vs.80).aspx). This can save a few characters when a large integer value is required. Example:

```
int n='  ';
```

The value is implementation-specific. Usually the value of `'ab'` is `256*'a'+'b'` or `'a'+256*'b'`. You can specify up to 4 characters between the quotation marks.

Answer (score 20):

## Shorter header

This is GCC specific, it may be extensible to other compilers.

#### Precompiled header.

In G++ `bits/stdc++.h` is the precompiled header consists of all other headers. If you need to `import` 2 different ones you can just use this.

#### Shorter header.

This is all headers listed on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header:

```js
$("#a").text(pako.inflate(atob('eJx9VkuW1DAM3HON2cOGx4o3V8lzK0q3wZ9gy90TTo+dDKCyM710yT9VqWS/2ECuzPzdhO3108vfUeCHGmUWNfJmVSMbsxo5m/VUEutZjaWsTo9NSkYfO/OvouNZDP1U4xqFOHkjNzVORmzU8YXDXcf5ym86lSIwvljBXOmWYtA7evYxbXCEi0aAAl930TM4JdiDSLYV0njQzSQNlA7Ikmy4KuDOJDFB6mGOHoVZHrPeNMsM7LhIBuWQ6C1pvW6Jjd5jKVKSXtII/qwlaIoA0EoAgHYPZy+A2GswDhCWH37tVpmkKShinZWtmzPzomkyyZoAika/GkiBRsUaU7jK5MxJULNexUGkdpaDAgvFcwKKq2Eqx1q4OCDLgOQBsdGbYIGxQV+KM9NdnmvRsgK99vIFZC95QPbSAmSvYEAeA0Jy7QxMNsdvX789RdoFbVh0Jce1+r6roHoYRXC/Fa4NAlxzN67vQXbk/xAfrn7UDEI73UjLXsUI7aXek1cru4dqIQ8Uh4H1Kl4HtRrseB8kpbEyDylg1sH84N1LjG6QY4bNqN604dpU/Ea8y4QJHLAm211jsnLzsJapDGvTaIsduBTdAt5TxTTOsCaDq+rg/Vq2WPwl0FBteQs02tY6zlsWBp++MzNUQDsaG2edNkky2JsOgae7xRe6brA3b9x2P3yqBoaiX2J6mDRP3WOdq2N4nvo3sYSYZm4RfBr/4/ghOF7IKXGOJRFD6lZszfM3p+FsimvdybhmIrQov621ZXoOYtwX/KVACG8BIbw4hPoPSwyzbepO+8txgfYJC/uvCgT7fwgGu08IBPsfEgSH3whEh7cZ6ek/LshQ/3RBdPhsQHR80yA8PtMQPmndqPhpO9Bpn7msI+bEsSfp96ZCYU7diOec+wpPOrckMvaBsz6Y9KS6//Xcp3f62LHdZu9NeFqjs7S9/gHXxXg4'), {to: 'string'}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nodeca/pako/master/dist/pako.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="a">
  
</pre>
```

sorted in increasing order of length.

Some of them are already longer than `bits/stdc++.h`, and some of them requires C++17 support. Some others are not supported by TIO G++ (for reasons I don't know of). Filter out them we have:

```js
$("#a").text(pako.inflate(atob('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'), {to: 'string'}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nodeca/pako/master/dist/pako.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="a">
  
</pre>
```

It may happens that some of them can be replaced by shorter ones. Just binary search whether the one you need can be replaced. In particular:

```cpp
cstdio -> ios        (-3 bytes)
algorithm -> regex   (-4 bytes)
vector -> queue      (-1 byte)
string -> map        (-3 bytes)
bitset -> regex      (-1 byte)
numeric -> random    (-1 byte)
```

Comment: I wish I could star answers. This is good.

Comment: The stack snippet seems broken

Answer (score 17):

One that I found handy:

Taking advantage of the fact that non-zero values evaluate to `true` in boolean expressions, and that `x&&y` evaluates to `x*y` when dealing with booleans

```
(x!=0 && y!=0)
```

evaluates to

```
(x*y)
```

You just have to be aware of overflows, as pointed out below.

Comment: Technically, it's `x!=0 && y!=0`. But when using multiplication you need to be careful with overflows. When using 32-bit integers *x = y = 65536* (and several other combinations of powers of two) would also yield *x\*y = 0*.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I used it as a twodimensional array bounds check here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37571/31477 where that didn't matter.  I'll edit those points in.

Comment: Note however that `&&` has a short-circuit behaviour which `*` lacks. For example, you can't replace `i++!=0&&j++!=0` with `i++*j++`.

Comment: @celtschk yes, good point.  But if you're purely doing the boolean algebra, then it works

Comment: @S.S.Anne the point is you can use `x*y` saving a character.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using `while(1)`, use `for(;;)`, saving one character :)

Answer (score 13):

When possible, change `&&` and `||` to `&` and `|` respectively.

When using simple if statements:

```
if(<condition>)<stuff>;
```

can be changed to:

```
<condition>?<stuff>:<any single character variable or literal>;
```

which saves a character.

Answer (score 12):

Using the comma operator in lieu of open and close braces can save a few characters, if you have a situation where your clauses have more than one statement in them:

```cpp
if(c){x=1;cout<<"Hi";y=2;}else{x=2;cout<<"Bye";y=3;}
```

vs.

```cpp
if(c)x=1,cout<<"Hi",y=2;else x=2,cout<<"Bye",y=3;###
```

Two characters saved on a plain IF, or three total for an IF/ELSE.

As a point of distinction between C and C++, the result of a comma expression in C++ as a whole may be used as an lvalue...FWIW.

Comment: How about `x=1,y=2/*...*/else x++,y++`?

Answer (score 10):

Use the following types:

```
u64, s64, u32, s32 (or int)
```

For repetitive words/types, use `#defines`:

```
#define a while
```

It's only worth it if you use `while` a lot to make up for the extra 10 characters. ([About 4](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=There%20were%20about%20three%20other%20customers%20in%20the%20place,%20sitting%20at%20tables,%20nursing%20beers.%20About%20three.%20Some%20people%20would%20say%20there%20were%20exactly%20three,%20but%20it%20wasn%27t%20that%20kind%20of%20a%20place,%20not%20the%20kind%20of%20a%20place%20that%20you%20felt%20like%20being%20that%20specific%20in.).)

Comment: The types u64, s64, u32 and s32 are not part of C++. They may be a non-standard extension of your compiler (I've never ever seen them, though).

Comment: These two tips would be better placed in two separate answers so they can be voted on individually.

Comment: What implementations provide these type names?  Is there a header you need to include?  `u8` is probably useful as a 2-byte type name when you don't need large values.

Answer (score 10):

If you're willing to use C++0x, you can use new features like [lambdas](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#lambda).

Answer (score 9):

Since array elements are stored directly after one another in memory, instead of something like this:

```cpp
for(int x = 0; x < 25; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 25; y++)
        array[x][y] = whatever;
}
```

You can do something like this:

```cpp
int* pointer = array;
for(int i = 0; i < 25*25; i++, pointer++)
    *pointer = whatever;
```

Obviously neither of the above are golfed, for readability, but explicitly using pointers can save you a lot of space.

Comment: Don't forget you can cut out all that whitespace! (Different tip altogether, but should be mentioned)

Comment: @stokastic The examples aren't meant to be golfed, only to demonstrate how to use the technique.

Comment: why not `for(int* i=array; i<array+25*25; i++)`? Then you only have to keep  track of one variable.

Answer (score 9):

Quite an obvious one, but it you are using a lot of the standard library, `using namespace std;` might save a few characters.

Comment: If you only use a single name, but that quite often, `using std::name;` may be shorter, though.

Comment: This only saves characters if you use `std::` five or more times.

Answer (score 9):

## Use GCC builtins instead of importing

If you are using a GCC compiler, it sometimes helps to use their builtin functions, such as `__builtin_puts` or `__builtin_clz`. For example,

44 bytes:

```
int main(){__builtin_puts("Hello, world!");}`
```

50 bytes:

```
#import<cstdio>
int main(){puts("Hello, world!");}
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of writing big powers of 10, use **e notation**. For example, `a=1000000000` is longer than `a=1e9`. This can be extended to other numbers like `a=1e9+24` is better than `a=1000000024`.

Comment: Note that this is not exactly equivalent, need to cast to integer types before using. For example `1e9/x` is not the same as `1000000000/x` or `int(1e9)/x`.

Answer (score 8):

You may use the ternary operator `?:` without any expressions in the true-block (it saves a byte)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int foo()
{
    std::cout << "Foo\n";
}

int main()
{
    1?foo():0;  // if (true) foo()
    0?:foo();   // if (!false) foo()
}
```

[Check it here](http://ideone.com/2iUeaH)

Comment: This appears to be a GNU extension and not in the C++ standard. [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals)

Comment: r?foo():0;  // if (r) foo() this is ok;;;;; but For this
    r?:foo();  i don't Know that

Answer (score 8):

Functions in `<algorithm>` often requires passing `a.begin(),a.end()` which is really long, instead you can use `&a[0],&*end(a)` to save a byte or two if `a` is `vector` or `string`.

````cpp
std::sort(a.begin(),a.end());
std::sort(&a[0],&*a.end());

// with using namespace std;
sort(begin(a),end(a));
sort(&a[0],&*end(a));
```
````

Answer (score 7):

`#import` instead of `#include` gives you one more byte.

Also, the space character between `#import` and header is not necessarily:

```
#include <map>
// vs
#import<map>
```

And if you need something from `stdlib` header, you may import any header with STL container (preferable `set` or `map`) instead of `cstdlib`.

Comment: `#import` is a deprecated GCC extension.  But still is supported by modern versions of GCC.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to swap two integer variables a and b then ,

```
a^=b^=a^=b;
```

can be used , saving 5 characters than the standard way

```
a+=b;
b=a-b;
a-=b;
```

Comment: About that standard way. `,t` at the ints created earlier and then `t=a;a=b;b=t;` would have already been 3 bytes shorter than the `a+=b;b=a-b;a-=b;`. Still, your `a^=b^=a^=b;` is even shorter than that, so +1 from me. I don't know C++, but [it indeed works](http://tinyurl.com/y3jvuynm). As a Java code-golfer I'm sad [it doesn't seem to work there](http://tinyurl.com/yxpjh3v2). :(

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yeah , I should have mentioned C++ , I dont know java much , but `a^=b;b^=a;a^=b;` is working fine in java .

Comment: No need to explicitly mention C++. All these tips are for C++. :) As a Java developer I was just curious if something similar could be done in Java, but apparently not. `a^=b;b^=a;a^=b;` indeed works, but is longer than the `,t`+`t=a;a=b;b=t;`. Sorry about mentioning Java, since it's off-topic here. But nice tip for C++ codegolfers!

Comment: If you already have a `using namespace std`, (std::) [`swap(a,b)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) is shorter.  To avoid `#include <algorithm>` or `<utility>`, another [answer suggests](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150895/30206) GCC `#import<bits/stdc++.h>` to get every C++ header.

Comment: I don't know why anyone would think +- swaps are the "standard" way, though.  You'd never do that outside of code golf, you'd use `auto t=a;` or something.  XOR-swap is the better known no-temporary swap, using just 3 separate `^=` statements instead of a `b=a-b;` that has to name `b` twice.  But yes, you save 4 bytes vs. `a^=b;b^=a;a^=b;`.  I guess you might consider that "standard" in a code-golf context if you don't have any spare variables you can use as a temporary.

Comment: Well even if it is not the standard way, it is what I am learning in school. But yours doesn't have any overflow problems. Will there be type issues?

Answer (score 6):

Arithmetic operations on Booleans:

Although

```
a*=b>0?.5:-.5
```

is better than

```
if(b>0)a*=.5;else a*=-.5;
```

it is not as good as

```
a*=(b>0)-.5
```

Also, using #define on anything that is used a lot. It is often shorter than using functions, since type names are not necessary.

Combine things as much as possible:

```
a+=a--;
```

is the same as

```
a=2*a-1;
```

Comment: While your examples are correct, be careful of invoking undefined behavior when using `x` as an lvalue and `x++` as an rvalue. [undefined behavior and sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: Yes possible a+=a--; has Undefined Behaviour

Answer (score 6):

It is useful to remember is that `a[i]` is the same as `*(a+i)`.

Replace `a[0]` with `*a` for two character savings. Also, `a[i][0]` is equivalent to `*a[i]` and `a[0][i]` shrinks down to `i[*a]`. So if you are hard-coding a `0` index in your array, a better way probably exists.

Answer (score 5):

## Use generic lambdas as cheap templates

For types other than `int`, using them as function arguments can be expensive.  However, generic lambdas were introduced (in C++14?) and allow any lambda to be a template - using `auto` for the argument types can save bytes.  Compare:

```
double f(double x, double y)
[](auto x, auto y)
```

Generic lambdas are also very convenient for accepting iterators - probably the best way to accept array inputs in C++ is `[](auto a, auto z)`, where `a` and `z` are passed as `begin()` and `end()` of the array/vector/list/etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing C++11 or newer (which should always be the case now), use `auto` for complex types, if possible.

Example: 54 Bytes instead of 66

```cpp
#include<vector>
std::vector<int> f(std::vector<int> l){return l;}
```

```cpp
#include<vector>
auto f(std::vector<int> l){return l;}
```

Also, as performance does not matter, for some challenges a `std::list` may just do the job for a few bytes less:

```cpp
#include<list>
auto f(std::list<int> l){return l;}
```

Comment: When `std::list` can't be used (usually because you need indexing), `std::deque` is often usable, saving 1 character per use over `std::vector`, and still lets you index it.

Answer (score 5):

It's rather straightforward to cacluate when replacing something with a `#define` results in shorter code.

```
#define a blabla
```

Where `a` is a single letter name and `blabla` is the replacement of length \$x\$ has in total \$10+x\$ characters.

If you have \$n\$ times `blabla` in the code then the `#define` pays off when

$$10 + x + n < nx$$

With the define you have \$10 + x\$ to define it and \$n\$-times a single character. Without it you have \$n\$-times `blabla` of length \$x\$. The following table lists how often `blabla` has to appear given its length for the define to make the code shorter:

| \$x\$ | \$n\$ |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 4 |

Because the inequality is symmetric, the same table applies when \$n\$ and \$x\$ are swapped, ie if `blabla` appears \$n = 2\$ times in the code then the `define` results in shorter code when `blabla` is of length \$x \ge 13\$. The formula is

$$n > \frac {10 + x} {x - 1}$$

or

$$x > \frac {10 + n} {n - 1}$$

PS: Sometines the single letter named preprocessor symbol has to be followed by a space. This shifts the matters a little towards not using the define, but just a little.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice tip!

Answer (score 4):

G++ allows for variable-sized arrays, so there is no need to go through the lengthy pointer-malloc-new stuff.

```c++
int* array = new int[array_size];
```

becomes

```c++
int array[array_size];
```

Saves 9 bytes minimum with int.

Answer (score 4):

Use `auto` instead of complex type names.

This can be done with generic lambdas and C++20 [abbreviated function templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template)

```cpp
int x(std::set<std::string>y){}
template<class T>int x(T&y){}
int x(auto&y){}
[](auto&x){}
```

This also allows you to avoid most includes.

Note that g++ on TIO requires `-fconcepts`.

Answer (score 3):

When writing a full program you can use argc to initialize an integer variable to 1:

```
main(a){
```

is the same as:

```
main(){int a=1;
```

Comment: this is C, not C++

Answer (score 2):

In my first attempt at code golf for [task "Subtract the next numbers"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91903/subtract-the-next-numbers/91916) I have started from function (58 bytes)

```cpp
int f(int N, int P){int F;for(F=N;P;F-=++N,P--);return F;}
```

then safe 5 bytes with shifting to lambda and moving initialization out of `for` (53)

```cpp
[](int N,int P){int F=N;for(;P;F-=++N,P--);return F;}
```

and finally after switching from `for` to `while` I got 51 bytes:

```cpp
[](int N,int P){int F=N;while(P--)F-=++N;return F;}
```

The ungolfed test code is something like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(void)
{
    int N, P;
    std::cin >> N >> P;
    auto f = [](int N,int P)
    {
        int F = N;
        while (P--)
            F -= ++N;
        return F;
    };
    std::cout << f(N, P) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually `for` can reach the same length as `while`:

```cpp
[](int N,int P){int F=N;for(;P--;F-=++N);return F;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kind of late to the party I guess...

If you want to turn an expression into -1 and 1 instead of 0 and 1, instead of this:

```
int x;
if (a * 10 > 5)
    x = 1;
else
    x = -1;
```

do this:

```
int x = (a * 10 > 5) * 2 - 1;
```

It can save some bytes depending on usage.

Comment: Instead of `int x=(a*10>5)*2-1;`, couldn't you do `int x=a*10>5?1:-1;`, which is 1 byte shorter?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a type alias, `using` is two bytes shorter than `#define`:

```cpp
#define T ... // newline
using T=...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `string("")`, use `""`. It saves 8 bytes.

Comment: It's not exactly equivalent. For example `"" + 'a'` is `char* + char`, which is pointer addition, while `std::string("") + 'a'` is `std::string + char` - string concatenation. `string()` would work.

Comment: I would suggest using `""s`. This saves 7 bytes and still is a `std::string`.

Comment: you need `using namespace std::literals` to use `""s`