# Solve the Global Debt, the Code Golf way

Tags: code-golf, math

The leaders of the world have met and have finally admitted that the best (and only) way of resolving global economic woes is to take stock of how much they owe each other and just pay each other off with huge cheques. They have hired you (ironically, at the lowest contract rate possible) to work out the best means of doing so.

After much deliberation, and asking someone to draw a simple example they've come up with the following spec.

Each country is represented by their [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) code: `US` for the USA, `AU` for Australia, `JP` for Japan, `CN` for China and so on...

1. A ledger is drawn up as a series of country entries and the amounts
   owing to each country.
2. Each country's entry starts off with their domain ID a colon, and how much they have in surplus/deficit (in billions of Euro), followed by a semicolon, then a coloned
   comma-separated list of the countries and how much (in billions of
   Euro) they owe.
3. If a country owes nothing to another country, no mention of that country is entered after that semicolon separator.
4. Deficits are indicated as negative numbers, surplus is indicated as a positive number.
5. Values can also be floats.
6. The ledger must be taken from STDIN. The end of the ledger is indicated by a carriage return on a blank line. The tally must be delivered to STDOUT.

An example of a ledger:

```
Input:
AU:8;US:10,CN:15,JP:3
US:14;AU:12,CN:27,JP:14
CN:12;AU:8,US:17,JP:4
JP:10;AU:6,US:7,CN:10
```

The system then works out how much each country owes and is owed and determines their surplus/deficit, for example, for AU:

AU = 8 (current surplus) -10 (to US) -15 (to CN) -3 (to JP) +12 (from US) +8 (from CN) +6 (from JP) = 6

When all the computing is done, a tally must be shown:

```
Output:
AU:6
US:-5
CN:35
JP:8
```

Your job is to create this system, capable of taking any number of ledger entries for any number of countries and capable of determining how much each country has in deficit/surplus when everything is paid out.

The ultimate test is for you to use your code to resolve the debt owed between the following countries in the test case below. These figures were taken from BBC News as of June 2011. (http://www.bbc.com/news/business-15748696)

For the purposes of the exercise, I have used their respective GDP as their current surplus... Please bear in mind that this is strictly an exercise in code quality assurance... there will be no talk of global economic resolution here in this question... If you want to talk economics I'm sure there's another subdomain in SE that handles it...

```
US:10800;FR:440.2,ES:170.5,JP:835.2,DE:414.5,UK:834.5
FR:1800;IT:37.6,JP:79.8,DE:123.5,UK:227,US:202.1
ES:700;PT:19.7,IT:22.3,JP:20,DE:131.7,UK:74.9,US:49.6,FR:112
PT:200;IT:2.9,DE:26.6,UK:18.9,US:3.9,FR:19.1,ES:65.7
IT:1200;JP:32.8,DE:120,UK:54.7,US:34.8,FR:309,ES:29.5
IE:200;JP:15.4,DE:82,UK:104.5,US:39.8,FR:23.8
GR:200;DE:15.9,UK:9.4,US:6.2,FR:41.4,PT:7.5,IT:2.8
JP:4100;DE:42.5,UK:101.8,US:244.8,FR:107.7
DE:2400;UK:141.1,US:174.4,FR:205.8,IT:202.7,JP:108.3
UK:1700;US:578.6,FR:209.9,ES:316.6,IE:113.5,JP:122.7,DE:379.3
```

Now, be the economic savior of the world!

Rules:

1. Shortest code wins... this is code-golf after all...
2. Please provide your output of the major test case with your code answer...

Comment: In the "ultimate test", shouldn't there be a semicolon after `JP:4100`?

Comment: @MathieuRodic Thanks for the sharp eye to detail... +1 to you, my friend...

Comment: @WallyWest: the sharp eye is not mine... but my script's, when it failed at parsing!

Comment: Merci bien, all the same...

Comment: I can't help but wonder if this is a very clever way of having a homework assignment completed for you. If so, you deserve it.

Comment: Yeah, if you did this will real numbers you'd notice an astonishing contradiction. The sum of all surpluses and deficits will be negative.

Comment: seems like this could be solved with linear programming (such as AMPL), although I've never seen it used for a code golf problem.

Comment: @Tobia I'm not sure what country you live in where you have "private banks" printing currency. Probably not a financially stable one...

Comment: Actually, it's not homework in disguise... It was inspired from my weekly poker tournament with my friends... Trying to figure out a quicker way of working out the winnings for each player ;)

Comment: @WallyWest LOL ;) btw, apologies for the OT comments, but it's a matter I'm quite passionate about. Now let's get back to some fun coding and forget the woes of the world...

Comment: @Tobia, Forgiven! I'd love to see an entry from you for this question...

Comment: Ok, will do an APL one over the weekend!

Comment: @JBentley If you want to talk economics, go elsewhere... This question was not to incite opinions about global economics...

Please keep comments like this out of this question or I'll start plucking these comments out like stray grey hairs...

Comment: @WallyWest I was responding to an existing series of comments. But I shall not post further on the subject.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## K, 66

```
{(((!)."SF"$+":"\:'*+a)-+/'d)+/d:"F"$(!).'"S:,"0:/:last'a:";"\:'x}
```

.

```
k)input:0:`:ledg.txt
k){(((!)."SF"$+":"\:'*+a)-+/'d)+/d:"F"$(!).'"S:,"0:/:last'a:";"\:'x} input
US| 9439.3
FR| 2598.9
ES| 852.1
PT| 90.1
IT| 887.5
IE| 48
GR| 116.8
JP| 4817.4
DE| 2903.7
UK| 1546.2
```

Comment: Incredibly impressed with this one... any chance you can provide a link to the K programming paradigm?

Comment: @WallyWest http://code.kx.com/ provides lots of information on q, which is the syntactic sugar that sits on top of k. q, moreso thank k, is what you'll find in production systems but for golfing k has the edge. Also check out Kona (https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona) which is an open source implementation of an older version of k

Answer (score 10):

## Perl, <strike>139</strike> <strike>137</strike> <strike>134</strike> <strike>119</strike> 112

Here's another working piece of code... I will document it later.

**Golfed code**

With dictionary (112):

```
for(<>){~/:(.+);/g;$d{$c=$`}+=$1;$l=$';$d{$1}+=$2,$d{$c}-=$2while$l=~/(..):([^,]+)/g}print"$_:$d{$_}
"for keys%d
```

Without dictionary (137):

```
for($T=$t.=$_ for<>;$t=~/(..:)(.+);(.+)/g;print"$c$s\n"){$c=$1;$l=$3;$s=$2;$s-=$&while$l=~/[\d.]+/g;$s+=$1while$T=~/$c([\d.]+)(?!;|\d)/g}
```

**Output**

```
US:9439.3
FR:2598.9
ES:852.1
PT:90.1
IT:887.5
IE:48
GR:116.8
JP:4817.4
DE:2903.7
UK:1546.2
```

**See it in action!**

http://ideone.com/4iwyEP

Comment: The definition of "short" should be judged by amount of tokens, not characters. Readability 4 life!

Comment: @Domi - you're new here, aren't you ;-)

Comment: @jimbobmcgee: I also have a feeling this website is not much about readability...

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <strike>211</strike> <strike>185</strike> 183

```
import sys,re;t,R,F=sys.stdin.read(),re.findall,float;S=lambda e,s:sum(map(F,R(e,s)))
for m in R('(..:)(.+);(.+)',t):print m[0]+`F(m[1])+S(m[0]+'([\d.]+)(?!;|\d)',t)-S('[\d.]+',m[2])`
```

Output with major test case:

```
US:9439.300000000001
FR:2598.9
ES:852.0999999999999
PT:90.09999999999997
IT:887.5
IE:48.0
GR:116.8
JP:4817.4
DE:2903.7
UK:1546.2000000000003
```

(test it here: http://ideone.com/CjWG7v)

Answer (score 4):

## C - <s>257</s> 253 if no CR at end of line

Depends on sizeof(short)==2.

No check for buffer overflow.

```
#define C(c) x[*(short*)c]
main(i){double x[23131]={0},d;char*q,b[99],*(*s)()=strtok;for(;gets(b);)for(s(b,":"),C(b)+=atof(s(0,";"));q=s(0,":");C(b)-=d=(atof(s(0,","))),C(q)+=d);for(i=b[2]=0;i<23131;memcpy(b,&i,2),x[i]?printf("%s:%f\n",b,x[i++]):++i);}
```

### Output:

```
DE:2903.700000  
IE:48.000000    
UK:1546.200000  
JP:4817.400000  
FR:2598.900000  
GR:116.800000   
ES:852.100000   
US:9439.300000  
IT:887.500000   
PT:90.100000
```

### Less golfed:

```
#define C(c) x[*(short*)c]

main(i)
{
    double x[23131]={0}, d;
    char *q, b[99], *(*s)()=strtok;
    for(;gets(b);) 
        for(s(b, ":"),C(b)+=atof(s(0, ";")); 
            q=s(0, ":"); 
            C(b)-=d=(atof(s(0, ","))), C(q)+=d) ;

    for(i=b[2]=0; 
        i<23131; 
        memcpy(b, &i, 2), x[i]?printf("%s:%f\n", b, x[i++]):++i) ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### PHP - <del>338</del>, 280

Should work with any version of PHP 5.

**Golfed**:

```php
while(preg_match("#(..):(.+);(.*)#",fgets(STDIN),$m)){$l[$m[1]][0]=(float)$m[2];foreach(explode(",",$m[3])as$x){$_=explode(":",$x);$l[$m[1]][1][$_[0]]=(float)$_[1];}}foreach($l as$c=>$d)foreach($d[1]as$_=>$o){$l[$_][0]+=$o;$l[$c][0]-=$o;}foreach($l as$c=>$d)echo$c,":",$d[0],"\n";
```

**Un-golfed**:

```php
<?php

while( preg_match( "#(..):(\d+);(.*)#", fgets( STDIN ), $m ) )
{
    $l[$m[1]][0] = (float)$m[2];

    foreach( explode( ",", $m[3] ) as $x )
    {
        $_ = explode( ":", $x );
        $l[$m[1]][1][$_[0]] = (float)$_[1];
    }
}

foreach( $l as $c => $d )
    foreach( $d[1] as $_ => $o )
    {
        $l[$_][0] += $o;
        $l[$c][0] -= $o;
    }

foreach( $l as $c => $d )
    echo $c, ":", $d[0], "\n";
```

**Output**:

```
US:9439.3
FR:2598.9
ES:852.1
PT:90.1
IT:887.5
IE:48
GR:116.8
JP:4817.4
DE:2903.7
UK:1546.2
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be shorter if you used `preg_match_all()` and then just looped once?

Answer (score 3):

### perl (184 characters)

**Code**

```
%c,%d,%e=();while(<>){$_=~/(..):(.+);(.*)/;$n=$1;$c{$1}=$2;for $i(split /,/,$3){$i=~/(..):(.+)/;$d{$1}+=$2;$e{$n}+=$2;}}for $i(keys %c){$c{$i}+=$d{$i}-$e{$i};print $i.":".$c{$i}."\n";}
```

**Output**

```
UK:1546.2
DE:2903.7
IT:887.5
FR:2598.9
PT:90.1
US:9439.3
JP:4817.4
ES:852.1
IE:48
GR:116.8
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl - <s>116</s> <s>114</s> 112

```
for(<>){($n,$m,@l)=split/[:;,]/;$h{$n}+=$m;$h{$n}-=$p,$h{$o}+=$p while($o,$p,@l)=@l}print"$_:$h{$_}\n"for keys%h
```

### Output:

```
GR:116.8
UK:1546.2
DE:2903.7
IE:48
IT:887.5
US:9439.3
PT:90.1
ES:852.1
FR:2598.9
JP:4817.4
```

### Ungolfed:

```
for(<>) {
    ($n, $m, @l)=split(/[:;,]/);
    $h{$n}+=$m;

    $h{$n}-=$p, $h{$o}+=$p while ($o,$p,@l)=@l
}
print "$_:$h{$_}\n" for keys%h
```

Comment: Nice! I like your approach :)

Answer (score 3):

### AWK - <strike>138</strike> 120

```
{l=split($0,h,"[:,;]");t[h[1]]+=h[2];for(i=3;i<l;i+=2){t[h[1]]-=h[i+1];t[h[i]]+=h[i+1]}}END{for(v in t){print v":"t[v]}}
```

And the results

```
$ cat data.withoutInputHeadline |awk -f codegolf.awk
IT:887.5
UK:1546.2
DE:2903.7
PT:90.1
ES:852.1
FR:2598.9
GR:116.8
Input:0
JP:4817.4
IE:48
US:9439.3
```

### Ungolfed

```
{
    l=split($0,h,"[:,;]");
    t[h[1]]+=h[2];
    for(i=3;i<l;i+=2){
        t[h[1]]-=h[i+1]
        t[h[i]]+=h[i+1]
    }
}
END{
    for(v in t){
        print v":"t[v]
    }
}
```

(test it here: http://ideone.com/pxqc07)

Comment: Why even put those headers in? You'll save more bytes without them... they weren't even part of the spec I set... ;)

Comment: @WallyWest: Ok, so I didn't understood that, because they are displayed in your first example of Input and Output e.g.:  (..)a tally must be shown: Output: (..) No worry about that, I remove my first example right now.

Answer (score 3):

## C++ - 1254

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;int main(){vector<string>input,countries,output;vector<double>results;string last_val;int j,k,i=0;cout<<"Input\n";do{getline(cin,last_val);if(last_val!=""){input.push_back(last_val);countries.push_back(last_val.substr(0,2));}}while(last_val!="");for(j=0;j<countries.size();j++){results.push_back(0);for(k=0;k<input.size();k++)input[k].substr(0, 2)==countries[j]?results[j]+=atof(input[k].substr((input[k].find(countries[j])+3),(input[k].find(',',input[k].find(countries[j]))-input[k].find(countries[j]))).c_str()):results[j]+=atof(input[k].substr((input[k].find(countries[j],3)+3),(input[k].find(',',input[k].find(countries[j]))-input[k].find(countries[j]))).c_str());}for(j=0;j<input.size();j++){for(k=0;k<countries.size();k++){if(input[j].substr(0,2)!=countries[k]){results[j]-=atof(input[j].substr((input[j].find(countries[k])+ 3),(input[j].find(',',input[k].find(countries[k]))-input[j].find(countries[j]))).c_str());}}}for(i=0;i<countries.size();i++){stringstream strstream;strstream<<countries[i]<<":"<<results[i];output.push_back(strstream.str().c_str());}cout<<"Output:\n";for(i=0;i<output.size();i++){cout<<output[i]<<'\n';}return 0;}
```

I realize the code is very long, but enjoyed the good fun. This is my first time code golfing, and I am new to C++, so suggestions for improving my code are much appreciated.

### Final Challenge Results

```
Output:
US:9439.3
FR:2598.9
ES:852.1
PT:90.1
IT:887.5
IE:48
GR:116.8
JP:4817.4
DE:2903.7
UK:1546.2
```

### Ungolfed Code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<string> input, countries, output;
  vector<double> results;
  string last_val;
  int i, j, k;

  cout << "Input\n";
  do {
    getline(cin, last_val);
    if(last_val != "") {
      input.push_back(last_val);
      countries.push_back(last_val.substr(0, 2));
    }
  } while(last_val != "");

  for(j = 0; j < countries.size(); j++) {
    results.push_back(0);
    for(k = 0; k < input.size(); k++) {
      if(input[k].substr(0, 2) == countries[j]) {
        results[j] += atof(input[k].substr((input[k].find(countries[j]) + 3),
                             (input[k].find(',', input[k].find(countries[j])) -
                              input[k].find(countries[j]))).c_str());
      } else {
        results[j] += atof(input[k].substr((input[k].find(countries[j], 3) + 3),
                             (input[k].find(',', input[k].find(countries[j])) -
                              input[k].find(countries[j]))).c_str());
      }
    }
  }

  for(j = 0; j < input.size(); j++) {
    for(k = 0; k < countries.size(); k++) {
      if(input[j].substr(0, 2) != countries[k]) {
        results[j] -= atof(input[j].substr((input[j].find(countries[k]) + 3),
                             (input[j].find(',', input[k].find(countries[k])) -
                              input[j].find(countries[j]))).c_str());
      }
    }
  }

  for(i = 0; i < countries.size(); i++) {
    stringstream strstream;
    strstream << countries[i] << ":" << results[i];
    output.push_back(strstream.str().c_str());
  }

  cout << "Output:\n";
  for(i = 0; i < output.size(); i++) {
    cout << output[i] << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Nice to see an example in C++. You could reduce number of characters by using one-letter identifiers in stead of descriptive names, i.e. use _i_ for _input_, _c_ for _countries_ and so on.

Comment: Agreed with @ahy1 here... If you reduce your variables to 1 letter you can cut a fair bit of this... You may also find this of interest for future golf challenges: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132/tips-for-golfing-in-c

Comment: Oh, and you won't need `cout << "Output:\n";` either... That's a 20 byte saving there...

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby - 225

First try in a challenge like this, sure it could be a lot better...

```
R=Hash.new(0)
def pd(s,o=nil);s.split(':').tap{|c,a|R[c]+=a.to_f;o&&R[o]-=a.to_f};end
STDIN.read.split("\n").each{|l|c,d=l.split(';');pd(c);d.split(',').each{|s|pd(s,c.split(':')[0])}}
puts R.map{|k,v|"#{k}: #{v}"}.join("\n")
```

And the results

```
$ cat data|ruby codegolf.rb
US: 9439.299999999997
FR: 2598.8999999999996
ES: 852.1
JP: 4817.4
DE: 2903.7
UK: 1546.2000000000003
IT: 887.5
PT: 90.09999999999998
IE: 48.0
GR: 116.8
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript(ES6) <s>175</s>,<s>166</s>, <s>161</s>, <s>156</s>, <s>153</s>147

**Golfed**

```
R={};prompt().split(/\s/).map(l=>{a=l.split(/[;,:]/);c=b=a[0];a.map(v=>b=!+v?v:(R[b]=(R[b]||0)+ +v c==b?b:R[c]-=+v))});for(x in R)alert(x+':'+R[x])
```

**Ungolfed**

```
R = {};
prompt().split(/\s/).map(l => {
    a = l.split(/[;,:]/);       // Split them all!! 
                                // Now in a we have big array with Country/Value items
    c = b = a[0];               // c - is first country, b - current country
    a.map(v =>                
         b = !+v ? v                 // If v is country (not a number), simply update b to it's value          
                 : (R[b] = (R[b] ||0) + +v   // Safely Add value to current country
                   c == b ? c : R[c] -= +v)  // If current country is not first one, remove debth 
    )
});
for (x in R) alert(x + ':' + R[x])
```

**Output**

```
US:9439.299999999997
FR:2598.8999999999996
ES:852.1
JP:4817.4
DE:2903.7
UK:1546.2000000000003
IT:887.5
PT:90.09999999999998
IE:48
GR:116.8
```

Comment: Not sure that ungolfed variant will be working correctly because in golfed variant i'm using one-line operators

Comment: can you please show your output?

Comment: Sure, but it's kind'a the same, as in other results

Comment: Replaced ```R[b] ? R[b] += +v : R[b] = +v``` to ```R[b]=R[b]||0+ +v```

Comment: Removed index ```i=0;i++%2==0?b=v``` to ```b=isNaN(+v)?v:```

Comment: ```isNaN(+v)``` -> ```!+v```

Comment: Nice reductions! +1 to each...

Answer (score 2):

## JS, <strike>254</strike> <strike>240</strike> 245

```
z='replace';r={};p=eval(('[{'+prompt()+'}]')[z](/\n/g,'},{')[z](/;/g,','));for(i in p){l=p[i];c=0;for(k in l){if(!c){c=k;r[c]=0;}else{r[c]-=l[k];}};for(j in p){w=p[j][c];if(w!=null)r[c]+=w}};alert(JSON.stringify(r)[z](/"|{|}/g,'')[z](/,/g,'\n'))
```

Well..I know it is quite long but this is my second code golf.

Suggestions are welcome!

BTW, Interesting Javascript preserves the order of elements in hashmaps,
so, even if p contains an array of dictionaries, I can iterate each dictionary
as an array and I'm sure that the first element of a dict is the first inserted. (the name of the country referred to the current line)

### Ungolfed:

```
z='replace';
r={};
p=eval(('[{'+prompt()+'}]')[z](/\n/g,'},{')[z](/;/g,',')); // make the string JSONable and then evaluate it in a structure
for(i in p){ 
    l=p[i];
    c=0;
    for(k in l){
            if(!c){ // if c is not still defined, this is the country we are parsing.
                    c=k;
                    r[c]=0;
            }
            else r[c]-=l[k];
    }; 
    for(j in p){
            w=p[j][c];
            if(!w)  r[c]+=w
    }
};
alert(JSON.stringify(r)[z](/"|{|}/g,'')[z](/,/g,'\n')) # Stringify the structure, makes it new-line separated.
```

---

Note: the input is a `prompt()` which should be a single line. But if you copy/paste a multi line text (like the proposed input) in a `prompt()` window then `JS` read it all.

Output:

```
US:9439.3
FR:2598.9
ES:852.1
PT:90.09999999999998
IT:887.5
IE:48
GR:116.8
JP:4817.4
DE:2903.7000000000003
UK:1546.2
```

Comment: You use the word "replace" ***four*** times in your code. How about shortening it like this: `z='replace';r={};p=eval(('[{'+prompt()+'}]')[z](/\n/g,'},{')[z](/;/g,','));for(i in p){l=p[i];c=0;for(k in l){if(!c){c=k;r[c]=0;}else{r[c]-=l[k];}};for(j in p){w=p[j][c];if(w!=null)r[c]+=w}};alert(JSON.stringify(r)[z](/"|{|}/g,'')[z](/,/g,'\n'))`?

Comment: Woah this saved me 7*4-(3*4+11) characters! (I also put `(w!=null)` as `(!w)`

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin Could you please show your output?

Comment: Thanks for your message @WallyWest. Turns out `!w` was not a good idea to check `w!=null` and the script wasn't working anymore :p. Now I'll update it with the results

Comment: Try using: `z="replace";r={};p=eval(("[{"+prompt()+"}]")[z](/\n/g,"},{")[z](/;/g,","));for(i in p){l=p[i];c=0;for(k in l)c?r[c]-=l[k]:(c=k,r[c]=0);for(j in p)w=p[j][c],null!=w&&(r[c]+=w)}alert(JSON.stringify(r)[z](/"|{|}/g,"")[z](/,/g,"\n"))` for 229 bytes...

What I've done here is reduced the `if(!c)` sequence to a single ternary operator, and I've also incorporated it in its parent `for` loop... I've also done something similar with the other `for` loop... comma operators can work wonderfully to join multiple statements within a loop...

Comment: Oh, and while I'm at it... welcome to Codegolf.Stackexchange... I hope you enjoy it here! :)

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy 315

```
def f(i){t=[:];i.eachLine(){l=it.split(/;|,/);s=l[0].split(/:/);if(!z(s[0]))t.put(s[0],0);t.put(s[0],x(z(s[0]))+x(s[1]));(1..<l.size()).each(){n=l[it].split(/:/);t.put(s[0],x(z(s[0]))-x(n[1]));if(!z(n[0]))t.put(n[0],0);t.put(n[0],x(z(n[0]))+x(n[1]))}};t.each(){println it}};def x(j){j.toDouble()};def z(j){t.get(j)}

Output:
US=9439.299999999997
FR=2598.8999999999996
ES=852.1
JP=4817.4
DE=2903.7
UK=1546.2000000000003
IT=887.5
PT=90.09999999999998
IE=48.0
GR=116.8
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
input = """US:10800;FR:440.2,ES:170.5,JP:835.2,DE:414.5,UK:834.5
FR:1800;IT:37.6,JP:79.8,DE:123.5,UK:227,US:202.1
ES:700;PT:19.7,IT:22.3,JP:20,DE:131.7,UK:74.9,US:49.6,FR:112
PT:200;IT:2.9,DE:26.6,UK:18.9,US:3.9,FR:19.1,ES:65.7
IT:1200;JP:32.8,DE:120,UK:54.7,US:34.8,FR:309,ES:29.5
IE:200;JP:15.4,DE:82,UK:104.5,US:39.8,FR:23.8
GR:200;DE:15.9,UK:9.4,US:6.2,FR:41.4,PT:7.5,IT:2.8
JP:4100;DE:42.5,UK:101.8,US:244.8,FR:107.7
DE:2400;UK:141.1,US:174.4,FR:205.8,IT:202.7,JP:108.3
UK:1700;US:578.6,FR:209.9,ES:316.6,IE:113.5,JP:122.7,DE:379.3"""

ungolfed(input)

def ungolfed(i){
    def tallyMap = [:]
    i.eachLine(){ 
        def lineList = it.split(/;|,/)
        def target = lineList[0].split(/:/)

        if(!tallyMap.get(target[0])){tallyMap.put(target[0],0)}
        tallyMap.put(target[0],tallyMap.get(target[0]).toDouble() + target[1].toDouble())
        (1..lineList.size()-1).each(){ e ->
            def nextTarget = lineList[e].split(/:/)
            //subtract the debt
            tallyMap.put(target[0], (tallyMap.get(target[0]).toDouble() - nextTarget[1].toDouble()))
            //add the debt
            if(!tallyMap.get(nextTarget[0])){ tallyMap.put(nextTarget[0], 0) }
            tallyMap.put(nextTarget[0], (tallyMap.get(nextTarget[0]).toDouble() + nextTarget[1].toDouble()))  
        }
    }
    tallyMap.each(){
        println it
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to where I can find more info on Groovy?

Comment: @WallyWest: I have this book, and learned tons from it. I feel that this is one of those languages that it is good to have a reference on the shelf. [link](http://www.amazon.com/Groovy-Action-Dierk-Koenig/dp/1932394842), Also tons of info here: [link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Getting+Started+Guide)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 333

```
$a='';while(($l=trim(fgets(STDIN)))!='')$a.=$l.'\n';$a=rtrim($a,'\n');$p=explode('\n',$a);foreach($p as $q){preg_match('/^([A-Z]+)/',$q,$b);preg_match_all('/'.$b[0].':(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/',$a,$c);$e=ltrim(strstr($q,';'),';');preg_match_all('/([A-Z]+)\:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/',$e,$d);echo $b[0].':'.(array_sum($c[1])-array_sum($d[2])).PHP_EOL;}
```

Ungolfed version :

```
$a='';
while(($l=trim(fgets(STDIN)))!='')
    $a .= $l.'\n';
$a = rtrim($a,'\n');
$p = explode('\n',$a);
foreach($p as $q){
    preg_match('/^([A-Z]+)/',$q,$b);
    preg_match_all('/'.$b[0].':(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/',$a,$c);
    $e = ltrim(strstr($q,';'),';');
    preg_match_all('/([A-Z]+)\:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/', $e, $d);
    echo $b[0].':'.(array_sum($c[1])-array_sum($d[2])).PHP_EOL;
}
```