# Generate the Temple Skyline Sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, binary

Consider the following process:

1. Take some non-negative integer N.

   e.g. N = `571`
2. Express it in binary with no leading zeroes. (Zero itself is the only exception, becoming `0`.)

   e.g. `571` = `1000111011` in binary
3. Break apart consecutive runs of ones and zeroes in this binary representation.

   e.g. `1000111011` → `1`, `000`, `111`, `0`, `11`
4. Sort the runs from longest to shortest.

   e.g. `1`, `000`, `111`, `0`, `11` → `000`, `111`, `11`, `1`, `0`
5. Overwrite all the digits in each run with alternating `1`'s and `0`'s, always starting with `1`'s.

   e.g. `000`, `111`, `11`, `1`, `0` → `111`, `000`, `11`, `0`, `1`
6. Concatenate the result to get a new binary number.

   e.g. `111`, `000`, `11`, `0`, `1` → `1110001101` = `909` in decimal

When you plot the values produced by this process you get a pretty neat graph:

[image: Temple Skyline plot to 1024]

And it's hopefully apparent why I'm calling the resulting sequence the *Temple Skyline sequence*:

[image: Temple Skyline]

## Challenge

Write a program or function that takes in a non-negative integer N and prints or returns the corresponding Temple Skyline sequence number. Your input and output should both be in decimal.

e.g. If the input is `571` the output should be `909`.

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

For reference, here are the terms in the sequence from N = 0 to 20:

```
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   6
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   14
9   13
10  10
11  13
12  12
13  13
14  14
15  15
16  30
17  29
18  26
19  25
20  26
```

[Here are the terms from 0 to 1023.](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=h8aHLkUQ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
ACr.BQ8|is*V_SGH2 1
```

*1 byte saved by Jakube*

[Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ACr.BQ8%7Cis%2aV_SGH2+1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=571%0A20%0A1%0A0&debug=0)

Uses the fact that after run-length-encoding, the runs are the desired runs in the output.

Lost 3 bytes special casing 0.

Answer (score 14):

## CJam, <s>25</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
ri1e>2be`z($W%a\+ze~2b
```

Just a bit of run-length encoding. -1 thanks to @MartinBüttner.

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri1e%3E2be%60z%28%24W%25a%5C%2Bze~2b&input=571) / [Test suite](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=100%20%7B_oSo%20i1e%3E2be%60z%28%24W%25a%5C%2Bze~2b%20p%7D%2F).

#### Explanation

```
ri        Read n from input as int
1e>       Take max with 1 (special case for n = 0)
2b        Convert n to binary
e`        Run length encode
z         Zip, giving a pair [<counts> <10101.. array>]
($W%      Drop the counts array and sort decending
a\+z      Add it back to the 10101.. array and re-zip
e~        Run length decode
2b        Convert from binary
```

Answer (score 11):

## Pyth - <s>21</s> 20 bytes

*Thanks to @sok for saving me one byte!*

```
is.em%hk2hb_Sr.BQ8 2
```

[Try it here online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=is.em%25hk2hb_Sr.BQ8+2&input=571&debug=0).

Comment: You can use `.BQ` instead of `jQ2`, which means you can lose the space between the `8` and the preceding `2`.

Comment: `is*R\`s=!Z_ShMr.BQ8 2` is an interesting same-length solution. Mostly posting because I didn't really expect the assign in a map argument to work.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Replace `\`s` with `]`. Saves one byte.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 121 bytes <s>125</s>

121: Thanks to Sp3000 for shaving off 4 bytes!

```
import re;print int("".join(n*`~i%2`for i,n in enumerate(sorted(map(len,re.split('(1*|0+)',bin(input())[2:])))[::-1])),2)
```

125

```
import re;print int("".join("10"[i%2]*n for i,n in enumerate(sorted(map(len,re.split('(1*|0+)',bin(input())[2:])))[::-1])),2)
```

Comment: Nice! I believe you can also do `n*\`~i%2\`for` instead of `"10"[i%2]*n for`

Comment: Thanks for editing! I had to rush off quickly but wanted to submit because I thought this was a beautiful challenge and a good one for a first submission. I will check out your submission shortly!

Comment: I think that you can save some bytes by using `sorted(...,key=len)` instead of using `map(len,...` but I don't fully comprehend your program right now so I'm not positive that would benefit you.

Comment: Hey @Cole I am mapping `len` because that is the only information I need to replicate the amount of 1 and 0. I tried your suggestion and it adds 2 bytes, as I will have to use `len` twice then, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript ES6, 110 bytes <s>113</s> <s>116</s> <s>119</s> <s>120</s>

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @intrepidcoder*

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @NinjaBearMonkey*

```
n=>+('0b'+n.toString(2).split(/(0+)/).sort((b,a)=>a.length-b.length).map((l,i)=>l.replace(/./g,i-1&1)).join``)
```

Straight forward approach. Don't like the length of the sort function but I can't think of a way to golf it.

Comment: I think you can use a `+` instead of `eval`.

Comment: @intrepidcoder thanks, that saved 3 bytes!

Comment: I can't test this, but `split(/(0+)/g)` should be able to replace `match(/(.)\1*/g)`.

Comment: @NinjaBearMonkey thanks, that saved 3 bytes!

Comment: Saving one byte:  `+(s=0,  ... .map(l=>l.replace(/./g,s^=1))...)`

Comment: Nice work! Are you sure you need the parentheses in the first regex?

Comment: @ETHproductions unfortunately yeah, otherwise split will actually split the `0's` themselves if that makes sense

Answer (score 5):

## C++, <s>535</s> 527 Bytes

(thanks zereges for shaving off some bytes.)

Now that we got rid of those bytes the program is now competetive ;)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
int main(){int I,D;std::cin>>I;while(I>int(pow(2,D))){D++;}int L[99];int X=0;int Z=0;int O=0;for(int i=D-1;i>=0;i--){if( int(pow(2,i))&I){if(Z>0){L[X]=Z;Z=0; X++;}O++;}else{if(O>0){L[X] = O;O=0;X++;}Z++;}}if(Z>0){L[X]=Z;Z=0;X++;}if(O>0){L[X]=O;O=0;X++;}int P=0;bool B = true;int W = D-1;for(int j=0;j<X;j++){int K=0;int mX=0;for(int i=0;i<X;i++){if(L[i]>K){K=L[i];mX=i;}}L[mX]=0;if(B){for(int k=0;k<K;k++){P+=int(pow(2,W));W--;}}else{for(int k=0;k<K;k++){W--;}}B^=1;}std::cout<<P;return 0;}
```

I'm new to golfing, so **please give me some tips in the comments**.

Things like "you don't need those brackets" or "use printf" are all helpful, but I also appreciate advice on the logic. Thanks in advance!

For ease of reading, I present the ungolfed version:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
int main()
{
int input,digits;

std::cin>>input;
while(input > int(pow(2,digits))){digits++;}

int list[99];
int index=0;
int zCounter=0;
int oCounter=0;

for(int i=digits;i>0;i--)
{
    if( int(pow(2,i-1))&input)
    {
        if(zCounter>0)
        {
            list[index] = zCounter;
            zCounter=0;
            index++;
        }
        oCounter++;
    }
    else
    {
        if(oCounter>0)
        {
            list[index] = oCounter;
            oCounter=0;
            index++;
        }
        zCounter++;
    }
}
if(zCounter>0)
{
        list[index] = zCounter;
        zCounter=0;
        index++;
}
if(oCounter>0)
{
        list[index] = oCounter;
        oCounter=0;
        index++;
}

int output = 0;
bool ones = true;
int power = digits-1;
for(int j=0;j<index;j++)
{
    int max=0;
    int mIndex=0;
    for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
    {
        if(list[i]>max){max=list[i];mIndex=i;}
    }
    list[mIndex]=0;

    if(ones)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<max;k++)
        {
            output+=int(pow(2,power));
            power--;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int k=0;k<max;k++)
        {
            power--;
        }
    }
    ones^=1;

}
std::cout<<output;
return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** golfed version brought down a couple bytes, ungolfed version unchanged

Comment: You can instead of `int a; int b;` use `int a,b;`. Also variables in in global scope are initialized with `0`. Also you don't have to use curly brackets when there is only one command to be executed. Also `ones=!ones;` can be simplified as `ones ^= 1;`

Comment: Saved some bytes thanks

Comment: Shift your first `for` loop by `1`, i.e. `for(int i=D;i;i--)` and use `pow(2,i-1)` inside the loop.

Comment: @LiamNoronha You actually did not save what I recommended :)

Comment: I changed it in the golfed version. I didn't touch the ungolfed version. I'll do that in a minute

Comment: @LiamNoronha [Check this out](http://pastebin.com/Hh3Xy981). There is still a lot of space for improvement. E.g. reusing variables (saves definition), `ones` can also be `int`. Maybe macroing `int(pow(i))` into `P(i)`. I would recommend you reading the discussion [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132/tips-for-golfing-in-c)

Comment: You are taking a power of 2, so instead of `pow(2, D)` you could just write `2<<D`. You can save a statement by replacing `L[X]=O;X++;` by `L[X++]=O;`. And as mentioned, your initializations may be shortened, e.g. `int a,b;` instead of `int a=0;int b=0;` and `bool b=1` instead of `bool b = true`. Golfing turns out to be a lot more than just removing all the whitespace, doesn't it ;)

Comment: Yes it does. It's pretty interesting to get into (and frustrating)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5.10, <strike>121</strike> 101

```
say oct"0b".join'',map{$|=1-$|;$_=~s/./$|/gr}sort{length$b<=>length$a}(sprintf"%b",shift)=~/(0*|1*)/g
```

I think the sort part can be shorter.

Edit: -20 bytes, thanks to symbabque!

Comment: You can get rid of the `\n`, and the `m` is not required for regular expression matching. In your substitution, just use `.` instead of the char group.

Comment: No need for the `grep` part either. The `oct` is neat though :)

Comment: Thank you, I accidentally left those parts from the original code.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>132</s> 131 bytes

```
import Data.List
g 0=[]
g n=mod n 2:g(div n 2)
q=[1]:[0]:q
f=foldl((+).(2*))0.concat.zipWith(<*)q.sortOn((-)0.length).group.g.max 1
```

Usage example:

```
> map f [0..20]
[1,1,2,3,6,5,6,7,14,13,10,13,12,13,14,15,30,29,26,25,26]
```

How it works:

```
                 max 1         -- fix n=0: f(0) is the same as f(1)
               g               -- turn into binary, i.e. list of 0s and 1s
            group              -- group sequences of equal elements
         sortOn((-)0.length)   -- sort groups on negative length
      zipWith(<*)q             -- map each element in a group to constant 1 or 0 by turns
   concat                      -- flatten all groups into a single list
foldl((+).(2*))0               -- convert back to decimal
```

Answer (score 2):

## J - 30 bytes

Function taking integer on right. Correctly handles 0.

```
(\:~#2|#\)@(#;.1~1,2~:/\])&.#:
```

- `#:` - Take the binary representation.
- `1,2~:/\]` - Between each digit, report *True* if they are different. Prepend a *True* so that the list has *True* at the start of each "run".
- `(#;.1~...)` - Using the boolean vector above, take the length of each run.
- `\:~` - Sort these lengths from longest to shortest.
- `2|#\` - Take a list of alternating `1 0 1 0 ...` as long as the list of lengths.
- `(...#...)` - For each number on the left (sorted lengths), take as many of the corresponding item on the right (alternating 1's and 0's)
- `&.` - Convert this new binary representation back to a number.

Examples:

```
   (\:~#2|#\)@(#;.1~1,2~:/\])&.#: 571
909
   i.21   NB. zero to twenty
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
   (\:~#2|#\)@(#;.1~1,2~:/\])&.#: every i.21   NB. apply separately to every number
1 1 2 3 6 5 6 7 14 13 10 13 12 13 14 15 30 29 26 25 26
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>146</s> 136 bytes

```
import re;print(int(''.join(len(j)*'01'[i%2<1]for i,j in enumerate(sorted(re.findall('1+|0+',bin(int(input()))[2:]),key=len)[::-1])),2))
```

Comment: Rather than `map` with a `lambda`, would it be better to do `''.join(... for  ... in ...)`?

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 83 bytes

```
Flatten[0#+(d=1-d)&/@SortBy[d=0;Split[#~IntegerDigits~2],-Length@#&]]~FromDigits~2&
```

This defines an unnamed function.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>107</s> <s>104</s> 102 bytes

(saved 3 bytes thanks to **nimi**)

Not going to beat the likes of CJam, but I got it pretty small for a sane language.

```
p gets.to_i.to_s(2).scan(/((.)\2*)/).map{|e|e[i=0].size}.sort.reverse.map{|e|"#{i=1-i}"*e}.join.to_i 2
```

Comment: A few bytes to save: `(i+=1)%2` is `i=1-i`.

Comment: @nimi Ah, thank you. I was trying to figure out how to shorten that.

Answer (score 0):

### Java 8, <s>179</s> 176 bytes

```
(x)->{int g[]=new int[32],h=0,i=highestOneBit(x);g[0]=1;while(i>1)g[((x&i)>0)^((x&(i>>=1))>0)?++h:h]++;sort(g);for(i=32,h=0;g[--i]>0;)while(g[i]-->0)h=h<<1|i%2;return x<1?1:h;}
```

I used two static imports: `java.util.Integer.highestOneBit` and `java.util.Arrays.sort`.

For readability, here's the code ungolfed:

```
java.util.function.ToIntFunction<Integer> f = (x) -> {
  int g[] = new int[32], h = 0, i = java.util.Integer.highestOneBit(x);
  g[0] = 1;
  while (i > 1) {
    g[((x & i) > 0) ^ ((x & (i >>= 1)) > 0) ? ++h : h]++;
  }
  java.util.Arrays.sort(g);
  for (i = 32, h = 0; g[--i] > 0;) {
    while (g[i]-- > 0) {
      h = h << 1 | i % 2;
    }
  }
  return x < 1 ? 1 : h; // handle zero
};
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
ḋ`Ṙİ¬↔OmLgḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO7oSHO2cc2XBozaO2Kf65PulAkf///5uaGwIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¤ò¦ ñÊÔËîEvÃ¬Í
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=pPKmIPHK1MvuRXbDrM0&input=NTcx)

```
¤ò¦ ñÊÔËîEvÃ¬Í     :Implicit input of integer
¤                  :To binary string
 ò                 :Partition on
  ¦                :Inequality
    ñ              :Sort by
     Ê             :Length
      Ô            :Reverse
       Ë           :Map each D at 0-based index E
        î          :  Fill D with
         Ev        :  Parity of E
           Ã       :End map
            ¬      :Join
             Í     :To decimal
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>32</s></sup> 30 bytes

```apl
⊥{⍵/(≢⍵)⍴⊤2}⊃¨∨{⍴¨⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵}⊤⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97f@jrqXVj3q36ms86lwEpDUf9W551LXEqPZRV/OhFY86VgAltwAZvVsfdTU96l1hqGP0qHOBPpAPVLHkUd9UkCn/07hMzQ0B)

-2 bytes for full program.

### Explanation

```apl
⊥{⍵/(≢⍵)⍴⊤2}⊃¨∨{⍴¨⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵}⊤⎕
                            ⊤⎕ convert input to binary
                       2≠/⍵    inequality of overlapping pairs
                     1,        prepend 1
                  ⍵⊂⍨          partition bits on that
                ⍴¨             get length of each part
              ∨                sort in descending order
            ⊃¨                 unenclose each
          ⊤2                   array [1,0]
    (≢⍵)⍴                      reshape to ⍵'s length
  ⍵/                           filter ⍵ by that(every other element)
⊥                              convert that back to binary
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
BŒgLÞṚJḂṁ"ƊFḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//QsWSZ0zDnuG5mkrhuILhuYEixopG4biE////NTcx)

### How it works

```
BŒgLÞṚJḂṁ"ƊFḄ - Main link. Takes n on the left
B             - Convert to binary
 Œg           - Group adjacent equal elements; Call this l
    Þ         - Sort by...
   L          -   length
     Ṛ        - Reverse, to put the longest first
          Ɗ   - Run the previous 3 commands over the sortedt list
      J       - Yield [1, 2, ..., len(l)]
       Ḃ      - Bit;  [1, 0, 1, 0, ..., len(l)%2]
         "    - Zip with l and do the following over each pair
        ṁ     -   Mould 1 or 0 to each element of l
           F  - Flatten
            Ḅ - Convert from binary
```