# Find the needle in the haystack

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a rectangular haystack of size at least 2x2 composed of all the same printable ASCII characters, output the location (counting from the top-left) of the needle which is a different character.

For example, if the following haystack is input:

```
#####
###N#
#####
#####
```

The output should be `3,1` when zero-indexed (what I'll be using in this challenge) or `4,2` when one-indexed.

The haystack can be composed of any printable ASCII character:

```
^^^
^^^
^N^
^^^
^^^
^^^
```

output: `1,2`

and the needle will be any *other* printable ASCII character:

```
jjjjjj
j@jjjj
jjjjjj
```

output `1,1`

It's also possible to have a needle in the corner:

```
Z8
88
```

output `0,0`

```
88
8Z
```

output `1,1`

or to have the needle at the edge:

```
>>>>>>>>>>
>>>>>>>>>:
>>>>>>>>>>
```

output `9,1`

#### Rules and Clarifications

- Input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963). This means you can take input as a list of list of characters, as a single string, etc.
- You can print the result to STDOUT or return it as a function result. Please state in your submission what order the output is in (i.e., horizontal then vertical, as used in the challenge, or vice versa).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- You do *not* get to pick which characters to use. That's the challenge.
- The haystack is guaranteed to be at least 2x2 in size, so it's unambiguous which is the needle and which is the hay.
- There is only ever one needle in the input, and it's only ever one character in size.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Suggested test case: `88\n8Z` (with any two characters of course).

Comment: Can we take input as a multi-dimensional array? i.e. [
 ['#','#','#','#','#'],
 ['#','#','#','N','#'],
 ['#','#','#','#','#'],
 ['#','#','#','#','#'] ];

Comment: @gwaugh Like a list of list of characters? Yes, that's fine (and explicitly called out as OK).

Comment: Can we take input as a pair of a string without newlines and the width (or height) of the haystack? i.e. `("########N###########", 5)`

Comment: @someone Yes, though it [doesn't have a real quorum](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17117/42963), I feel that should be allowed.

Comment: On the topic that @someone asked, can we take input as pair of string w/o NL and width as function params?

Comment: @gwaugh Yes, that's fine.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork would a numpy array of `int32` be fine as input? (note that numpy _does_ have char arrays as well)

Comment: @ASCII-only If `int32` is the *only* way to take input, that would be OK, but given that `char` arrays are possible, I'm going to rule that numpy must use char arrays.

Comment: What about `##\n@@` i.e. same amount of both characters

Comment: @FireCubez There's only one needle. I can make that explicitly clear, if you think it's necessary?

Comment: i.e. input is guaranteed to only have one needle? I think you should clear that up, since I got confused at first.

Comment: @FireCubez Added. Thanks!

Comment: "The haystack is guaranteed to be at least 2x2 in size" – does this mean it's guaranteed to be at least 2 wide and 2 high, or that it's guaranteed to be at last 4 characters in area?

Comment: @Deadcode I think also 3x1 or 1x3 may be correct. It could be enough to have one needle different from the rest from my point of view.

Comment: @Deadcode Guaranteed at least 2 wide and 2 high. While AZTECCO is correct that 1x3 or 3x1 is enough to distinguish the needle and hay, such a situation will never happen.

Answer (score 21):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>49</s> <s>47</s> 44 bytes

```r
function(m,`?`=which)m==names(?table(m)<2)?T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BTsMwDIbveQprvcRSuWwIVWilHDlMO3HaoVrI3DVTk1aJgfL0JW3Fwi/Z/h1/jv3UwP5haj6dZtM7afNzdS6/W6NbtGXplKUgK1YfHUmL@y1W71P2Rt1AHv6WgHvwpC7ALQFTYNAqUADlLqB790WeZ0SBVezNKK7l/dyIQQ1D9yMD@zB0huX80cG4eDUfMd9sMNcoRCOv8hFRZLPmfMySj3kBniJQ1/Uaxzr5GAuwi8Btkbi9rmXtluk2Tk@FKIrURl@c0u7LXck@/3udfgE)

Takes input as a matrix, returns 1-indexed coordinates

Comment: That `which` assignment is disgracefully smooth.

Comment: I was so excited to try this challenge in R, then I saw this and decided to cry in awe instead

Answer (score 9):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <del>41 38</del> 37 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to @nwellnhof.*

*1 byte saved thanks to Jo King.*

```perl6
{map {[+] ^∞Z*!<<.&[Z~~]},$_,.&[Z]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RUxbCoMwEPzPKbZRilrxs0h90BN4gKgpWhQqaqWxHyL63VP0cL2IjYmYgdmZ2R22K171eWkGOJYQLGOTdTDGpxTo7/Ml1sH3nWNM5jmdbP1mrz6dFg@xdw59wXpDZyaMwLIBdOYJLfnOqR9twRz@zLCc@7PJ@YL1ppyyhgOJpE1aDBNC4h3WViDOSExtm9j0tgKlFAlGm0qqQiWAqqsUAXUlLnJdFV0eiYrhDrS7i7Lh2lz@)

### Explanation

It takes the input as a list of lists of characters and returns list of length 2 containing zero-based X and Y coordinates of the needle.

It works by applying the block `{[+] ^∞ Z* !<<.&[Z~~]}` on the input and on its transpose. `.&[Z~~]` goes through all columns of the argument and returns `True` if all the elements are the same, `False` otherwise. We then negate all the values (so we have a list with one bool per column, where the bool answers the question "Is the needle in that column?"), multiply them element-wise with a sequence 0,1,2,... (`True = 1` and `False = 0`) and sum the list, so the result of the whole block is the 0-based number of the column where the needle was found.

## Nwellnhof's better approach, [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 34 bytes

```perl6
{map *.first(:k,*.Set>1),.&[Z],$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RUxBCoMwELznFSGKGJFALyUoSl/gpTdrLVoiaNWKSQ8ivj2NiZiBmdnZHXZic3@VwwK9BiZyHaoJBqRpZy786BMG5M5EesEh8R75M3Rfm4wB/9VQMFVwOYYr5NUCXR5rb9SO9O3IOFGf/IC8v0OtFlxgo6aGEoNiLEYENwD0O@TsAIqZVudQhOOjUJYl0MwON7SFTgN0N2Ma9ppTQKmNVMXcxvQEOKfIjunelH8)

### Explanation

Generally the same approach, just more effective. It still uses a block on the array and its transpose, but now the block converts all *rows* into`Sets` and checks for the number of elements. The `first` function then gives index (due to the `:k`) of the first row that contained more than 1 element. Because of that, the order of `$_` and `.&[Z]` needed to be swapped.

Comment: Nice approach! [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##RUxBCoMwELznFSGKGJFALyUoSl/gpTdrLVoiaNWKSQ8ivj2NiZiBmdnZHXZic3@VwwK9BiZyHaoJBqRpZy786BMG5M5EesEh8R75M3Rfm4wB/9VQMFVwOYYr5NUCXR5rb9SO9O3IOFGf/IC8v0OtFlxgo6aGEoNiLEYENwD0O@TsAIqZVudQhOOjUJYl0MwON7SFTgN0N2Ma9ppTQKmNVMXcxvQEOKfIjunelH8 "Perl 6 – Try It Online") with `first(:k)`, `Set` and `.&[Z]`.

Comment: @nwellnhof, very well done. You basically found what I wanted to find but failed to do that :—). (Also I had no idea that you could write `.&[Z]`.)

Comment: In general, `.&[op]` doesn't seem to be equivalent to `[op] $_` but it works with `Z` for some reason.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda m:[map(len,map(set,a)).index(2)for a in zip(*m),m]
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BCoMwEEX3OcWAiyQldeFKBEtP4AGsDaSoNGJi0CBtL28zcaEPkvk/8yHfff17stnWl802KvNqFZjiYZRjY2cFzqXzQnGeatt2H5bxfppBgbbw045dDBfmuflu8QuUwCilDUkQvKvk0EkSdkRATEgp91PJQ0t5SgwRMtz3ETmt65zk@cnnwdfoOSFYEAthx1isIBBYQz@06eJG7RmPj5idMbjuIcTN2nqYyaFpUNcbFdCzlYcfG0u3Pw)**

---

A port of this to **[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/)** can be **62 bytes**:

```python
lambda m:[[len(set(v))for v in a].index(2)for a in(zip(*m),m)]
```

The list comprehension, `[len(set(v))for v in a]`, is shorter than the double map by two bytes now as it would need to be cast to a list like `list(map(len,map(set,a)))`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBLCoMwFNznFA9cJCnWRbsRwdITeAA/AYtKIxpFQ2h7@TQvWehA8mbmDWTI@tXvRd3tkNd2audX18KcVdXUK7b3mhnOh2UDA1JB2yRSdf2H3bzXOo/95MouM49n3ljd73qHHBiltCYRAu8iOngUuR2JwSeEEOEU4uBCnBKjBxmfYXic1mVK0vSkU6dL1JwQbIiFsLgvlhFwMK4fymRfJ6kZ9yZmNwyaEEKsm1SabSEQBHXs@qAxDO5b3JO1otz@AQ)

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 20 bytes

```
c≡ᵍ∋Ȯ&;I∋₎;J∋₎gȮ∧I;J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P/lR58KHW3sfdXSfWKdm7QmkHzX1WXtB6PQT6x51LPe09vr/P1pJGQSUdEC0H5RWRtCx/6MA)

Outputs `[I,J]`, where `I` is the row index and `J` the column index, both 0-indexed.

Stupidely long, but getting indexes in Brachylog is usually very verbose.

#### Explanation

```
c                       Concatenate the Input into a single string
 ≡ᵍ                     Group identical characters together
   ∋Ȯ                   Ȯ is a list of One element, which is the needle character
     &;I∋₎              Take the Ith row of the Input
          ;J∋₎          Take the Jth character of the Ith row
              gȮ        That character, when wrapped in a list, is Ȯ
                ∧I;J    The output is the list [I,J]
```

Answer (score 6):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>99</del> 85 bytes

Using string without newlines and the width (or height) `('########N###########', 5`) as input.

- -5 bytes by removing chr() call, props to @Titus
- -9 bytes by taking input as two function args, also props to @Titus

```php
function($a,$l){return[($p=strpos($a,array_flip(count_chars($a,1))[1]))%$l,$p/$l|0];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDBS8MwGMXv/Ss@tkgS@MBWUYq16kXwIHPnlayE2tLO2IYkPcjc317TrbQHf4fwHu/xSKJrPTw@61oDqdKh6tvCNV3LiESi@NGUrjdtxohOrTO6s2MgjZE/eaUazYqub11e1NKck4jzLBKcXxGFRF8T9RuK5DQkxJXWWUghCwAyup7YrBco3gk8p/sLm/0MxdspO1x4OcxQvJ@yXRzHFG8m581ucU//eVgkxSgUgUiCoOpMKYuawXRjab0CDke/AmVRd1DUffuVW60ax4jLQoH@9G9GoBlFaL616j5LtsIV@h8dh@aO3xlrwte2b9v89eN9FklwGv4A)

Ungolfed:

```php
function need_hay( $a, $l ) {

    // identify the "needle" by counting the chars and 
    // looking for the char with exactly 1 occurrence
    // note: this is 1 byte shorter than using array_search()
    $n = array_flip( count_chars( $a, 1 ) )[1];

    // find the location in the input string
    $p = strpos( $a, $n );

    // row is location divided by row length, rounded down
    $r = floor( $p / $l );

    // column is remainder of location divided by row length
    $c = $p % $l;

    return array( $c, $r );

}
```

Output:

```php
#####
###N#
#####
#####
[3,1]

^^^
^^^
^N^
^^^
^^^
^^^
[1,2]

jjjjjj
j@jjjj
jjjjjj
[1,1]
```

Comment: 1) no need for `chr`: If the second parameter for strpos is an integer, it will be interpreted as an ASCII code. -> -5 bytes. 2) Two function parameters `$s,$w` can save another 9 bytes.

Comment: @Titus, removing the chr() that's brilliant. Thx!  The func params did occur to me too, I just didn't want to run afowl of input req's. I'll clarify w/OP.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 6 bytes

Saved 3 bytes switching input format.

Input is taken as a string and a row-length.
Output is a zero-based list of the form `[y, x]`

```
D.mks‰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fRS83u/hRw4b//@0wgRWCyWVoAAA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/m9t9FLze7@FHDhv86/5WhwE8ZAbhMueIgwC8ODriMubIgwCELDrjMuKIsLCy4jLiAZBSQssMEVggml6EBAA)

**Explanation**

```
D           # duplicate the input string
 .m         # get the least frequent character
   k        # get its index in the string
    s       # swap the row length to the top of the stack
     ‰      # divmod the index of the least frequent char with the row length
```

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it. Was working on an answer. Had just finished a 13-byter. But yours is way better, so +1 instead. :) Completely forgot about `.m`..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Yeah. I don't think I've ever used  `.m` before, but I was reasonably sure I'd seen it at some point :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/reference/), <s>75</s> 66 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to [@ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39244/ascii-only)

```python
lambda x:where(x.view('i')-median(x.view('i')))
from numpy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZJNDsIgFIT3nOJFFwVT3bhpmmg8QQ9QfxJMIWKEEqTaxnj2itaFFrWNJLNg3jfDW6Aru8vVtOazVX2gcptRKOPzjhmGy8lJsDMOREDGkmWCqleLEMRNLkEVUlcgpM6NHdVC6cIeYQYYgTvUGFrh5TIYBmFL6/BBPM87kXQSw77EmoTvm2yc36id/j1J/sh0Trzt9s731W64u4te1Icu783U@ZGXjhrXo6OvdPqBnju/W@22Pqn4r9T8viMiCPHcQAlCQfNj40eVNkJZXJKXCx8kjGUHBuII1MKFu/F1slIDUt8A)

This assumes that the input is a NumPy array. The output is zero-indexed, and first vertical, then horizontal.

It converts the input from `char` to `int` then calculates the median of the array, which will be the haystack character. We subtract that from the array, which makes the needle the only non-zero element. Finally, return the index of that element with `numpy.where()`.

Comment: Since you know the input will be ASCII (i.e. fits in a byte) why not use `uint8` for one byte less?

Comment: Language has to be "Python 3 + numpy" here since numpy isn't included with the normal Python distribution

Comment: @Draconis that was actually my plan, but that introduced zeros between the correct `uint8` ASCII-codes. I assume this is because Python3 uses Unicode as standard input format for strings.

Comment: also it would be nice if you linked "numpy" to numpy's website

Comment: [74](https://tio.run/##nVNLasMwEN3rFEOysASuFsnGuCT0BD5A0gQElolKPRay3MiUnN2RYyhtLBqRgbfQvI9mMaN7e2pwPQyq1o2xgF2texAtICllBRV1LHcbx7@UPNNEoV2vEvZqpO0MAvLzSRpJ3QvyWpZKoJezQaHubAsboAR8IRfGiJ7u98kySe9wSG@an/qrKSI0y3jNgaX3Ex09M2Ge8IgrnvRFcIFJPzwzxzxl7L9F6gJ5gZ93nskCCdnUDziyfxy7oGPrmceYJ8b48id923FSwgipGgMOFMK02fktTBt/DX7ffz2qRSFl@SlBtSAsfI/Xc@HvuGDDFQ)

Comment: Also, might want to ask OP if it's ok to take input already converted to `uint32`

Comment: [69](https://tio.run/##nZNNbsIwEIX3PsUIFthVyqJsoiBQT5AD8FMpUsbCiDjW4BRHVc8eHNJFiWkTYWkWfvO951mMTW0PpV40jaSyAF0VpgZVmJLsC8tRguROJG7l5p8KL1xpu3gTS0JbkYbLAQm5ey0wV5n2oGiUNpU9wwo4A38yoqzm2@1sOot6tY9uxM@5J9JBYjqW2IvofpIPr3fVd//fSZ/wDHaC6Y5eD6uf0Krvo6gHWcGbG6/HgTvu1ICO/6Q3D@i114ernzbGlTzlWrczMsGYLAkcKA3dxia3KEN@wf0e/7rISYqYnxDUGTILX@1/@J7v9EQ0Vw)

Comment: [66](https://tio.run/##nZJNDsIgFIT3nOJFFwVT3bhpmmg8QQ9QfxJMIWKEEqTaxnj2itaFFrWNJLNg3jfDW6Aru8vVtOazVX2gcptRKOPzjhmGy8lJsDMOREDGkmWCqleLEMRNLkEVUlcgpM6NHdVC6cIeYQYYgTvUGFrh5TIYBmFL6/BBPM87kXQSw77EmoTvm2yc36id/j1J/sh0Trzt9s731W64u4te1Icu783U@ZGXjhrXo6OvdPqBnju/W@22Pqn4r9T8viMiCPHcQAlCQfNj40eVNkJZXJKXCx8kjGUHBuII1MKFu/F1slIDUt8A)

Comment: Wow nice @ASCII-only. I included this in my answer, please let me know if this is ok with you or if you'd prefer to create a separate answer.

Comment: It's fine, after all it's not only based off your solution, but also I don't normally use numpy anyway. Plus, it's kinda unavoidable that a solution might be very similar anyway given that all solutions are public _and_ this is a relatively easy challenge

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 55 bytes

Takes input as \$(s)(w)\$, where \$s\$ is a string and \$w\$ is the width of the matrix. Returns \$[x,y]\$.

```javascript
s=>w=>[(i=s.indexOf(/(.)\1+(.)/.exec(s+s)[2]))%w,i/w|0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7fCoIwFIfvfYpBRDtozj8UJig9Qd1rCaEzlHDRNLvo3c3pEIuwzsX4nbPzfVt@up94fMuu5bJgCW1Sr@GeX3t@iDOP61mR0Mc@xQTrcDDV9iQ6fdAYc5VDaB0B5rWWkfppHJuYFZxdqH5hZ5xihAhBrCqvVekiWzMVhBYzUQukyrwb5dl7VgCvAJQJpalZYj2KIgmO0u7L7C21entK39q7D@ddSTDfjpv@phWtJ0WGZoj1wJGc4wjG@udxZ2CC38ymZ/yhJDv07ufAF1LTAGhe)

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>65</s>  64 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Neil*

Takes input as a matrix of characters. Returns \$[x,y]\$.

```javascript
m=>m.some((r,y)=>r.some((c,x)=>!m[p=[x,y],~y&1].includes(c)))&&p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY/dCoIwGIbPvYqFYBuspXViwkZX0AUoCrI0FHXiT@RJt25WasvC6Dt73u15vy32z37JiyivVpk4Bm1I25SylJQiDSAscIMoK3ri@NLRInVy6lxw4@JroxkuiTKe1MeghBwhpGl5y0VWiiQgiTjBEDpgvQairvK6ssAWGwoADiFkqd5n6WKJDxNWv7DiIqTMbDDwZjA8z5P8CR1mzj5pfmu3dPxW/BjJj/fToL/xo1PH@mDYpqSb5j/PMd9U@6e6e6lsHKlizKxvIXv2tzc)

#### How?

We look for the first character \$c\$ located at \$(x,y)\$ which does not appear anywhere in another row \$r[Y]\$. We can perform this test on any row, as long as \$Y\ne y\$. Because the input matrix is guaranteed to be at least \$2\times 2\$, we can simply use \$Y=0\$ if \$y\$ is odd or \$Y=1\$ if \$y\$ is even.

Comment: `~y&1` saves a byte over `y&1^1`.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>132</s> 111 bytes

```java
m->{int c=m[0][0],i=0,j;for(c=m[1][0]!=c?m[1][1]:c;;i++)for(j=m[i].length;j-->0;)if(m[i][j]!=c)return i+","+j;}
```

-8 bytes (and -13 more implicitly) thanks to *@dana*.

Input as character-matrix.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##xZBfa4MwFMXf@ynu7EvEP7Rv0qDb2PN82ZtiIUttm0xjiWlHKX52l9iu7GE6WoRdJMT7u5dzTjg5EI@vPlpakLqGV8LEaQLAhMrlmtAcYvML8KYkExugiG6JTLM0g9LGmjQTfdSKKEYhBgEhtKUXnfQ@0LBMZ5n@XBbOXI7XlUSmNze9h5A@dtd5tqAYM8exDeeas8wvcrFRW8w9L5phm62R6abcbNkyV3spgDmWazkcNy02Fnb790JbuDg5VGwFpc6Czr61XWJfghxrlZd@tVf@TiNVCCR8ikT@Cd/RzoMA1tSU5avqRZNnKckR2e4PGA/B6XiwY43dPfhtCZbLZZ/QEIrv2roF3R@Jd9WnxJ8G6W@791tJgj6hIBhNJOgXScYTSf41STKeSHStPrHrwOLPiWjAVjNp2i8)

**Explanation:**

```java
m->{                    // Method with char-matrix parameter and String return-type
  int c=m[0][0],        //  Character to check, starting at the one at position 0,0
      i=0,j;            //  Index integers
  for(c=m[1][0]!=c?     //  If the second character does not equal the first:
         m[1][1]        //   Use the character at position 1,1 instead
        :c;             //  Else: keep the character the same
      ;i++)             //  Loop `i` from 0 indefinitely upwards:
    for(j=m[i].length;j-->0;)
                        //   Inner loop `j` in the range (amount_of_columns, 0]:
      if(m[i][j]!=c)    //    If the `i,j`'th character doesn't equal our character to check:
        return i+","+j;}//     Return `i,j` as result
```

Comment: [124](https://tio.run/##xZBfa4MwFMXf@ynu7IvBP7Rv0qDb2PN82ZtiIUttm0xjiWlHKX52l9iu7GE6WoRdJJj7u5dzTjg5EI@vPlpakLqGV8LEaQLAhMrlmtAcYnMFeFOSiQ1Qm26JTLM0gxJhTZqJPmpFFKMQg4AQ2tKLTnofaFims0x/LgtnLsfrStqmNze9h5A@dr/zbEExC0OGmeMgM8P1DMv8IhcbtcXc86IZRmxtm27KzSaSudpLAcyxXMvh@Hy1LNy02PjZ7d8L7edi61CxFZQ6mH0Oob0TdEl1rFVe@tVe@TuNVCFs4VNb5J/wnfM8CGBNTVm@ql40eZaSHG3k/oDxEJyOBzvWoO71b0uwXC77hIZQfNfWLej@SLyrPiX@NEh/273fShL0CQXBaCJBv0gynkjyr0mS8USia/WJXQcWf05EA7aaSdN@AQ "Java (JDK) – Try It Online") - the final `return` statement should never get hit. There might be a better way to keep the outer loop going?

Comment: @dana Thanks! As for: "_There might be a better way to keep the outer loop going?_", there certainly is; just removing it so it becomes an infinite loop. And then the `return"";` is unreachable and can be removed as well. :D So -21 bytes thanks to you.

Comment: Interesting... I had tried removing the outer loop condition and was getting an `unreachable code` error. Didn't know that removing the final `return` was the fix.

Comment: What exactly does the --> operator do in the inner loop? I was trying to find the java docs for that syntax but couldnt find anything

Comment: @KBusc It's two operators: `i--` and `>`. :) [See this SO answer for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c) So the `i > 0` is executed first, checking if `i` is larger than 0. And then `i` is decreased by 1 with `i--`, before it enters the body of the loop.

Comment: Huh, neat, I dindt know you could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

Outputs **[height, width]** (1-indexed).

```
ŒĠLÐṂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opCMLfA5PeLiz6f/h9kdNa9yA2P3//@hodWUQUNdRADH8YAxlJEasDpdCtHpcXBxICEb5ofAQFERxFhiAxLIc4CyIGERBlAVIyMICyrWAcKOgXDs4AAnDOVYoPDv12FgA)

```
ŒĠLÐṂ – Monadic link / Full program. Takes a list of strings M as input.
ŒĠ    – Group the multidimensional indices by their values (treating M as a matrix).
  LÐṂ – And retrieve the shortest group of indices (those of the unique character).
```

---

#### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ŒĠḊÐḟ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opCMLHu7oOjzh4Y75/w@3P2pa4wbE7v//R0erK4OAuo4CiOEHYygjMWJ1uBSi1ePi4kBCMMoPhYegIIqzwAAkluUAZ0HEIAqiLEBCFhZQrgWEGwXl2sEBSBjOsULh2anHxgIA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sub>Maybe this could've just been a comment for Mr. Xcoder it is pretty similar...</sub>

```
ŒĠEƇ
```

A monadic link accepting the matrix of characters which yields a list of one item, the  1-indexed (row, column) co-ordinate from top-left.
(...As a full program given an argument formatted such that parsing results in a list of lists of characters -- that is a list of strings in Python format -- the single coordinate is printed.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opCMLXI@1////P1pdXT0LDIAMLh0QzwGFB5eLBQA)**

#### How?

```
ŒĠEƇ - Link: matrix, M
ŒĠ   - multi-dimensional indices grouped by Value
     -  ...due to the 2*2 minimum size and one needle this will be a list of two lists one
     -     of which will have length one (the needle coordinates as a pair) and the other
     -     containing all other coordinates as pairs
   Ƈ - filter keeping those for which this is truthy:
  E  -   all equal?
     -   ... 1 for the list of length 1, 0 for the list of at least 3 non-equal coordinates
```

Comment: Well... this seems borderline, since the `EƇ` is clever.

Answer (score 3):

## Wolfram Language <s>37</s> 58 bytes

My earlier entry did not correctly handle the case where the "odd character out" was at the upper left corner of the matrix.  This does.

```
#~Position~Keys[TakeSmallest[Counts@Flatten@#,1]][[1]]&
```

---

`Counts@Flatten@#` lists how many of each character are in the array, `#`.

`TakeSmallest[...,1]` returns the least frequent count, in the form of an association rule such as `<| "Z"->1|>`

`Keys...[[1]]` returns the "key" to the only item in the association, that of the least used character. ("Z" in the present case)

`#~Position~...` returns then position of the key in the original matrix, `#`.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> 8 bytes

```
tX:XM-&f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyTCKsJXVy3t//9oBXV9dQV1RXUwbQ0iwCwYqRALAA)

Using the `mode` function as the majority-detector. Returns 1-based indices.

```
 t           % duplicate the input
  X:         % turn the copy into a linear array
    XM       % find the arithmetic mode of that (the 'haystack' character)
      -      % Subtract that from the original input
       &f    % find the position of the non-zero value in that result
```

*-4 characters thanks to @LuisMendo*

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. I don't think I knew about the 2 output version of `find`, even in MATLAB. (Hi, btw!)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5 `-p00`, <s>52</s> 45 bytes

```
/^(.)(\1*
)*(\1*)|^/;$_=$&=~y/
//.$".length$3
```

[45 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18/TkNPUyPGUItLUwtEadbE6VurxNuqqNnWVepz6evrqSjp5aTmpZdkqBj//68MAlxA7AcmlWEkF1dcXBwE@8Uh2EDMxZUFBlxZDhAKwuPiirLgsrAA0kDCIgpI28EBgmmFLPovv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megeF/3ZwCAwMA)

[52 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@fS99apdxWyUFbyVo/TkNPUyPGsIZLU7smDigeDxZXVSnXU1HSy8wrAfH0Vcr//1cGAS4g9gOTyjCSiysuLg6C/eIQbCDm4soCA64sBwgF4XFxRVlwWVgAaSBhEQWk7eAAwbRCFv2XX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwPC/bk6BgQEA)

How

- `-p00` : like `-n` but also print, paragraph mode
- `/^(.)(\1*
  )*(\1*)|^/` : matches either

  - from start `$1`: first character, `$2`: repetition (not used), `$3`: characters before the "needle" in the line, `$&` whole match
  - or null string (position 0) no capture.
- `$_=` : to assign the default input/argument variable
- so `$&=~y/
  //` the number of newlines of `$&`
- `.$".` : concatenate with `$"` (space character by default) and concatenate
- `length$3` : the length of `$3`

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) 42 bytes

```r
function(m)which(ave(m,m,FUN=length)==1,T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9RS8MwFIXf8ysCPtwEsmHbKWXYsZcNfFEQ9yJ9KaW1Gc21tDfaf18jsZtlbLhLHkJO7jnfaYeSP8z4UFrMSX@gMPKr0nklss9CGGXUdveU1AW@UyWTJFCvcmA3fNNnpqkLHrA8IwEpbvo5D1JMESQzP4aw97PeHwa8YrHWHYmO2q6pNbkQAPm7ZTJqde@eeKT4vRzdH7GxtPTmLv3F4jH52dJBLB09Y6MCfr8tGgEzUIs7l/KHPRz/efpwQr86neXxem2T4PZSlfB8lf81iaZNokmTtziOr@IN3bmEG53DHb4B)

**Input:** a haystack matrix `m`

**Output:** `(row,col)` vector - index starting at `1`

Comment: Nice job, and welcome to PPCG! I believe this is 42 bytes, since the `f=` can be omitted from the byte count, but not the `function(m)=`.

Comment: @BLT I wasn't sure about that but thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>109</s> <s>108</s> 107 bytes

<sup>First() => Last() for -1 byte</sup>

<sup>currying for -1 byte thanks to Embodiment of Ignorance</sup>

```cs
a=>w=>{var d=a.Where(b=>b!=a[0]).Select(b=>a.IndexOf(b));return d.Count()>1?(0,0):(d.Last()%w,d.Last()/w);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHva8IwEP3c/hW3ukGCWdYqG2JtNxAGgrgPDgRFobZRKy4daVyF0r@9S1p/bWPvwzW9e/fyLhem92Eal697HvZSKWK@JlD9xFwSQFVUAfs@rFQavDLw/Mzz869AQOQFdLJhgqGl5y9vvGBmzzEdsx0LpU4FdMAjdnhboSXGrmByLzhEtJ/suUTYd56RTWzcRREdBqnK3GXkdHzIsFuUrqmvkSyV/SBlKXjAWQYInZxqZ9cu8WyemwhZjSNGjQssAo@YGAagNgEHY6KJixqjxRmK1laamucQaB152xov2zMU76mWcy5y006nY@kuLaBrNgH7WFOl6Y9a3Ve4prlKhJ4BYjWg7apP7zIzHTK@lhuVbTaxmZtGP@FpsmN0ImLJ0K2Vx0UXLOyahn4rUb2SXhU6S8ziOR1I9uHUEf9XaZ1E1kkSKZU/tJb76/phzLUFdvhUG2cR5LqTvifjaj8IF0RpSciVq@usdluU3w)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

```
$#:(i.~.{~1 i.~#/.~)@,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxNC4JAFEX3/opLRk/BJj8qbEQxAiEQidy5cCOJ2aJFixaBf92eaUp0hmFm3px763YmqIQvQTBgQvJeChzOcdTOValdRSNejQU@1ZVo9NBodUUpqpsvoC1lqS@ClfKo7k9@X4rqHmoGNIr2x5g8Ou3TlHS8GnCAY50HCw48rLHBHKQOJOoE9Z7Npoct2@zlPUk@Qt@2znLYY6vuCeuRwTJ5edxod1bmuu5PepjzOBvnu0@rZXYfwT9yupLSvgE)

NB. returns answer in (row, column) format.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>53</s> 47 bytes

```python
lambda s,w:divmod(s.find(min(s,key=s.count)),w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFYp9wqJbMsNz9Fo1gvLTMvRSM3M0@jWCc7tdK2WC85vzSvRFNTp1zzf0FRZl6JQpqGkjIU@CkjgJKOgqnmfwA)

Call as `f("########N###########", 5)` (allowed in a [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179351/find-the-needle-in-the-haystack#comment432444_179351)). Outputs `(y, x)`.

Erik saved 6 bytes, suggesting rearranging the output + using `divmod`. Thanks!

Comment: You can reorder the output, so you can [use the `divmod` builtin](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFYp9wqJbMsNz9Fo1gvLTMvRSM3M0@jWCc7tdK2WC85vzSvRFNTp1zzf0FRZl6JQpqGkjIU@CkjgJKOgqnmfwA).

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>107</s> <s>98</s> <s>82</s> 77 bytes

```powershell
$l=@{}
$args|%{if($_-10){$l.$_+=$x++,+$y}else{$x=0;++$y}}
$l|% v*|? c*t -eq 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBRboMwDIbfc4ooNSs0KYLuhXVizQl6gD6AEEvXdZHWAduoAmdnDhTY9kt27N@fFcmX929VlCeldQdHGlPTgY6laQlkxUvZOOb16EK6DgPPgPYh5THUnAsO11bpUhmo4@CR2xZXdOPQr1Wzo/mqomv1QTddS4h0CRGuXJIkSYbYJ3ONsZQiFBvvRvlWNu/8ucaM1L0IR2phZfN@MdeY/1LnXuQsh2fo@u8m5BCRKLJeIILRQyM6/OOeJs3l9reL@EOPe7ShDjWEouCUXcsqy98EqPqi8ko945EhHYaFKj91hcYd3l6OaD9j4LLbnOEl2bTOvO24yEjb/QA)

Takes a splatted string with LFs. Returns zero-indexed location x,y. Unrolled:

```powershell
$locations=@{}                      # make a hashtable. key=char, value=location array
$args|%{
    if($_-10){                      # if current char is not LF
        $locations.$_+=$x++,+$y     # add $x,$y to hashtable value and move $x to next pos
    }else{
        $x=0;++$y                   # move $x,$y to next line
    }
}
$locations|% Values|? Count -eq 2   # find and output location array with 2 elements (x,y)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 98 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHBToQwEIbv@xST7qWN2oMnQsJGH2DxQLysiqlsWUugYNsQdd1nx6EB2SUhTgLlm/@fTunYTJSiq98KmTnYCqXhuALYyxwqBCrMwYZwb4z4ekqcUfrwwkJ41MpB5J0ArSjBSessZhL5QX0SgBCy7mNAgB@E@BLXc8QibrFNs8XGSl9Pe6VpOnkvIV5UZrC8e@FjMhd3M/axXL8LJm8QLPuCc99u5vMS8@@uH0BOqxAv9O/eo4o7I7Rtait5JRr6yl2dSMet@paMK72Xnw85vWVhWP2jx6rs@j5@bjyvjRTZOxw9Q7QZDtlPtsWp9llum1I5Sp41YaM8FtIGD@hKPQoDUoLfNxsgcIX/0jJcpvLTqn9Oq@4X)

```scala
def f(m:Seq[String])=m.transpose.map(_.toSet.size).indexOf(2)::m.map(_.toSet.size).indexOf(2)::Nil
```

Ungolfed version. Try it online!

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val tests = Seq(
      """#####
        |###N#
        |#####
        |#####""".stripMargin,
      """^^^
        |^^^
        |^N^
        |^^^
        |^^^
        |^^^""".stripMargin,
      """jjjjjj
        |j@jjjj
        |jjjjjj""".stripMargin,
      """Z8
        |88""".stripMargin,
      """88
        |8Z""".stripMargin
    )
    
    val f: Seq[String] => Seq[Int] = m => m.transpose.map(_.toSet.size).indexOf(2) :: m.map(_.toSet.size).indexOf(2) :: Nil

    tests.foreach { test =>
      val v = test.split("\n")
      v.foreach(println)
      println("   -> " + f(v) + "\n")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 78 bytes

```
s->(n=argmin(x->count(x,'
's),s);q=split(s);~=findlast;b=~(n.∈q);(n~q[b],b))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVAxDoJAEIztvuKiBXfJYQQtLpIjvoAHaCQBBQPBU7wjsaL2DzY0FD5JS18icooNiZPMzhYzO8le67TIkqC6iSjaZhHiqC5UbLK7J00XCx6cdvtE4LPpbg6FUPhMDTAkoZI4OZfHLFG4WUseJ2KbBVI5IS-xGD8vl5w4WJT5KlzTkBB99TEwABaBlNFJId2IYTh6Axp67Rx95hAI4hzhGbVJT8r3fWjpfVTzm7LptC-VtoB0oaXFL9JbtGTA2NdjUavPwxrP8s8dtwN02_y3ul3FpMnrf1WV1hc)

This function takes input as a single string, which probably isn't the most efficient approach. The output is 1-indexed.

-19 bytes thanks to MarcMush: add a newline to the haystack to guarantee that the needle is always the least frequent character, even in a 2x2 haystack.

Interestingly, concatenating a character literal with a string variable doesn't require an operator in Julia. Apparently, it's parsed just like [numeric literal coefficients with variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#man-numeric-literal-coefficients). This saves a byte here, which is the best thing to come out of [Julia's choice of concatenation operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#Why-does-Julia-use-*-for-string-concatenation?-Why-not-or-something-else?).

Comment: Julia, 78 bytes: [`s->(n=argmin(x->count(x,'
's),s);q=split(s);~=findlast;b=~(n.∈q);(n~q[b],b))`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVAxDoJAEIztvuKiBXfJYQQtLpIjvoAHaCQBBQPBU7wjsaL2DzY0FD5JS18icooNiZPMzhYzO8le67TIkqC6iSjaZhHiqC5UbLK7J00XCx6cdvtE4LPpbg6FUPhMDTAkoZI4OZfHLFG4WUseJ2KbBVI5IS-xGD8vl5w4WJT5KlzTkBB99TEwABaBlNFJId2IYTh6Axp67Rx95hAI4hzhGbVJT8r3fWjpfVTzm7LptC-VtoB0oaXFL9JbtGTA2NdjUavPwxrP8s8dtwN02_y3ul3FpMnrf1WV1hc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <strike>103</strike> 91 bytes

```lua
s,l=...s:gsub('.',load'c=...b=b or not s:find(c..c,1,1)and s:find(c,1,1)')print(b%l-1,b//l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RchBCoAgEADArwgRKmwrHroEfaE/uEoRLBpZ798oouY4fAaRCjwiYh2WepLRqIFLSDreSSOpsqtcDlWHec3JRMQIHrwNOX33hLbbvubDUMudB3KOrYg0r6n5SX8B)

Ungolfed version:

```lua
s,l=...                                           --Take in haystack and line width as args
s:gsub('.',function (d)                           --For each character in s
    b=b or not s:find(c..c,1,1)and s:find(c,1,1)  --If there is only one instance of c, store location
end)
print(b%l-1,b//l)                                 --Print results
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

this can probably be golfed down a bit as there's a lot of register shenanigans i'm not a huge fan of. takes an array of a single string with a width

```
Ç║æ░·╝;J╕╤¢ⁿÿì<
```

[Try it online! (With test cases)](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80ba91b0fabc3b4ab8d19bfc988d3c&i=%5B5,%22%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23N%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%22%5D%0A%5B2,+%22Z888%22%5D%0A%5B2,+%22888Z%22%5D%0A%5B10,+%22%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3A%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%22%5D%0A%5B6,+%22jjjjjjj%40jjjjjjjjjj%22%5D%0A%5B3,+%22%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5EN%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%22%5D&m=2)

This is Packed Stax, which unpacks to the following:

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 17 bytes

```
Nc|!IYxhX%yx/2l|u
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=Nc%7C%21IYxhX%25yx%2F2l%7Cu&i=%5B5,%22%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23N%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%22%5D%0A%5B2,+%22Z888%22%5D%0A%5B2,+%22888Z%22%5D%0A%5B10,+%22%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3A%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%22%5D%0A%5B6,+%22jjjjjjj%40jjjjjjjjjj%22%5D%0A%5B3,+%22%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5EN%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%22%5D&m=2)

```
N                 # get the string
 c|!              # get the rarest element
    I             # get the first index in the string of this
     Y            # store that in register Y
      xh          # get the width
        X         # and store this value in register x
         %        # modulo with what was stored in register Y
          yx      # register y and register x from above
            /     # divide them
             2l   # create an array of the top two elements on the stack
               |u # and put it in a format which can be printed
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 93 bytes

```python
def f(s):x=s.find("\n")+1;return[(i%x,i//x)for i,c in enumerate(s)if s.count(c)<2and" "<c][0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBbCoMwEPzfUywpBUPFvn7EVukJPIBWQTShKW0sSQRL6dltYu1jYHZnmQR29nY3p1Zuh6FhHLmnadTHOuBCNh45SkIX651iplMy98S898Vy2VPeKhR@jUIik92Vqcow@1Nw1EHddtJ4Nd1vKtkQJPu6yFfFoI3SGGNOCJk5gGU61tlUreNblmUJI9Opvzm55xFwPrzbiMnKQgjDj84g@@jkC/iq6CcT@6QAcJG0C@QWjQAtbkrYJJr@DZykjDUXhkJjZfDh7vUM3JmGFw)

Input is taken as a multiline string. Output is 0-indexed

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 40 bytes

```matlab
@(x){[r,c]=find(x-mode(+x(:))) [c,r]}{2}
```

Port of [@sundar's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179361/36398). Output is a two-element vector with 1-based column and row indices.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCszq6SCc51jYtMy9Fo0I3Nz8lVUO7QsNKU1NTITpZpyi2ttqo9n@agq1CYl6xNVeaRrS6MgioWyuAGH4whjISI1bzPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 41 bytes

```
s`(?=(.)+\1)(.*?¶)*(.*)(?!\1|¶).+
$.3,$#2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@/OEHD3lZDT1M7xlBTQ0/L/tA2TS0gralhrxhjWAPk6WlzqegZ66goG/3/rwwCXEDsByaVoSQA) 0-indexed. Explanation:

```
s`
```

Allow `.` to match newlines. This costs 3 bytes (3rd byte is the `?` before the `¶`) but saves 6 bytes.

```
(?=(.)+\1)
```

Look ahead for two identical characters. `\1` then becomes the hay.

```
(.*?¶)*
```

Count the number of newlines before the needle.

```
(.*)
```

Capture the hay to the left of the needle.

```
(?!\1|¶)
```

Ensure that the needle isn't hay or a newline.

```
.+
```

Match the rest of the hay so that the result replaces it.

```
$.3,$#2
```

Output the width of the left hay and the number of newlines.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 82 bytes

```cs
x=>w=>{int y=x.IndexOf(x.GroupBy(c=>c).Last(g=>g.Count()<2).Key);return(y%w,y/w);}
```

Thanks to dana for shaving off 6 bytes!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYvbCsIwDIbvfQpRhARmPaEMtxZRUETRS8ELQWo3uosqXcdWxGef9YCC84OEJP8XnrZ5Kst5pniYGi1V7D1nqYwHj@YKGYtoWVCWU3Z1e93SgizVSRTbCAqy0OfsMrXAKeNI1sfUQExZTGbnTBnAsI9kJSwGWphMK7Ct3LOdHINbGdR2WhqxlkpABI3mm03zSwNhiPgjHl5sDh@cNqhoyYtJ8sFpo4q2933fBf1K4O77vwGrMv6O7qXXdT/lHQ)

## Old solution, 106 bytes

```cs
n=>m=>{var z=n.Distinct();int d=n.IndexOf(n.Count(c=>c==z.First())>1?z.Last():z.First());return(d%m,d/m);}
```

Both take input as a string and an integer specifying the amount of columns.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYtdC4IwFIbv@xWRBBuYfVGIthUUQSB1GXghyNRY4Am2GWH02@2UkYQ9sPHynucVeiC0rLYFiIU2SsLJfmcJxiavDx/lPGMVMJ4zfr/GqlsycDZSGwnCEOqj0k2w2kGS3g4ZAWd9KcAQwbhgrHS2Umn0KB8vSyeIX9lrWl@lplBAkn5uJ8Oc@o/K7xyVNGkgISUZ6Vkf9lZDj5IZbn/FqGYffUFt2tLONavzF9TmLS10XRcPk9YB@/DvgbfxmoiT8Qg31RM)

Comment: @dana never knew that `Enumerable.Last()` accepted a delegate, thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 74 bytes

```c
h(char*s,z,x){for(s+=z--;*s==*--s|*s==s[-1];)z--;printf("%d,%d",z%x,z/x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLbaoNAEEDf9ysWg7DaWeolinQx9AvyAQmxiDbV0JjgmiJav93uVhOwXug8LWfmzAzLRDT6DLOPtk1IlIS5zqGCUquPl5zwJ7@ilOnc93VK@bd88D01D0yT/JqnWXEkihqDGitQqSVUz6XGmhbLTpi/mfsD9nGtnH5DQXgYyul1hnf1DfubQffOVt85CIKxPg23/66cgw3DswvZ/UIrGWNdwO00Xs3ipXHrftzOG9uet6g6vepNqbtF1e3VzSPGLR6pl4Xc5j4Goa9LGuMz0errrZBjiGmIE0JI3BY@h2lGNFyjbouEiJMC0wNXE5chHNYxSzJ7yGywDHCGbA1rsIbIGSMXbAPkEqj7iPy9uOUZNhhq2h8)

DEGOLF

```c
int h(char*s,int z,int x){// z = string size, x = row size

 for(s+=z--;
 // move pointer just over the end of the string 
 // and move z counter to the end of string

*s-*--s?   ==>  *s==*--s|  @ceilingcat suggestion 
 // if the previous element is different we will check if the next element is also different
 // if not the result is 1 and the iteration continue
 // in the first iteration it will be different because the pointer is just  over the end

 *s-s[-1]? ==> changed to *s==s[-1]   @ceilingcat suggestion 
 // the second check returns 0 if the char changed again so it was the needle
 // if not it's because in the first iteration the first check finded a difference just because the pointer was just over the end

 /*0:1*/   :1;)z--;


 printf("%d,%d",z%x,z/x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>93</s> <s>89</s> <s>85</s>  58 bytes

Complete rewrite taking input as `concatenated string, width`:

```python
lambda g,w:divmod(g.index({g.count(c):c for c in g}[1]),w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9NCoMwEIXXzSmGdJMUEVPpRvAk1sWYtDFYE1FbK6Vnt7FYQfpgZuCbH940Y186G09Vep5uWBcKQQdDosyjdorp0Fh1ebKXDqW7255Jnki4uhYkGAv6nYmcBwOfShy7HmXVQQoZYTRaJeZEAzjxwHNELHygB8cZAA3/tF@qnxHxd0tEG/2uAd1ysTRyQmaL5WxxNZaQXdMa/0LFDiXn0wc)

---

Original answer:

```python
def k(g):t=''.join(g);return divmod(t.index({t.count(c):c for c in t}[1]),len(g[0]))
```

EDIT: Saved 4 bytes by swapping linebreak/indent for semicolons. Saved another 4 bytes by using `divmod`(thanks @JonathanFrech).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU9BDoIwEDzbV2zwQJuQhsYbhpc0HGoLUtGWQDES49uRVjAcdC8zuzObybSjq605TJMqK2jwmWQuj2N6sdrMy7Er3dAZUPp@swo7qo0qH/jpqLSDcViSTEJlO5CgDbgXZwVJruX8ytOCEDTVYuydkE0POXDEIUr9RCjZMhZYkSBvECLcxOkDYoVFptsJWmD79bLY2I@YdBuT/jEwbygQ8qVqX@rbIEO7ttNz6QbXhExv)

I know this could be a lot shorter, but I just wanted to try an approach around this `dict` comprehension.

Comment: Using `divmod` would save five bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8, 104 Bytes

```
(x,w)->{int i=0,p=x.length;for(;i<p;i++)if(x[i]!=x[(i+1)%p]&&x[i]!=x[(i+2)%p])break;return i/w+","+i%w;}
```

Input is array of char, and integer indicating row width.

Output is zero-based, vertical then horizontal (i.e., row number then column number)

Explanation:

```
(x,w)->{
    int i=0, p=x.length;
    for (;i<p;i++)          //iterate through characters in x
      if (x[i]!=x[(i+1)%p] && x[i]!=x[(i+2)%p])    //compare x[i] with the two subsequent characters in array, wrapping around if necessary
        break;
    return i/w+","+i%w;}  //return row number then column number, zero-based
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. In a sense, this is actually a kind of poly-glot, as it takes as argument either a character matrix or a list of strings, with the code meaning something else in each case. Always returns `[row,column]` in which ever index origin is currently active. (APL lets you choose.)

```apl
⍸↑=∊~∘∊∩/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/x/17njUNtH2UUdX3aOOGUDqUcdK/f9pQLlHvX0QZV3Nh9YbAxUBecFBzkAyxMMz@H@agroyCKiDaT8orYygudIUgJrU4@LigEJQ0g@JDSchCjXMHvVuUc9S11RQz3LIAgJ1BbgQ1KgoC6AOCwuYyRZgbhRMv6EBSLUdyAA7GLACGgIXBwA)

**If the argument is a matrix, the function works like this:**

`∩/` intersection reduction of each row. Since there will be at least one all-hay row, this gives us at least one hay character. And since every row has at least one hay character, the intersection will always empty out the row that has the needle character.

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten) this, giving us one or more hay characters

`∘` then…

`~` remove all such characters from…

`∊` the **ϵ**nlisted (flattened) argument, leaving just the needle

`↑=` Boolean matrix indicating where the matrix equals the needle

`⍸` the indices where true

**If the argument is a list of strings, the function works like this:**

`∩/` intersection reduction of the strings. Since only one string will have a needle, and all strings have hay, this will give us one or more hay characters without the needle character.

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten) this, giving us the one or more hay characters

`∘` then…

`~` remove all such characters from…

`∊` the **ϵ**nlisted (flattened) argument, leaving just the needle

`↑=` Boolean matrix indicating where the matrix constructed by merging the strings equals the needle

`⍸` the indices where true

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 43 bytes

Takes the haystack as a single line and its width as arguments. Returns the 0-based row, then column as an array.

```ruby
->s,w{(/[^#{s[/(.)(?=\1)/]}]/=~s).divmod w}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3tXXtinXKqzX0o-OUq4uj9TX0NDXsbWMMNfVja2P1beuKNfVSMsty81MUymuhWtILFNyiuZSUQUBJG8zwgzGUkRg6CqaxXFwQxVlgAJLLcoCzIGI6CmZwZVEWIAkLC6CgUSzEugULIDQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 49 bytes

```arturo
$[s w]->/%index s first select tally s[k v][1=v]w
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?kVhqOw)

Takes input as a single line and a width. Returns a 0-indexed `[row col]` pair.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ƒ⊍hÞḟ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJBIiwiIiwixpLiio1ow57huJ8iLCIiLCJbXCIjIyMjI1wiLCBcIiMjI04jXCIsIFwiIyMjIyNcIiwgXCIjIyMjI1wiXVxuW1wiampqampqXCIsIFwiakBqampqXCIsIFwiampqampqXCJdXG5bXCJeXl5cIiwgXCJeXl5cIiwgXCJeTl5cIiwgXCJeXl5cIiwgXCJeXl5cIiwgXCJeXl5cIl1cbltcIlo4XCIsIFwiODhcIl1cbltcIjg4XCIsIFwiOFpcIl1cbltcIj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj5cIiwgXCI+Pj4+Pj4+Pj46XCIsIFwiPj4+Pj4+Pj4+PlwiXSJd)

Takes a list of lines. Outputs 0-indexed `[row, column]`. Vyncode does nothing here apparently, it decided.

### Explained

```
ƒ⊍hÞḟ
ƒ⊍    # reduce by set xor
  h   # get the first of that
   Þḟ # find it's multidimensional index
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# .NET, <s>133</s> <s>112</s> 111 bytes

```csharp
m=>{var c=m[0][0];c=m[1][0]!=c?m[1][1]:c;for(int i=0,j;;i++)for(j=m[i].Count;j-->0;)if(m[i][j]!=c)return(i,j);}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@EmbodimentOfIgnorance*.

Port of [my Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179362/52210), but with a `List<List<char>>` input and `int`-tuple output, instead of `char[][]` input and `string` output.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rVPRasIwFH33K@70JcFa9E3M2m0Mtpfqw/YwqCh0MWpKTUeSOob0211Sa6uyYWELbbjn3Jx7eksuVT2aSranSaQUjHctAKUjzSm8finNNu5TJuhtGT@mScKo5qlQ7jMTTHLqBlzpq3m6jqTvO4C40I55sQ9L8PYbz99tIwnU20z7M/MQGw1sdOPRuyIczEaULFNppcC9vhMTwrtdbKnYnOYzY5sJTeJez@8TzJfIktPYlsCS6UwKxJ0Yk3xPWqa9j@w9Me2VXW5TvoBxxAXCtncAzZRGgn2aA5KL1XR2oAHaHbvazgmcnMPONVigHJMrRvP5vFaeg8mvmUvQ0CsuVi2N7y/wId@wWjislcNhU9XwVBU2VoV/9Qobq/xq1eqKGv3A@aeV81Y9VcV9K4yOJhCVN89OQmKmBTywH/E/M4fK3sy4sIiuS1dQwEVlfLAOGvoWdY9lAQL3YbF4icSKIVWRtg3Lo6Ck8mKvSguVJsx9k1yzgAuGlsgqcPm38v03)

Comment: Can't you save two bytes by turning you `char[][]` into a `List<List<char>>`? Since `List<T>.Count` is shorter than `Array.Length`

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, <del>68</del> 22 bytes

<del>`[r,c]=find(v~=v(1));if size(r,1)>1 disp([1,1]);else disp([r,c]);end;`</del>

<del>If I could exclude any one case, such as `[1,1]` in this solution, I could have saved several bytes.</del>

**Updated solution**:

```
@(v)find(v-mode(v(:)))
```

Thanks to @sundar for helping me with the special case problem and saving 42 bytes! Also, thanks to @Luis_Mendo for the suggestions and saving me another 2 bytes!

Comment: I think you can get rid of the check for `[1,1]` case by using `mode(v(:))` instead of `v(1)`.

Comment: You need to wrap your code so that it is a full program or a function; you cannot assume that the input is in a variable `v`. Also, you can probably replace `~=` by `-`, and remove the final `;`

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
tX:YmyYk-&f
```

Output is row, then column; 1-based.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyTCKjK3MjJbVy3t//9odWUQULdWADH8YAxlJEYsAA)

#### Explanation

```
t    % Implicit input. Duplicate
X:   % Linearize into a column
Ym   % Compute mean (characters are converted to ASCII codes)
y    % Duplicate from below: pushes input again
Yk   % Closest value: gives the input value that is closest to the mean
-    % Subtract, element-wise. Gives non-zero for the value farthest from the mean
&f   % Two-output find: gives row and column indices of nonzeros. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
.Dxz-zh.-z{z
```

Takes input as the length of the row and the input without lines and outputs as [row, column].
[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.Dxz-zh.-z%7Bz&input=5%0A%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23N%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
.Dxz-zh.-z{z
       .-z{z    Subtract one of each character from the input.
      h         Take the first.
    -z          Remove all instances from the input.
  xz            Find the remaining character in the input.
.D          Q   Take the result divmod the (implicit) length of the row.
```

### Old approach

```
mxJmt{kdeSJ.TB
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mxJmt%7BkdeSJ.TB&input=%5B%27%23%23%23%23%23%27%2C+%27%23%23%23N%23%27%2C+%27%23%23%23%23%23%27%2C+%27%23%23%23%23%23%27%5D&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
mxJmt{kdeSJ.TB
           .TBQ   Take the (implicit) input and its transpose...
m      d          ... and for each...
   mt{k           ... deduplicate each row...
 xJ     eSJ       ... and find the index of the largest.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
≔§⎇⌕θ§θ¹ηθ⁰ζＳθＷ⁼№θζＬθ«⊞υωＳθ»Ｉ⌕Ｅθ⁼ιζ⁰,ＩＬυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5NCsIwEIXX7SlCu5lABF27KkWhoFLQC4S2NIGS/iSxWvHscdJWFwZm5iV872UKwYei5Y1zidayVpCYTJXVA27VoPjwhKNUJfSMfN9R7ihlRDDS49hiTXQfZqqz5moGqWro8T4K2VQEDr3ljYa0tcp464T4qVK1EUhRSl5hkFstwDIyoiv4j3mHOWoDKddmWeXMOx@0BksfOa9BkV7YiEU/PfvWD61nnIv9CbEuc4/X7jb35gM) Link is to verbose version of code. I must be doing something wrong because this is almost as long as the Retina answer. Explanation:

```
≔§⎇⌕θ§θ¹ηθ⁰ζ
```

Check whether the second character in the first string is also the first character, and take the first character of the first string if so otherwise the first character of the second string if not. This is then the hay.

```
ＳθＷ⁼№θζＬθ«⊞υωＳθ»
```

Keep reading strings until a string whose hay is less than its length is found.

```
Ｉ⌕Ｅθ⁼ιζ⁰,ＩＬυ
```

Output the position of the mismatching element and then the number of strings previously read.

Answer (score 0):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 81 bytes

```
f a{i=indexOf;l=i("
",a)+1;chars a|sort|count|[[_2,_1]]|min|i _[1],a|[_%l,_1//l]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYpBCoMwEEXX5hRDoEWpKHZZ0Sv0AGkIoSod0FFihBbHs6ctBfs2//F5bmxsCB3YFSukpn1eu7KvMJZCpjY5FeX9Yd0MlufReb6PC3lWypxTU2jNAxIjGFXo1LIyh/5z53mvtzBYJFhFhDQtHipQ2LTk0b/iRB/ljSRkGXxXRB38IobJIXkwYgv1jtjt8tf6DQ)

Takes input as a string containing newline-terminated lines. Returns a stream containing 0-indexed horizontal and vertical indexes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n0`, 77 bytes

```perl
$t=(@b=sort/./g)[0]eq$b[1]?pop@b:$b[0];++$y&/\Q$t/g&&say"$y,",pos for /.+$/mg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lxFbDIcm2OL@oRF9PP10z2iA2tVAlKdow1r4gv8AhyQrINoi11tZWqVTTjwlUKdFPV1MrTqxUUqnUUdIpyC9WSMsvUtDX01bRz03//9/Y2JgLjGOM/@UXlGTm5xX/1/U11TMwNPivm2cAAA)

Output is `row,column` starting from the top left, 1-indexed

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 64 bytes

```hs
f s=[(r,c)|c<-[0..],r<-[0..length s-1],any(notElem$s!!r!!c)s]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcbBCoMwDADQ@74ioR4UanH3edxXSA@lxLUsRmgKbuC/18EOD14K@ibm1lbQeemLjcMZH@MyOedt@YdJXjWBjndvg3x72euTaesUsSDGQT3i1LaQBWbIUqmEWKEDTfsBDtYfzkLazMfcjDEX) `f` takes a list of lines and returns zero-indexed `(row,column)`.

Works by iterating through the columns and rows and looking for a character which does not appear on all rows.

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 39 bytes

Index origin =1.
Prompts for character matrix as a string input followed by row width.
Outputs row by column index position.

```
(,(⍳i÷n)∘.,⍳n←⎕)[((1=+/m∘.≡m)/⍳i←⍴m←⎕)]
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/5r6Gg86t2ceXh7nuajjhl6OkBOHlAWqEozWkPD0FZbPxck/qhzYa6mPkglSLJ3Sy5UTex/oCn/07jU7TCBFYKpzmVoAAA)

Explanation:

```
⍳i←⍴m←⎕ Prompt for string and create a vector of indices from 1 to length string.

(1=+/m∘.≡m) Boolean vector identifying position of unique character in string.

(...)/⍳i Use Boolean to select index position of unique character.

,⍳n←⎕ Prompt for row width of character matrix and create a vector of indices.

,(⍳i÷n)∘., Create a nested vector of row by column indices of character matrix.

(...)[...] Select row by column index position of unique character.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 142 bytes

The result is zero based [vertical,horizontal].

```
{d:List<String>->val h=if(d[0][0]!=d[0][1])d[1][0]
else d[0][0]
var a=""
for(r in d.indices)for(c in d[r].indices)if(h!=d[r][c])a="[$r,$c]"
a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVh/b9tGEv1fn2KjBoh0peXYbXGpUKXNpbnAQJoUdQ6Hq2sDK3IlbUNyebtLS0rgz557M7tcUrZ7/SkYpric2Zl582ZmqXfGl7r@eHwsnlslvSrEyljhN9qJ3BRKrE25EvlGlqWq12o@guDG@8bNj4/pOT2eOS/zd2oHKYjMclMd/7dVzmtTu@OTv3/52RcnI9L7p64L7KxErVRRKqFrvtvIPW/AMi/1taqFFFblHru1pbRJQJiVcPq9EtKLUknnxenuFF5WjXHwG0/hJW/pZKVEY3Xt5RKGnp0/PzujIKzMvbIuE6b1TetZtjS5JFfFJDdt7XW9FitrKn7mTXNUqpWf0uYDz7cbnW8EIJKi0KuVsqr2/f6zEC1gVDtZNaXKhA7qK1OWZksmUkzYRNfwZc5Kn9Anfnn9ye0VfKFvb7FTDMBtTFsWYqnEZ9kJ3AJ275U1R0Ba7YDJZLsBWGePgAtkWkemGXZKb5dURGfF59lp0De16tRnyVxyN5c17XQAer3/ZaxDWFdXV8PL66t7FnGhawhsLk6yU76Xh5zZ6hAKGTVYt79m@mf@8Ldv0rew1puDtUDRM/8ISS2dEQjPadrVG0R/DYu3aJsbW3dGfnxC/588GW75OHs8iqv0/8f7zFGlxe0HMcpATFVQvZHY0/Q5uJvfejYw8CUM4O6HtlSOIXyOQtIrHajuWJQ@Z0Q9FoiKMb9rLsPlnnHOTY07TRyvlN@YYgZOgECVkrUTe9OylpfvVKCykFQYpUaBgh7ddVh@LEBkRLTOI4HrTCifzzq3/hP35NwyGFa5tvSE1vnbb9/86y1BZ5VvbS10NLhq65wLOcjOxPfUJMgA2hplDZ5a4dplpZFayHFtGFsoyyYiAlyQYqJnapaJjbH6vQG/uK/U4lpZDxBLDqGlAujY0BVTRp5d61yRrJPTFNMLzXQlP0Hhxpq1lRUJDzyXFtnPc9UwoQ/gKIyojRdrxSA0GrUYulCPKz2AT5QdSTw@8CttdlDOCHbdQr/2oB7pL291V4RHLTcTKAlNm7a1rJZ63ZrW9W1wSF5w6WAdtpLtc/T0QtoCTdc0G8PktNQW7VIXhaoHTlIawgg64hEE@9TdW9ciF7RCrcwGfjdNuc9Sp0BPtB7jJ8yviSYe436K3lG70NJe7BpII2LKEQEf23uJ2AoJQb@hFleB8oQqqahdU0rstTHb/zPDyOcVxghaJ5JKWc6Vc5NCejkXr1AJX50z3Z9O5yJ8Ex9GIyFg4Fz5hJc4i/NCWzcYLCCBcvUjHxQq6YEyR6xQokVGyR@opZG1iwoWroO2VAVs5A0Rcqsdsttr@a0J0gNeUY6gQTnYKi5Mpn5SmkHjGmkhmcWIE0gTj8O@eHyJP/FgIbq7k8tplBFh7YQk4pIqnTp8yvoRo2/VSlIboBDQe7aYteJc1yg2@EVeEplVILMMKiFPGXUJnh3hkCIUOpoHlUrgwJNa5puEUsZnIFoCC8q2quMAR2UAdKt3NB00VWxQiWkJjRwgZOQO02BIFReBxd6VPIiB4evuxEKMx1ghFyaUMlCMgJhhKKOtuAAePw3OdQIXEL48lAppoLR0@JPMRdAbpEEMbF88JAQeRhnyJPbZIDK6oRgisbmYvqOySC0snB4HjSfgJr1XVZOqCUfNgA2IZNFVAqygJDaQumxt5GQREs6TrUapd@Of@BdKrIL1ibRrNxfPrJX7VGCpsF6Fok4eosut7j2JBvGulDtSN0xpPDj5/DR0ko8fivmwlo@eMvkXejUpAl0fLIrI9CKym3gt4tMRJ3uBLAOsieX8pbzRUs5LF7bPJrbe0KYWybucQhdZQo6QHnnzkb17a/eMKrWUO8Bm1Oj0ak9VoF0IBz7rInTNmE08paA9dmLs7pQcj3LAR5ncd52@5J5jVafAp@JabbndxB7UecFp13zg6MRlwSvYtbMwEy@V53M4Gk0whTeUtD9VZs0HzxXZVjvtXTzIm2bGUoQvsR10rloepZSuN6suYZPA/OD8xNtWEVtCIVAqwylmwe6@gunJVHw9F0vcvhuUFUvNiOOYFouFeNzX01CUaxdRBvkgwzXE5hPO6PhoGoUuqJHwlN8airUyaGuA0lFB4JpwAzY7OimA0iHqruPO@B3pK3Ha@cN64gzluJblM7tuaa696JQngy4w/gflh6Mnkw/G0@TfSyuXYdjQ7mY4n3iuICVwQPtOvuuJaz7cDmIJjeXXw6FEsK00OSLWKdi/JM4UwjDY3zeL/8A0/r3z@I9M5Lsz@bdO5Xvm8q3JfHs2H7SKiJzg92mqbHolZYaELtTJh8GAhk5c45DSu3vIdBZrJMq7tqq69sb793jEY1gcI4c1xc1eiiVSzi3JDkQ5i504na95hJu63NO8SYeHwKz7OGpjlCj/fi4PpvZwDjNfATkeRyr3kP927h6wNxYTcfeeLAXXPg0Ww82HQIgF9dybu23jb/Tv6IS8ZPk/VVoBvWFd/Zte5HKFl0vKCE@gLhFgcqEdztg0pLJOoZ9MeANBGjuR/pUwJIJfFMt6Mn4WzjEYQky6paSyGH@aHBxfpFe4/t3uMsKXdvmp/o69mo@n92c1jYtOBQ8HrR3yhxv@wL7OxcMPTQDbGxpJk@n0JsADpTcDemX8Cwu/cAwHNE4xahvPnF2x8ZsOwnT9QZbvszBPGK9RrLd@Eg@BlYfAxmNwQvcG26G3TZS1xs7xaoZYaaZ2IKQg@8yHH5qii4mdf02SOBccNcApea5P4mXMv5GNMzHmn8/GWb/j8Am@TLNOdXx1dUXrfOnlr173qweXgWb4GWmoFX5iItH4bDq9S5U77DrkF4XWK93DsFsc@wWW8TY34zuk5K844oVzPJ2eP/4P)

Answer (score 0):

## Python3

Well I've never tried to do code golf before and I really can't compete with some of
these really good solutions, so I've prepared a long-form answer just to demonstrate
how I would solve this problem. This function takes a 2-D list of characters of any
size as its input.

(edited to shorten the function up as much as I could)

```
def f(i):
    a = None
    b = 0
    c = None
    d = 0
    h = len(i)
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(len(i[y])):
            if a == None:
                a = i[y][x]
            elif a != None:
                if i[y][x] != a:
                    c = i[y][x]
            if i[y][x] == a:
                b += 1
            elif i[y][x] == c:
                d += 1
    if b == 1:
        n = a
    elif d == 1:
        n = c
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(len(i[y])):
            if i[y][x] == n:
                return (x, y)
```

Here is a longer version that demonstrates the example input. If you run this script
it will show you the 2-D array and the needle (randomly generated every time) as 
well as solve it with the find_needle() function.

```
# Code golf! Needle in a haystack challenge
# sgibber2018 (my email handle)
"""
Notes: I can't really compete with what's already been done but I'm doing
       it just to do it. 
"""

import random

input_height = 10
input_width = 10
example_input = [["#" for x in range(input_width)] \
    for y in range(input_height)]
needle_spot_y = random.randrange(input_height)
needle_spot_x = random.randrange(input_width)
example_input[needle_spot_y][needle_spot_x] = "!"

for y in range(input_height):
    print(example_input[y])

# and now for the algorithm itself:
def find_needle(example_input):
    # declare two variables to count different char types
    c1 = None
    c1_count = 0
    c2 = None
    c2_count = 0
    # iterate through the whole list
    height = len(example_input)
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(len(example_input[y])):
            # assign c1 or c2 accordingly
            if c1 == None:
                c1 = example_input[y][x]
            elif c1 != None:
                if example_input[y][x] != c1:
                    c2 = example_input[y][x]
            # count the symbols based on whether or not they match
            if example_input[y][x] == c1:
                c1_count += 1
            elif example_input[y][x] == c2:
                c2_count += 1
    # Find the value with just one increment
    if c1_count == 1:
        needle = c1
    elif c2_count == 1:
        needle = c2
    # go back through the list and find the needle and get it's pos
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(len(example_input[y])):
            if example_input[y][x] == needle:
                return (x, y)

print(find_needle(example_input))
```

The function find_needle() takes a 2-D list and returns the coordinates of the 
character that only has one count. I could probably shorten this up a little but I
don't think I can compete with the existing Python3 answer which is mighty impressive.
How do you calculate the size of your answers?

Comment: Done! I'm wary of violating Python's whitespace rules too much but I shortened all the variables. Thanks for the heads up. How do I calculate the bytes?

Comment: You can use a number of tools.  [Here](https://tio.run/#python3) is an environment you can use that counts bytes, if you hit the link button at the top it will even generate an form filled answer for you.  Also some tips:  most operators `=`, `==` etc. don't require space on each side of them, so you can remove that easily, If you want to reply to a user in comments you can use @ <user-name> other wise they are unlikely to see it.  Anyway, hope you have fun here!

Comment: I'd also suggest looking at the [Tips for golfing in Python page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/76162) for some general shortcuts you can take

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I recommend going through the tips as per Jo King's suggestion. RE: "I'm wary of violating Python's whitespace rules" - for code-golf you need to violate whatever saves bytes and still works; however for this challenge we can make do with no newlines at all - the only white-space abuse of the port of my Python 2 answer to Python 3 (at 62 bytes) is to miss the space between `)` and `for` [twice] and between `in` and `(` - and, in fact, no "Python rules" are broken only "style guidelines" (although I don't actually see this one in PEP-8).

Comment: The current code (using tabs or single spaces in place of four spaces) is 387 bytes. Removing trivial white-space is [347 bytes](https://tio.run/##nY85DoMwEEV7n2LoQEkRlC7SXCEXQBTGS4yEhsgikn16xwsx1Cnff39m7LffzEr3EKTSoNu5ezDg@FxJMZjwxkDsIBMYXBTFEgO9WvAwE1hOL9WaNJdDd4S5O/ixyxJmHTfnbRkjJDm4MZFakm5OOvLuG@Qlio85jRwF/BWmC/Z1W5WiSJllFBNinyJCzkpV1kT8@7V6jco1q7aPpdZdfRfCFw).

Comment: Employing a bunch of golfing techniques and the fact that we do not need both counts (we are guaranteed a single needle and >=3 others) we can get this method to [158 bytes](https://tio.run/##TZFRbsMgDED/OQVTPggamzLtJ2rkaSfoAUpBIilRqbY0IhQ1p88wkZZYAvxsYxszzuF6Hz6X5WJ72peOHwg10EIHF6gaC3Z4/FpvgiW0v3vqqRuoSzGZIpI/dCCj6JSMAEY1BskoaV6gUk37Cmgm1Nvw8IMsn2LmeHcWOZdNJRGfIq7ouetlhwlagA8FEJWs1BLsFCYKtGSMnUmBgvux2PSiSD4iaI7QWq/rqDdd613ELQu5fa9Hlp37VJO63nGd@ITMCcGGsSHsODeGA6FpHJDxfRp/XCh5Nv5PLa5BKKN3Q0gvJRuwpL19MZH@IPJU8jwwvvwB).

Comment: Wow good tips thanks. I'll employ them on the next one!

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 81 bytes

Takes input as three pointers: one to the array, and two to the dimensions. Returns by modifying the dimensions to be the coordinates of the needle.

```c
i;f(char*a,int*w,int*h){for(i=0;*a==a[i];i++);i=i-1?i:*a==a[2];*h=i/ *w,*w=i%*w;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/bboJAEH1mv2KqUWFZUumDIW7X9gv8ABUT3IgusdCAlQfjr3c7O1BtJ5nbHs45g44OWltrZO7rY1bzTJjyzFuqx@CaV7Vv1FTyTKlsbVJpwjCQRpkofjPz7vUllfyozDMgjbfKjHgrb/YjM6WPKpDVBy1AV2VzBmcBnOPTJYAr82jffeXreMbjWSqZh4ZANAMKYontlRRwQmfmIclzsK5OjZoKqKu26zu8ErE7v0D@VDruBe9eF6mEghRIwjM5@A8MlILJppwEpBeGTsnbn5o90Meec4NQwZODCfTc1fUuDJH718RhN9blQ@uzxpNyfzAyZCAAB6e5KQeif3FrQH/go7QYu12MHRb8U2gAomiBAmJkNqUT6N0FMX4JN3azduiCYS6pDvtqt9sto1z2vUtbULDivWsUdpWwJLEJ1pVd3IPdp/ljXHzr/JQdGhu1Pw)

### Degolf

```c
i;f(char*a,int*w,int*h)
{
  for(i=0;*a==a[i];i++); // Count the number of elements equal to
                         // the one at (0,0)
  i=i-1?i:*a==a[2];  // Special case i==1, because it is 
          // ambiguous whether the needle is at 0 or 1 there.
  *h=i/ *w,*w=i%*w; // Modify pointers to indicate coordinates.
  // the space between i/ and *w is required, as /* starts a comment
}
```

Comment: Suggest `i=*a;i=strspn(a,&i)` instead of `for(i=0;*a==a[i];i++)`

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
lambda s,w:divmod(s.find({s.count(c):c for c in s}[1]),w)[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDbCoJAEIav26cY6mYXpmiNwhaMnqAHyAzMAym5irslET27rYc06Lsafr4Z@Kd46msurTp2TvXNzy6hDworESaPLA@pWsSJDOlLLYL8LjUNmAggzksIIJGg3i73GFbMFWLOvVpHSitwwCUTOp31HGYjU4Q1Al0hcMaQNNq543AeMJIRKEewvlLasU8HjLTppOHS0bZtE1smXiIsv7FJj338a@/@EeNoFrg5Qrf9hkdI07opiFAhlJG633Tzg7azIJOiTKSGmLZKxeoP)

Expects a string with no newlines and the width of the haystack as arguments.

**Explanation:**

```python
                         # get a dictionary of (number of occurrences : character)
                         {s.count(c):c for c in s}
                         # only one character will have one occurrence, so get that character
                         .........................[1]
                  # get the 0-indexed index of the needle character
                  s.find(............................)
           # flat_index / width will give us how many rows "down" the needle is (the y-value)
           # the remainder will give us how many columns "over" the needle is (the x-value)
           # so take the divmod and reverse the returned values to get (x,y)
           divmod(....................................,w)[::-1]
# anonymous function, takes haystack string with no newlines and haystack width
lambda s,w:
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>135</s> 111 bytes

```cs
S=>{for(int x=0,y;;x++)try{for(y=0;;y++)if(S[x][y]!=(S[0][0]==S[0][1]?S[0][0]:S[1][0]))return y+","+x;}catch{}}
```

[Try it online! (111 bytes)](https://tio.run/##zZBfa4MwFMWf56fI7IuiG92bNNMNCvsDWxn4MGixJaRpl84mI0k3RfzsNtVOkGmhsAcPojfn3Hv5RSyvMBek2EnK1iBMpSJbaDC0JfILYQLGfEkeebwyMgNo4RhJCd4EXwu0LZ3MuJAKKYrBw47hW6mEXjSLXFBVAZgQsozJ4pktnpBej/An8EER@kG24sKiTIHEH7ophInj2EqkpZ36QwhTbdCVFc6SaJZGl76uhpF@fL8sbqK7ozEK9UF/bVsQtRMMpI7pmk4Cc4wU/sjyvIAl7EFH2m9Ol@AVUWb9IgMk1tKu@7K6qqaOTaGmZ@SnNhpdzZmDzMFBptsaTLqCwYmg4eewcRxzJnlMrt8FVeSFMmL9/ftWaNvQaIyde6f5fN7G12VPzurutntw802pNsDNfWdSzfSAfuq18XleH9i8drZpH9iCWm2MdTg6mQb/dJN6gVG982IP)
[Try it online! (135 bytes)](https://tio.run/##zVFda4MwFH2evyKzL4qudG/SNHZQ2Ad0ZZCHQcWWYFNnZ5OR2E2R/nbnRyvItFDYgweJN@fcezmHePLO44JmBxkwH@BERnQPFUb2VH4Rj4IZ39AnHm6VVAE5vJBICd4E9wXZl0yq3MiIRIEHHg/Mm8hI5Isc1wRVZYMFpZuQrl/Y@pnk64n3CRDIMLLTgEUgQSMzht9EAIFUFW650GAywcM5ZX70ARPD0AsuRiMYT7CTuGclzhWBCsaJ3VukYWfk5h9CZXHvTk/EGOeX/K9PY0M1VSMZCyhodBAMCHjMYBmiwCnFNw824JUETDtHAUT4Uq/70rqqpk5NOE/F6E9NNLqaMwXUQQHVbBUWXcLggtDgj7BxnXEmeUiH7yKI6DxgVPv7KhrWdag0xq7NtFqt2vx10YururvpHiTflWgzuHvoVKqZHrhfWm3@LKsP3qx2b8s@eLNrtHmsxfFF1f6nJPUCpTqP2S8)

New one:

```cs
for (int x = 0, y; ; x++)
    try
    {
        for (y = 0; ; y++)
            if (S[x][y] != (S[0][0] == S[0][1] ? S[0][0] : S[1][0]))
                return y + "," + x;
    }
    catch { }
```

Previous one:

```cs
int i = 0, y;
var r = "";
for (; i < S.Length; i++)
    for (y = 0; y < S[i].Length; y++)
        r = S[i][y] != (S[0][0] == S[0][1] ? S[0][0] : S[1][0]) ? i + "," + y : r;
return r;
```

Answer (score 0):

**C (VC++) Visual Studio 2017, 538bytes**

well there can be a couple of Bytes be stripped of if the haystack and needle string is Input via command line Parameters but i can not get it to work proberly then so the haystack and needle string is hard coded in the source (ugly….. ) takes 50bytes

Maybe anyone wants to improve on that

anyway the  Code i came up with is

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#define r v[1][i]
#define i(x,y) if(x==y)
void main(){const char*v[]={"haystack.exe","#####\n##+##\0" };int i=0,z=0,s=0,c=r,f=c,a=-1,h=0;do{c=r;i(c,f)a++;i(a,1)h=c;if(h&&c!=h&&c!=10)break;i(c,10){z++;s=0;}}while(s++,i++,c);printf("%d,%d",s-1,z);}
```

the ungolfed variant is

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main(/*int argc, const char * argv[]*/)
{
    const char * argv[] = {"haystack.exe","#####\n##+##\0" };
    int i = 0,row = 0, col = 0;
    char character = argv[1][i];
    char firstChar = character;
    int howMany = -1;
    char hay = '\0';
    do
    {
        char character = argv[1][i];
        if (character == firstChar)
        {
            howMany++;
        }
        if (howMany ==1)
        {
            hay = character;
        }
        if ((hay != '\0') && (character != hay)&&(character!='\n'))
        {
            break;
        }
        if (character == '\n')
        {
            row++;
            col = 0;
        }
        col++;
        i++;
    } while (character != '\0');
    printf("%d,%d", col-1, row);
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

i dont expect this to be explained

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I'm not familiar enough with C++ to assist, but I know there's a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132/42963) page you can check out.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 62 bytes

```
~:04p~-k#v>~:a-!2j6$_04g-!..@
-#v_$$1+0>  >~:a
.;>04g-#;_1+^@.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@vszIwKajTzVYus6uzStRVNMoyU4k3MEnXVdTTc@DSVS6LV1Ex1DawU1AAyXPpWduBJJWt4w214xz0/v9XBgIuZWVFEKGsDAA)

Output is: column row