# Make a haystack (with a needle)

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, random

*(Essentially the inverse of [Find the needle in the haystack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/179351/42963))*

Given two tuples, `(w, h)` and `(x, y)`, generate a haystack composed of a single random [printable ASCII character](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5869/42963) of `w` width and `h` height with a needle made of a different random printable ASCII character at `(x, y)` when measured from the upper-left.

For example, when given `(5,4)` for the width and height, and `(3,1)` (zero-indexed) for the location of the needle, a possible haystack could be the following:

```
#####
###N#
#####
#####
```

Another possibility could be

```
*****
***$*
*****
*****
```

among hundreds of others.

#### Rules and Clarifications

- Input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963). This means you can take input as a list of list of integers, as a single string, as two integers via command-line and a tuple via function argument, etc.
- You can print the result to STDOUT or return it as a function result.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- You can choose whether the `(x, y)` tuple is zero-indexed or one-indexed, but please specify in your solution which you're using.
- You do *not* get to pick which characters to use. That's part of the challenge - randomly selecting the characters.
- Every possible output for a given input must have a non-zero chance of appearing, but the randomness doesn't need to be uniform.
- The haystack is guaranteed to be at least 2x2 in size, so it's unambiguous which is the needle and which is the hay.
- There is only ever one needle, and it's only ever one character in size, and it's guaranteed to be within the boundaries of the haystack.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Can we return a flat list of characters?

Comment: @TFeld No, you must have `\n` (or equivalent) included where appropriate.

Comment: can we return a matrix of characters?

Comment: @dzaima But of course.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/) about the choice of the characters. Applies to a few early answers... :p

Comment: @Arnauld I don't know what was the magic here, but I completely read the challenge as I can use any ASCII printable characters "that I like", instead of "random", and it is funny another person also did same exact thing! I didn't mean to implement the random in such a beautiful way :P

Comment: Can the order of elements in the tuples be altered, and can the input format be mangled in any other ways?

Comment: @UnrelatedString Yes and yes? Those are standard I/O rules.

Comment: Just a quick question for clarity - the two random printable ASCII characters should be by definition, dissimilar, correct?

Comment: @TaylorScott Yes, that's covered in the opening paragraph. The two characters need to be different.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork- Thanks for the clarification, I can be completely blind sometimes and did not see that! Cheers

Answer (score 12):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>122 120 106</s>  103 bytes

Recursively builds the output character by character. The coordinates are 0-indexed.

```javascript
(w,h,x,y)=>(s=new Date%9023,g=X=>Y<h?Buffer([X-w?(x-X|y-Y?s+1:s%96)%95+32:13])+g(X<w?X+1:!++Y):'')(Y=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcndCoIwGADQV6kL8fvYFv5koDgH0UNsRBdimxbiwllT6N1X5/Y820/ruvnxWthk7zoYHsDTga50Q96A45P2u0u76KhMspz2XPJG1YM4v43RM1wl8wJWJr8bU8KRtHJRecKoLEieVWl@Q9KDrL2Q/9oTorCKYwTFEwydnZwd9WG0PRgo6JHmNEUMPw)

### How?

#### Problem

To generate the haystack and the needle, we could either:

- generate a random haystack and process some loop to generate a random needle until it's different from the haystack
- shuffle the whole range of printable characters and pick the first 2 of them

Unfortunately, both approaches are rather lengthy in JS.

#### Solution

We use instead a method that guarantees to generate 2 distinct characters with a single random number and without any loop.

We pick a random seed \$s\$ in \$[0..9022]\$ and define the haystack \$h\$ and needle \$n\$ as:

$$\begin{align}&h=(s+1)\bmod 95\\
&n=(s\bmod 96)\bmod 95\end{align}$$

(we then need to add \$32\$ to turn them into printable ASCII codes)

Basically, \$h\$ follows the pattern:

$$1,2,3,...,94,0,1,2,3,...$$

while \$n\$ follows the pattern:

$$0,1,2,3,...,94,\color{red}0,0,1,2,3,...$$

The sequences are progressively shifted relative to each other because of the extra \$0\$ in the needle pattern.

[This code](https://tio.run/##TY7BTgMhFEX3fMVNEwM4SmprTaajcdFP6FJdkIHp0Eyh4WGbaPz28ZG4cAWcx7n3He3FUp/DudzH5Pw8ky94QfRX7H3phBhSVsRk2YHwjHa5WvOtaTS@BTDyhMcNHjRu0G46ZpEZ1dfTH2IWBsVfOVejjDldsQjxYqfgcLYhL6rGxcY6p/Ylh3gwQ06n3Wjzjrdit8F6dcfR9dS6Ez@iT5HS5M2UDqq6FL58rWg3uEX7iFdI@ux7TySxhRxsmLyTrP4X5XuUnPlmjOGMD3NMISoJyRXz/As) shows that it does eventually lead to all possible pairs \$(h,n)\$ with \$h\neq n\$ (there are \$95\times 94=8930\$ of them).

And because we need only one random number, we can afford to use the current timestamp in milliseconds as our entropy source with `new Date%9023` instead of the longer `Math.random()*9023`.

### Commented

```javascript
(w, h, x, y) => (      // w = width, h = height, (x, y) = coordinates
  s = new Date % 9023, // s = random seed in [0..9022]
  g = X =>             // g = recursive function taking X
    Y < h ?            //   if we've not reached the end of the grid:
      Buffer([         //     append the next character:
        X - w ?        //       if we haven't reached the end of the line:
          ( x - X |    //         if this is not the position of the needle:
            y - Y ?    //
              s + 1    //           append the haystack character
            :          //         else:
              s % 96   //           append the needle character
          ) % 95 + 32  //
        :              //       else:
          13           //         append a linefeed
      ]) +             //
      g(X < w ? X + 1  //     append the result of a recursive call
              : !++Y)  //     with either (X+1, Y) or (0, Y+1)
    :                  //   else:
      ''               //     stop recursion
)(Y = 0)               // initial call to g with X = Y = 0
```

Comment: Never seen `new Date` be used to generate a random seed before. Cool.

Comment: @DanielVestøl, it's a common tactic in challenges where "random" is un(der)specified.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
p/⁼€ịØṖẊ¤s⁸Ḣ¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/79A/1HjnkdNax7u7j484@HOaQ93dR1aUvyoccfDHYsOLfl/eLnSoa2RQPmsRw1zDm07tO1Rw9z//6OjTXUUzGN1FEC0KYi21FEwio0FShjqKBiDBIC0IZQGSgAA)

-1 byte thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)

Returns a list of lines. The last line in the Footer section displays it as a square. Takes input as `[w, h]` and `[y, x]`, where `x` and `y` are 0-indexed.

### How it works

```
p/⁼€ịØṖẊ¤s⁸Ḣ¤ - Main link. Takes [w, h] on the left and [y, x] on the right
p/            - Reduce Cartesian product over the arguments.
                This yields a list of co-ordinates from (1, 1) to (h, w)
   €          - Over each list:
  ⁼           -   Is it equal to [x, y]?
              - This yields a list where every element except 1 is 0
        ¤     - Create a nilad:
     ØṖ       -   Printable ASCII characters
       Ẋ      -   Shuffled
    ị         - Index into the shuffled characters, replacing 1 with the first char in the shuffled list and 0 with the last. Therefore, the two characters will be distinct
            ¤ - Create a nilad:
          ⁸   -   Yield [w, h]
           Ḣ  -   Extract w
        s     - Split the list of characters into rows of length w
              - Implicitly output
```

Comment: -1 byte if you take `[y, x]` instead of `[x, y]` so you can drop the `U`

Comment: @UnrelatedString Huh, weird. That didn't work for me when I first posted it, but is now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## Excel VBA, <s>128</s> <s>118</s> <s>106</s> <s>94</s> 96 bytes

<sup>*-12 bytes inspired by agtoever*</sup>
<sup>*-12 bytes thanks to Taylor Scott, VBA extraordinaire*</sup>
<sup>*+2 bytes and -1 bug thanks to Taylor's unnecessary, intimidating, and [much appreciated work](https://pastebin.com/ftBs4Dn3)*</sup>

```vb
Sub n(w,h,x,y)
a=94*Rnd
[A1].Resize(h,w)=Chr(a+32)
Cells(y,x)=Chr(32+(a+93*Rnd+1)Mod 95)
End Sub
```

Input and output are one-indexed. Output is to the top left cell range of the active sheet.

`a=94*Rnd+32`: `(126-32)*Rnd+32` gives a number between 32 and 126, inclusive.

`Range(~)=Chr(a)`: Fills all the cells with the ASCII character.

`Cells(y,x)=Chr(~)`: Fills just that one cell with the other ASCII character.

`(a+62*Rnd)Mod 95+32`: `{(a+[94-32]*Rnd) Mod (126-32+1)}+32` gives a random number between 32 and 126 inclusive that is *not* the same as `a`. (I can't prove that mathematically but 100 million tests showed no collisions.)

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Shorter: `b=Chr(Asc(a)+1+95*Rnd Mod 127)` instead of the do-while loop.

Comment: Oh. And then you can just insert that statement in `Cells(y,x)=...` instead of assigning it to b.

Comment: @agtoever I tested that. It results character codes up to 221 which is [not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5869/42963). I can't figure out how to modify it to generate a uniquely random integer 32-126. I kept hitting a ≈1.5% match rate, which is no good. However, that helped me find an error in my original code since it allowed up to 127 instead of 126. (It turns out that `Chr()` rounds instead of truncating.)

Comment: Ow. [Adding (+) has a lower operator precedence than Mod](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/operator-precedence). Add parenthesis: `Cells(y,x)=Chr((Asc(a)+1+94*Rnd)Mod127))` (not tested, maybe spaces are mandatory around Mod...)

Comment: @agtoever I tried that when I was trying to get the previous suggestion to work. As written, `b` ends up in the range 0-126 instead of 32-126 although it's always unique from `a`. I massaged it a bit to get the most recent edit, which had 0% failure rate over 100 million runs.

Comment: You can get down to 94 bytes if you use `[A1].Resize(h,w)=Chr(a)`

Comment: The `62` in the needle declaration didn't quite sit well with me, so I went and checked the math - it looks like as written it does avoid all possible collisions of `a` and `b`, but, it also fails to give 31 expected `b` values for every `a` value. I did work out a solution to this should only cost you two bytes - `a=94*Rnd`, `Chr(a+32)` and `Chr(32+(a+93*Rnd+1)Mod 95)` should give you everything you need. Uh, I've also been working on my own commenting and formatting habits, so [here](https://pastebin.com/ftBs4Dn3) is a needlessly well commented proof of the above. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>134</s> <s>133</s> <s>120</s> <s>112</s> 111 bytes

```python
lambda w,h,x,y:zip(*[iter(chr(r[x+y*w==i]+32)for i in range(w*h))]*w)
from random import*
r=sample(range(95),2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpLDoIwFAD3nKI7@kpjIshCk54EWFSh9hn6ybNJwctXDauZTCbuyQbfFqPGsmp3nzXL0spN7rcPRi4GTAvxhyVOw9bsIiuFU9O1YAIxZOgZaf9ceBYWYBIZKkPB/eP8A7oYKImK1Fu7uC78mK89yBZKJPSJ1aOvT6@AnjsdeX24NLyXF9nJMwCULw)

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell) v6, <s>102</s> 96 bytes

```powershell
param($x,$y,$a,$b)$j,$k=' '..'~'|random -C 2
-join((,$j*$x+++'
')*$y|%{"$_$k"[$i++-eq$b*$x+$a]})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclLDoIwGEXheVfxh1wt0EIIjyEjl2GMKREib6wDIYBbr5WcyZecafyU@v0su86gylczKa16F7PEIqEkCg@NRJtz4mHIv3zTaniMPQUXilnQjPXguhKNj1kIwRn3fCzbaXVwR@tcUQsRlC8U/w912z2zM3ZGRbEtouhwShkllB7ObPaZHw)

This answer, thanks to mazzy, uses the character range feature added in v6 to save several bytes over the more flexible answer below.

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>119</s>..<s>105</s> 102 bytes

<sup>-16 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to AdmBorkBork</sup>

```powershell
param($x,$y,$a,$b)$j,$k=32..126|random -C 2
-join((,$j*$x+++'
')*$y|%{[char]($_,$k)[$i++-eq$b*$x+$a]})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtLDoIwAAX3PUUXT6G0ECzgjpXHIMQUhQDysy6EAGevlcxmkjdvGr@l/tRl1xlU6WompVXvYhZYBJRAwdAKvNJIBsFFXjethufYU/9GJfHbsRlcV6D1MHPOHeIwD8t2WrNHrXTu4m6vLEPDuV@@UfwzqHxnZifkjIpKS0jDw2Oa0IjGhycWu5kf)

Gets two ints in the range of [32,126]. We first make a 1D array out of the first value, appending a new line after every `$x`chars. Doing this means we also have to increment `$x` so that our index math isn't affected. We then iterate through the array, and either yield a char-ified first value or the needle. Finally, we join all the yielded values and output it.

Answer is 0-indexed by the way.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
QŒṬƤSḂịØṖẊ¤
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lists, `[[height, width], [row, column]]` (1-indexed), which yields a list of lists of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//UcWS4bmsxqRT4biC4buLw5jhuZbhuorCpP/Dh1n//1tbNSw3XSxbMywyXV0)** (The footer calls the link and joins with newlines.)

#### How?

```
QŒṬƤSḂịØṖẊ¤ - Link: [[h, w], [r, c]]
Q           - de-duplicate (i.e. [[h, w]] if [r, c] == [h, w] else [[h, w], [r, c]])
   Ƥ        - for prefixes (of that list):
 ŒṬ         -   get a 2D array with ones at the coordinates specified
    S       - sum (vectorises) (giving us an h*w matrix with zeros almost everywhere,
                                except a 1 at our needle and, if [h, w] != [r,c], a 2 at
                                the bottom-right)
     Ḃ      - modulo two (replacing the 2 with a zero if it exists)
          ¤ - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
       ØṖ   -   list of printable characters
         Ẋ  -   shuffled
      ị     - (left) index into (right) (vectorises)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Dyalog APL, <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```apl
⎕UCS(32+2?95)[⎕∘≡¨⍳⎕]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862hXSQPxQ52ANYyNtI3tLU81oIP9Rx4xHnQsPrXjUuxnIi/0PVPg/jctEwZTLUMEYAA) 0-indexed.

-1 thanks to ngn, -2 thanks to Adám suggesting to use a different I/O format.

Comment: `(⎕UCS 32+2?95)` -> `⎕UCS(32+2?95)`

Comment: `⎕UCS(32+2?95)[⎕∘≡¨⍳⎕]`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 133 bytes

```python
from random import*
r=range
def f(h,w,x,y):
 p=sample(r(32,127),2)
 for i in r(h):
	print ''.join(chr(p[i==y and j==x])for j in r(w))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCsIwEETP5iv21l1ZxKaIIORLxEOxjUmxSVgDbb4@RoSBgeE9JpXsYtC1WokryBimVn5NUfJRiWnDa1bTbMGi4413LnRTkMxnXNN7RsFBc6@vxJoU2CjgwQcQdA07JPEhQ9edlugDPp1guntjCrQbWIzZH/RTlr@yEVWL/ZlbLjxQ/QI)

-12 thanks to Value Ink for suggesting using a loop comprehension. -2 thanks to Unrelated String for suggesting python 2 instead of python 3 to get rid of parenthesis in the print function!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! My first thought was to wrap the innermost loop into a loop comprehension that is then joined together and printed, to eliminate both the `end=''` part as well as the additional `print()` call after the loop. This cut the size down to 135 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3bCsIwEESfk6/Yt@7KIrZFBCFfIj4U25gUc2EttP36mCIMDAznMHlfXIp9KVZSABniWMuHnGQ5aTF1eE96nCxYdLzyxjvdtcrmO4T8mVCw77jtbsQdaWWTgAcfQdAdmMri44JNc56Tj/hygvnhjdmh/sBszPakw5n/zkpExWJ74Zor91R@ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: You can also [shave two more off](https://tio.run/##JY3BCsIwEETP5iv21l1ZxKaIIORLxEOxjUmxSVgDbb4@RoSBgeE9JpXsYtC1WokryBimVn5NUfJRiWnDa1bTbMGi4413LnRTkMxnXNN7RsFBc6@vxJoU2CjgwQcQdA07JPEhQ9edlugDPp1guntjCrQbWIzZH/RTlr@yEVWL/ZlbLjxQ/QI) by using Python 2 instead of 3, but it's minor.

Comment: `print(end=chr(p[i==y and j==x]))` saves three bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 110 bytes

```python
from random import*
w,h,x,y=input()
m,n=sample(map(chr,range(32,127)),2)
l=eval(`[[m]*w]*h`)
l[x][y]=n
print l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCsMgEEDRvafIUmU2MS1deRIRIq2tgo6DNU08vXX14cGn3kJBNca7lrxUh6@ZmKnUJtkJAS7oOiIdjQuWAfXXZUqeZ0f8GSrM4@P5pmBVDyFACZa0/7nEd2OylaeVYZ9mLmu61cioRmxLGuMON9hg/QM)

I copied [TFeld's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194356/20260) and managed to golf a char using list assignment. The `eval()` trick is used to [make a mutable matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51022/20260) to avoid the list mutation applying to every row.

**111 bytes**

```python
lambda w,h,x,y:[[chr(r[x^i<1>y^j]+32)for i in R(w)]for j in R(h)]
from random import*
R=range
r=sample(R(95),2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYhJDoIwFED3nKI7@vXHBJCFRjwEW4akCrVt6JAvCXD6imH1hrDNyrs8yqqNk7CvQbAFFa643ZvmrYhTs/b6kT233nTnIgfpiWmmHav5At2/zFEKukSSt4yEG3ZoGzzNp6Su9vEZE6q@woZp5DW/lYA5xEDazSxtXXoxXjtuReDp4Sh5iVcsMAOA@AM)

A smaller change that only tied. Calling the function multiple times always give the same random choices, which I hope is OK.

**109 bytes**

```python
lambda w,h,x,y:[m*w]*y+[m*x+n+m*(w+~x)]+[m*w]*(h+~y)
from random import*
m,n=sample(map(chr,range(32,127)),2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxDoMgEIDh3adwvINbxDZNmvgk1oFWKSQeEkqDLL46Nen0Df8fSrKbV9UMj7pqfs66zWRpp3IfWeRJFHm6Sy9ZQJbHjpP8B7DyKNiYuHEbtZ9PHIctJtEw@eGjOawLsA7wspHO471Ar6hTN0RSWEN0PrUGhPPhmwCxXulCPXU/)

A shorter function making the list of lines via multiplication. Also generates the characters just once.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that eval trick.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 86 bytes

```perl
($,,$b)=keys%{{map{chr,1}33..126}};$_=($,x$F[0].$/)x$F[1];s;(.*
){$F[3]}.{$F[2]}\K.;$b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19DRUdHJUnTNju1sli1ujo3saA6OaNIx7DW2FhPz9DIrLbWWiXeFqiqQsUt2iBWT0VfE8QyjLUuttbQ0@LSrAbyjGNr9UC0UWxtjLeetUrS//@mCiYKxgqG//ILSjLz84r/6/qa6hkY/tdNLAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 71 bytes

```julia
f(w,h,x,y)=(z=unique(rand(' ':'~',9));g=fill(z[1],(h,w));g[y,x]=z[2];g)
```

`x,y` are one indexed. Returns a 2d array of characters, I spent the extra bytes to make sure the default printing has the right orientation (`'` for transpose no longer works because they stick to a strict mathematical meaning). Getting two distinct randoms is surprisingly verbose, this has about a 1e-18 chance of failing to do so, one more byte could make it 1e-196.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchLCoAgEADQq7RzBmaj1KLCk4gLwSxDog@SuujqVrzdW2PwhqdaHdy0UKKMEoqMmz/iBKfZLLCGDexh1COOs3Q@BCiKa4KF7r9UpqRlUUKPM1brrz2YDA46aj8Csb4)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 21 bytes

```
u:@(32+2?95){~#.=i.@[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/S60cNIyNtI3sLU01q@uU9Wwz9Ryi/2tycaUmZ@QrGANhmoKhgiGECzQJTBsaKBgZACWA0v8B)

Inspired by dzaima's APL answer.

Thanks to Galen and Adam for the randomize fix.

Comment: [Fix](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/S60cNIyNtI3sLU01q@vsHbT0bTP1/mtycRWlFpZmFqUqqOeV5qYWZSarcxUl5qXk52ZWpQIN5EpNzshXSFMwVjCGMIFiUCFDAwUjg/8A) by Adam

Comment: You need two tuples as input

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that, will fix.  Thanks for the other fix btw.

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) with Statistics Package, 45 bytes

```matlab
@(x)randsample(' ':'~',2)(sparse(x{:},0:1)+1)
```

The input is a cell array of 2 numeric vectors of length 2: `{[h y] [w x]}`, with `x`,`y` 1-based.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzKDEvpTgxtyAnVUNdQd1KvU5dx0hTo7ggsag4VaOi2qpWx8DKUFPbUPN/mkZ1tJmCUaxCtLmCcWyt5n8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 62 bytes

```ruby
->w,h,x,y{a,b=[*?\s..?~].sample 2;r=[a*w]*h*$/;r[y*-~w+x]=b;r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165cJ0OnQqeyOlEnyTZayz6mWE/Pvi5WrzgxtyAnVcHIusg2OlGrPFYrQ0tF37ooulJLt65cuyLWNsm6qPZ/QWlJsUJatKmOMRAaxv4HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel + CSV, 104 bytes

```
,,,,=94*RAND()+32,=REPLACE(REPT(REPT(CHAR(E1),A1)&"
",B1),D1*A1+D1+C1+1,1,CHAR(MOD(E1+62*RAND(),95)+32))
```

Save as CSV, add input as `A1` - `D1`.
Output will be in `F1`.

Using @Engineer Toast's solutoin for generating 2 unique characters.

Needle position is 0-indexed, which is curious, as Excel itself if 1-indexed.
Changing to 1-indexed input adds 3 bytes (`(D2-1)*(A2+1)+C2` instead of `D1*A1+D1+C1+1`).

Comment: @Arnauld, it does not.  Thanks for poingin out.  Have updated.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that the indicated solution for the needle character is not quite correct. You should switch to `CHAR(MOD(E1+93*RAND()+1,95)+32)` to insure that your solution covers all possible combinations of needle and haystack

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <strike>56</strike> <strike>50</strike> <strike>48</strike> 41 bytes

```
JEKE=TE=Yrd\~=Zh.SYVJVQ ?qHK?qNTpeYpZpZ)d
```

I'm somewhat struggling to golf Pyth, but posting this to force myself to learn.

Edit 1: Golfed it down a bit, and made it an actual solution -6 bytes

Edit 2: Looked at it after posting it and realized a few bytes save by ignoring space. -2 bytes

Edit 3: Today I learned about character ranges, which shortens things significantly. -7 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>113</s> 109 bytes

```php
for([,$w,$h,$x,$y]=$argv,$a=range(' ','~'),shuffle($a);$i++<$h;print"
")for(;$$i++<$w;)echo$a[$i-$y||$$i-$x];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLCoMwEEX3/YoiF5LgdFPaVZR@iLgIkjiBoiF9qCD99VEpF86Bs7iJk1SPtDOMWTeEicCEmbC0NVzuvwRXZzf0XquzIvVThl78CeHpNZyxiGVZgW3KcXgXp8IcPxb/PFnjOx7hGsQLlnXF4bm1InKX277rBg)

Pass inputs as command arguments (`$argv`) in order of `w`, `h`, `x` and `y`. The `x` and `y` are one-indexed.

```php
for(
  [,$w,$h,$x,$y]=$argv, // put inputs from $argv array into 4 short named variables
  $a=range(' ','~'),    // create $a array containing printable ASCII characters
  shuffle($a);          // shuffle the array
  $i++<$h;              // loop $h times (rows)
  print"\n"             // print a newline after every row
)
  for(;$$i++<$w;)       // loop $w times (columns)
    echo                // print
      $a[               //   a character from $a (1st char for needle and 2nd for heystack)
        $i-$y ||        //   when row and y don't match
        $$i-$x          //   or when col and x don't match (will be false only for needle)
      ];
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 65 bytes

```
D,g,?!,
L,c95Rdb[€BXd¦=BFV#@G+b[95€Ω%31€+€CA€RbU‽g$€=$€Ω:A$pbUp$T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ13HXlGHy0cn2dI0KCUp@lHTGqeIlEPLbJ3cwpQd3LWToi1NgWLnVqoaGwJpbSB2dgQSQUmhjxr2pqsAmbYqYAVWjioFSaEFKiH/VXISc5NSEhUM7ezt7Lm4XHSy8jPzdLg4HeqAhBdIoKAotaQkM60SJGgFJIAGVIMU1SaF5nFxqcCk7Sr@/482VDCM/R9trGAcCwA)

Takes input as `[y x]` and `[w h]`. `x` and `y` are 1-indexed. Outputs a list of lines.

Added 17 bytes to make sure the needle is distinct.

### How it works

We start by generating two ranges from \$1\$ to \$95\$ inclusive, before choosing a random value from each. If the two values are equal, we add one to the one of them. We then add \$31\$ to each, yielding two characters ord points in the ASCII range. Finally, we convert them to characters.

Next, we generate a list of all co-ordinates in the grid, and compare them with `[y x]`. If the co-ordinates match, we yield \$1\$, otherwise \$0\$. Next, we index each of these \$1\$s and \$0\$s into the two characters, creating a grid of \$0\$ characters with 1 \$1\$ character in it at `[y x]`. Finally, we retrieve the width and split the grid into that many rows.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
 ~Δψ] ~Δψ⁴⁴=}A*∙až
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTIwJTdFJXUwMzk0JXUwM0M4JTVEJTIwJTdFJXUwMzk0JXUwM0M4JXUyMDc0JXUyMDc0JTNEJTdEQSoldTIyMTlhJXUwMTdF,inputs=NSUwQTQlMEEyJTBBNA__,v=0.12) 1-indexed.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 145 bytes

```cs
(a,b,c,d)=>{int l=0;for(var j=Enumerable.Range(32,95).OrderBy(k=>Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();l<a*b;)Write((char)j[l==c*a+d?1:0]+(++l%a<1?"\n":""));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYhBC4IwGEDv/YohBN@XS7LwkHNGQXSJggg6VIc5Z83WhGlFRL/d6tDhvQdP1n1Z63YqG11Zkmjb0D/kq7TgLQiaUUlz5Onru4jhA1ZUDu7CkZLP7e2qnMiMCjbCnhSMhnQcYbB2uXKzJ1x4urjpPFipx6@AGGyrpa4bQGYS0csY7pxuFIA8C4fl3nAue8LPJ2E8OPrg@6YrknDiHawXex4ie7esUxCI6IiGdIis/QA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 119 bytes

```
procedure f(w,h,x,y)
until m:=char(32+?95)&n:=char(32+?95)&m~==n
t:=[];1to h&put(t,repl(m,w))&\z
t[y,x]:=n
return t
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7BTsMwDAbge57CXKpE@MJgQgRFvMDeYOxQpZ4a0TiVcek6BK8@SjcQwrf/s2U7xcKnLvELSM1NyadeSqRmEIK9HbHFA07ODKypg@xDbGuxt6vrp4e1q/hfzp8hsFEftrvHGy3QVv2gVlGo72zG0bnq@Wh0O@Fh5@dJIR2EQQ1x8@durhNbZ2Cu80/pSJe88WFv7xHWCHcIqzPSG8kE4sPVBpoC7wv@epxdvn2UpPRqo/vpL3BZ/LH88AU)

`x`and `y`are 1-indexed

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 137 bytes

```python
lambda w,h,x,y,c=chr:"\n".join([c(a)*w,c(a)*x+c(n)+c(a)*(w-x-1)][r==y]for r in range(h));a,n=__import__("random").sample(range(32,127),2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrtCoIwFEBfZezXvXUV1CIo9iQqY01tC/fBEtSnX2G/zoFz4r6Y4Js8iS7Pyj0HxVYytNFOWmiT7rzzvHwH66HVoPC00oHtrMHj@XBYi62osG@TEHs/hcQSs54l5V8jGMSHIi@ktC6GtEgJ/FeG4DiWH@XiPML/bGqq6htSjTkm6xeY4EoXaqhCzF8)

Uses zero-based indexing for the needle position.

Comment: `from random import*` is shorter than `__import__("random")`. [136 bytes.](https://tio.run/##JYpBCoMwEADvviL0lNW1oLYUCnmJekijaSxmE7aC@vq0taeZgYn74gI1yaouzdo/Bi1WdLjhjkYZx/dTR6fzK0wkWyM15Cse2AojCYrD5VpuZQV9y0rtvQ0sWEwkWNNzlA4gsxz8L4cvJh8DL3mmkdRb@ziP8j82NVb1DbCGFHmiRVp5xQs2WAGkDw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 57 bytes

```perl6
{(' '..'~').pick(2)[0 xx$^a*$^b-1,1;*].pick(*).rotor($a)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WkNdQV1PT71OXVOvIDM5W8NIM9pAoaJCJS5RSyUuSddQx9BaKxYipaWpV5Rfkl@koZKoWftfrzixUiEtv0ghTcNUx0TzPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
ＵＯＮＮ‽γＪＮＮ‽Φγ¬⁼ιＫＫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98/KSc/L13DM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU0cBjRuUmJeSn6uRrqlpzeVVmlsQko9XA1BVQFFmXokGVJ9bZk4JUDxdR8Evv0TDtbA0MadYI1NHISA1NRuoGgSs//83VTBRMFYw/K9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＵＯＮＮ‽γ
```

Draw a rectangle of the given width and height using a random printable ASCII character.

```
ＪＮＮ
```

Jump to the 0-indexed position of the needle.

```
‽Φγ¬⁼ιＫＫ
```

Print a random printable ASCII character, but filtering out the character under the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>27</s> 23  bytes

-4 bytes thanks to ngn!

```
{`c$(32+-2?95)x#&/y=!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qOiFZRcPYSFvXyN7SVLNCWU2/0laxovZ/WrSZgrm1iYJx7H8A)

0-indexed `x` and `y`

Similar to Dzaima's APL and Jonah's J solutions.

Comment: `(x/y)=x#!*/x` -> `x#&/y=!x`

Comment: @ngn That's much better than my naive solution. Thanks!

Comment: @ngn Clever use of the odometer for 2d matching!

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 156 bytes

```
func[w h x y][c: :collect p: take/part random c[repeat i 95[keep to sp 32 + i]]2
c[repeat i h[keep/only c[repeat j w[keep pick p i * w + j
=(y * w + x)]]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc69CsMgFIbh3av4xv4MgaQtNNCb6CoOokdikqoYi8nV27QptGf6hveBE0mXO2kuWJRO@0c1EWk4n5lpi3k6xTM6zFgEVy1a5ceRVEJokeRAVZAxYZNQPFIgmWBxPfOBKCB5TAFNjSOsEDX7S7pPUXk3Lj/ZI28wWDUgrNkBecU9u@2W75734n3F@EhSdUgwuOCMExoeonXrP9R765BEeQE)

`x` and `y` are 1-indexed. Returns a list of strings.

### Readable:

```
f: func [w h x y] [
    c: take/part random collect [
        repeat i 95 [
            keep to sp 32 + i
        ]
    ] 2
    collect[
        repeat i h [
            keep/only collect [
                repeat j w [
                    keep pick c i * w + j = (y * w + x)
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>144</s> <s>132</s> 131 bytes

```python
from random import*
i,j,k,l=input()
n,h=sample(range(32,127),2)
for x in range(j):a=[chr(n)]*i;a[k]=chr((n,h)[x==l]);print`a`[2::5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLCsMgEEX3@QqXTphNTEPB4JeIEGmTah6jGAvp11tLV5fDOdz4yS6QKGVJ4WDJ0rOOP2JIuW08rrjhrjzFd@bQEDp12iPuM6/la@a9wE7cAQU0S0jsYp7Y36wgrdIPlziBaf1o9WbUD3k9AX0ptRsYY/KUJztpIeVgShnwhj12Xw)

Corrected the problem with the guaranteed uniqueness of the characters and saved 12 bytes along the way.

Comment: I liked the idea of this solution well enough that I shaved off 3 more bytes for you: https://tio.run/##JYxBCoMwEEX3OUUQhIzOxthSEHKS4EJaraPJJKQp2NOn0q4@vPf48ZPXwLqUJQUv08SPc8jHkHIjCDfc0Rni@M4KBONqXpOPblZn@ZxVr7HTN0ANYglJHpJY/s0GQ0zEuarvVUO1UozQ7K2y58doD2PciND@KIEdaCzlihfssfsC

Comment: Nice and also different enough for you to post as your own if you wish :)

Comment: Eh, it's not that different. It is a direct modification of yours edited directly on TIO. Posting it separately would have been actual effort.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 140 bytes

```forth
include random.fs
: x 95 random 32 + ;
: f x -rot 0 do cr dup 0 do 2over i j d= >r over r> if begin x 2dup - until nip then emit loop loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU1bDoMwDPvvKbzviYnH0B5o3GWjKXSCFoUy7fZdCpOjxHYS2XgOQ9abNGK0rhtXTeCn0346mUXd8cWt/huoShzRiGnEztgH5NAeHUOv885L/yGGxRv6gZaxSW5hDV7UWyePZTrOsLpgRzg7IwzkQJMNGL2f99bEgZiwEGkcVAFBnsooSVO5hFWCpFQiZ8EmCtmUgk3UuOCKG0z8AQ)

0-indexed

#### Code Explanation

```forth
include random.fs        \ import the random library

\ Generate a random number in range 32 to 126 inclusive
: x                      \ start a new word definition
  95 random              \ generate a random number between 0 and 94
  32 +                   \ add 32
;                        \ end word definition

: f                      \ start a new word definition
  x -rot                 \ generate a random number for the haystack, then move it
  0 do                   \ loop from 0 to h-1 (inclusive)
    cr                   \ output a newline
    dup 0 do             \ loop from 0 to w-1 (inclusive)
      2over i j d=       \ check if this is the needle square
      >r over r>         \ hide result, grab a copy of the haystack char, then grab result back
      if                 \ if it is a needle
        begin            \ begin indefinite loop
          x 2dup -       \ generate a new random number and compare to haystack char
        until            \ only end loop when values differ
        nip              \ drop haystack char
      then               \ end if block
      emit               \ output ascii char for value on top of stack
    loop                 \ end row loop
  loop                   \ end column loop
;                        \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 87 bytes

```c
f(w,h,x,y){x+=y*w;h*=++w;for(y=time(0)%9023;h--;)putchar(h%w?(x--?y+1:y%96)%95+32:10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoQgFADQvadwI3xTwYqJqY90logahckGMUyiszu99ZvV/J38p5QVkrTylJlfpzC5SmgrI0TCdQ@QTXTbApqzXjctWqWQ/4442ymAZWmEU6kxi3rIrO@e9BJtM9Sa412cj3SbnAdOL7LCW3aylQ1HQh9hiUfwVCO5yx8)

Stealing from [@Arnauld answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194361/84844)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/),<s>34</s>   <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 24 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;E=öx)ÎpU*V hW*U+XEg1)òU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=O0U99ngpznBVKlYgaFcqVStYRWcxKfJV&input=OCw2LDIsMg)

5 Bytes saved thanks to @Shaggy.

Inputs are U,V => size , W,X => needle coords 0 indexed

```
 ;E=   // set of printable characters 
     öx) // random permutation 
 Î // => g0  pU*V    repeats U*V times first element of set
           hW*U+XEg1) // overwrite at W,X with 2nd element 
                      òU // split
```

Comment: @Shaggy my first try, the best I can do, any suggestions are implicitly welcome!

Comment: A few quick savings for you [here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=O0U99ngpznBVKlYgaFcqVStYRWcxKfJV&input=OCw2LDIsMg).

Comment: Thanks @Shaggy! The good thing is that I 've understood your improvements, though I'm still far from a good usage of this language, maybe due to my poor experience in JS

Comment: you don't *really* need a JS background to learn Japt.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žQΩIP×žQΩIPǝ¹нô
```

Coordinates are 1-indexed. Outputs as a list of lines.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7Acys9Aw5PhzKOzz2088Lew1v@H9r9P9pUxySWK9pExygWAA) (`»` in the footer joins the list of strings by newlines to pretty-print, feel free to remove it to see the actual output).

**Explanation:**

```python
žQ              # Push all printable ASCII characters
  Ω             # Pop and push a random character
   IP           # Push the first input (rectangle-size), and take its product
     ×          # Repeat the random character that many times as string
      žQΩ       # Push a random character again
         IP     # Push the second input (1-based coordinate), and take its product as well
           ǝ    # Insert the random character at this (0-based) index into the string
            ¹н  # Push the first input again, and only leave its first value (width)
              ô # Split the string into parts of that size
                # (after which the resulting list of strings it output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>130</s> <s>117</s> <s>116</s> <s>109</s>  106 bytes

```c
c[2];f(w,h,x,y){x+=y*w;for(h*=++w;y++<h|*c==c[1];)c[y%2]=time(0)%94+33;for(;h--;)printf(h%w?c+!x--:"\n");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrRCoIwFIDhe59iCcLm2cA0ojqNHsS8kOHaIFcMYw7z2Zf0X378Sqhn7x4pqbbuUNPADZ95ZMsMMpYB9ctTU0qAgBHgar6lklK1@w6ZamNRd3Ky40ArVpwP0DT/H40QyN7euklTU4Sbgt0sxCW/u5zhmjYnY28dZWTJND3xI294zTAjW36YPt6RCrM1/QA)

Saved 13 thanks to @ceilingcat 
Didn't thought using just only time() was enough 
And also didn't thought printf accepted a int pointer as a format string!

Needle is 0 indexed

```c
c[2]; // needle and hay stored in array 
f(w,h,x,y){
 x+=y*w; // sets counter for needle (x no more needed)
 for(
     h*=++w; // while incrementing w for newline sets counter for haystack 
     y++<h  // more than 2 iterations to fill array
     |*c==c[1]; // until they're different 
     )
     c[y%2]=time(0)%94+33; // assign value to array (I've excluded spaces )
 for( ;h--; ) printf(h%w?c+!x--:"\n")
 // output: on h%w =0 => newline 
 //              if  x != 0 => hay
 //              when x=0 => needle 
 //              and continue to finish haystack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 108 bytes

Needle location is 1-indexed

```sh
repeat $2 : $[h=r++?h:RANDOM%95]&&(repeat $1 s+=${(#)$((n=r-$4||++c-$3?h:(n=RANDOM%94)+(n>=h),32+n))};<<<$s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU3RasJAEHy/rxhwK7tcBE3iQ23SUuhrW@hr6UMaL1xATsnZqlW/Pd0osjPM7uwO@xd937Bw37mNq7agFAvQpy87a5/84uP57eX99e5@/jUe8@1khmhLOvJIiDmU3YTy08naekKZRtS5pXKxHB5LL0mW2iByfiiKgqL0YkyDuVaGTNt1hx089jiADZDjwhS6vMjAmWKYpgM0l06NHNVwtV@rMF@fJlcRwQjV8rcKtUN0bpkgtkPfoI1oA@LPd/RutdJoA9qBPGgPOphz/w8)

```sh
repeat $2
  # set hay when row is 0 (shorter than setting it before due to the cost of "(( ))")
  # ": $[  ]" always exits true. "((  ))" would exit false if hay == 0
  : $[hay = row++ ? hay : RANDOM % 95] && (
    # inner loop in (subshell), $str and $col will be empty every time
    repeat $1
      # ${(#)$((x))} expands to the Unicode character at codepoint $x
      str+=${(#)$((offset =
        row - $4 || ++col - $3
        ? hay
        : (offset = RANDOM % 94) + (offset >= hay),
        32 + offset
      ))}
      <<< $str
  )
```

[Proof of correctness by exhaustion](https://tio.run/##bVJRa9swGHz3r7jFmpFqpzSO9xA3zhZoSgddB3sbIQPFVnCKJ3eS/dC6@u3ZZ7uBwiYLgU939@mk78WWpwMXnef5OGo0pcKh1XlzrHWEH@uHm@/fPi4@oZQWe6U0jHqqZK4K7J9xt/5Jqn/GWZX8X/Ww2dzcb04EKdmAxUjBtmVmwvBzmZLlLgj4eXMGG2as475gnOvMTFny@hqG@ZTNiUzIaCZCrldZKaJ5HGoh3PVyuWRWnJznHWqDvP69B2fdr3TaXV1dXi4S5979zZ0T6Dz0eTLWk7ezKN4RMLq/YfMo2XkE@uTX6gatPv5pFfJSGpk3ytj@/uq2eWqbFLas24riKsQk6Tk24xNK8qUVtNo0pUQHxJj1n3BuIojHOfMHLj5kiIVAEEDlZY3b9df7sfZjTVVGjtQFZFGgqWk2soI0Rj4Ta5CsghgTRpEisDEHshW2VPxxGa3EYOF2E6IP4rA/3gDSSVzfDWNKWVXnpLUplKE37G/jqGXfIjZ6l5Ta5AKLxBvKs86nUq0YzJ0Dvd/bvhCnvw), for all combinations of `RANDOM%95` and `RANDOM%94`.