# Reorder a matrix, twice

Tags: code-golf, matrix, linear-algebra

You are given a square \$n \times n\$ matrix \$A\$, and a list (or vector) \$u\$ of length \$n\$ containing the numbers \$1\$ through \$n\$ (or \$0\$ through \$n-1\$). Your task is to reorder the columns **and** rows of the matrix \$A\$ according to the order specified in \$u\$.

That is, you will construct  a matrix \$B\$ where the \$(i,j)\$-th element is the \$(u(i),u(j))\$-th element of \$A\$. You should also output the inverse of this action; that is, the (i,j)-th element of \$A\$ will end up at position \$(u(i),u(j))\$ in a new matrix \$C\$.

For example, given $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 11 &12& 13 \\ 21& 22& 23 \\ 31& 32& 33 \end{bmatrix},\quad u=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$

the output should be $$B = \begin{bmatrix}33 & 31 & 32 \\ 13 & 11 & 12 \\ 23 & 21 & 22 \end{bmatrix},\quad C= \begin{bmatrix}22 & 23 & 21 \\32 & 33 & 31 \\ 12 & 13 & 11 \end{bmatrix}$$

You may take input and output through any of the default I/O methods. You do not have to specify which matrix is \$B\$ or \$C\$, as long as you output both. You may assume \$A\$ only contains positive integers, and you may use 1- or 0-based indexing for \$u\$. You must support matrices up to at least size \$64 \times 64\$.

### Example

```
===== Input =====
A =
 35     1     6    26    19    24
  3    32     7    21    23    25
 31     9     2    22    27    20
  8    28    33    17    10    15
 30     5    34    12    14    16
  4    36    29    13    18    11
u=
  3 5 6 1 4 2

==== Output =====
B = 
  2    27    20    31    22     9
 34    14    16    30    12     5
 29    18    11     4    13    36
  6    19    24    35    26     1
 33    10    15     8    17    28
  7    23    25     3    21    32
C = 
 17    15     8    10    28    33
 13    11     4    18    36    29
 26    24    35    19     1     6
 12    16    30    14     5    34
 21    25     3    23    32     7
 22    20    31    27     9     2
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18091/32352)

Comment: Can we output [without the empty line here](https://tio.run/##FYwxCsMwEAT7vGKKYEinvZNkGT3AD0hpXAS3TmfI85UzHMcyu8z3c51jXP58pWNaf9P7jmNsTqEiMrY/Ni8RKxZkwXLHcWPGhDlWAohosLjAqdOwhjuaUUL3JIXTMzIUv/aQe0gXFLOGtP8B), that is, [like this](https://tio.run/##FYwxCsMwEAT7vGKKYEinvZNlGz0gD0hpXKRPOkOer6zhOJbZZb7v8zPGmffH9PxNryuMsSczDVGJ47bn7NgIk42onSSDhRCRxGwg3BA@49JZiZVMtKCCrkmxMysK5N@65WnphjxbkY4/)? (there is no ambiguity) Or, failing that, use `0` as separator?

Comment: @LuisMendo Sure no problem.

Comment: Is 1-indexing required for this? Can we use 0-indexing and input `u = [2, 0, 1]`?

Comment: @ValueInk See the first sentence, *[...] containing the numbers 1 through n (or 0 through n−1)*

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
t3$)&Gw&St3$)
```

Inputs `u`,  then `A`.

Outputs `B`, then `C` without a separator, as there is no ambiguity.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYwxCsMwEAT7vGKKYEinvZNlGz0gD0hpXKRPOkOer6zhOJbZZb7v8zPGmffH9PxNryuMsSczDVGJ47bn7NgIk42onSSDhRCRxGwg3BA@49JZiZVMtKCCrkmxMysK5N@65WnphjxbkY4/)

#### Explanation

```
t     % Take input u implicitly. Duplicate u
3$)   % Take input A implicitly. Index A with u as row and column indices
&G    % Push the two inputs again: u, A
w     % Swap
&S    % Push indices that would make u sorted. Call that v
t     % Duplicate v
3$)   % Index A with v as row as column indices. Display implcitly
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 42 bytes

```r
function(A,o)list(A[o,o],A[I<-order(o),I])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCoAwDAXQqzgm8B2SrDp09AziINVCQQ3UCt6@urzplZa6oe9aeq5Ys18U4Hzku1KYHb4gzNPQe9n2Qs6YFm6JwniuteSXIolABSYQhSpMIQY1mDF@GT5GMvyLuX0)

Takes `A` as a `matrix` and 1-based indexes `o`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 33 bytes

```matlab
@(A,u){A(u,u) A([~,v]=sort(u),v)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7NCoNgDLt/T5GjQhHT@suHMJ9DPIwxr8KmXsb26q56GIPS0iRNM9@W63bfpy7Lsv2S9LKmrz5ZfaBPho9sY/ecH0uyprKl771Hh4EUqtCiUlRFLRrFVMzGGNZDYeKML2E6HUM476wEUUErsIUWEQZT1FBCDVo6QDgD9XI4j2igDczAGszBQ5KjhBWggt6riALmpi3osgbkL4QL/ZXzf1H2Lw)

Thanks to [Luis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo) for correcting an error and saving several bytes!

Basic indexing works here for both tasks, by defining a vector \$ v \$ equal to the permutation that undoes \$ u \$. That is, if \$ u = ( 3, 1, 2 ) \$ then the first element of \$ v \$ is 2, since 1 is in the second position of \$ u \$. This is accomplished with Octave's [sort](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/sort.html) function.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) with numpy, <s>51</s> 45 bytes

```python
lambda m,p:[m[x][:,x]for x in(p,p.argsort())]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDRboQgEHznKza@qA01B3i2vcQvUdPQnN6ZFNwgTfTrLSx3Ty0Pk8kwM8uCu78vVh2zwcV5sD8Gd9ArWGRT2x/f2nxdNRiOl85029Bd@DZMi4MNZlsgx0q72xqSRVkOh9H@c/UOWsiyrGfqDPEIwiaCJBQfxGsGoCJTkhxvpJJbki7PDFRKUwLIJxMm9yl0vBMjVJQTdCdOhLGDGNBrVE0qdYjEm9BBTKU30iyRmqhViJ6FhRiOzjz3U6GuCavVIDPGwuJBtFhNbjHBMdtb8fgMDuuIbQ45h6vfcWxn68vKjetd41g0HJqSiv/kn9P@LYBXEAyDzxcvUxzFIfrLh7m3vc3L4xc)

*-6 bytes thanks to @xnor*

The function takes two arguments: a `numpy` matrix and a permutation vector having values from \$0\$ to \$n-1\$.

Comment: [45 bytes as lambda](https://tio.run/##bVDRboQgEHznKza@qA01B3i2vcQvUdPQnN6ZFNwgTfTrLSx3Ty0Pk8kwM8uCu78vVh2zwcV5sD8Gd9ArWGRT2x/f2nxdNRiOl85029Bd@DZMi4MNZlsgx0q72xqSRVkOh9H@c/UOWsiyrGfqDPEIwiaCJBQfxGsGoCJTkhxvpJJbki7PDFRKUwLIJxMm9yl0vBMjVJQTdCdOhLGDGNBrVE0qdYjEm9BBTKU30iyRmqhViJ6FhRiOzjz3U6GuCavVIDPGwuJBtFhNbjHBMdtb8fgMDuuIbQ45h6vfcWxn68vKjetd41g0HJqSiv/kn9P@LYBXEAyDzxcvUxzFIfrLh7m3vc3L4xc)

Comment: @xnor Thanks ! I felt that it could be shortened in some way but the idea of using a `for`-loop did not come to my mind.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
ii[[#,#]]&/@{#,Ordering@#}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY6/joJAEMZ7nmLjJlQfkZkBhMJkG2vtCQVRPCn0LoRugw/hG/iEPgI36@E1k5l8f@Z3bcdLd23H/tjO5@3cvx7Pvq4tbNPEa@ct9sOpG/rbl7NTPB90G9fO3g9D99PdTvdVkiQrNZ5r29SWm9i53fHy7WwIR957IhCDZEJkjGcCM3i5hCAMkSmcXqBiWDUlOQzBFOACVIGzv4CREDAbhB4B5/89poLhd7eK6eIuwaXWgzagFPRxpzA5JHtz6SwWdwbRf5WygkoQfahyKAOywBZN8y8)

Input as `f[A][u]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>78</s> <s>73</s> 71 bytes

```
($A,$u=$args)|%{$A[$u]|%{''+$_[$u]}
$u=1..$u.count|%{$u.indexof($_-1)}}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##RVDBbsIwDL3nK3wwkGhZhZOW0QOHfsc0VWgr2yREJ1i0SSXfXp6hiIPT9579bNc//V93PH11@/3IO9rQMFpuPKcNb4@fJ3eeDdy8cnoDWCyeuFWcDfJSFJyK9z4dfrUoFd@Hj@6/31lun8XlPGZjrLUiniQgovOGyAbwAB4mHsEjeIzOeaQ9LVEMrOZYAXuiFSLgkRrGcjJCU@OL5rQphFA9mtaqa@gwFIXlLbdWba0D0Q@66Ly7D7jSvuW0tH5Xt1ypOnYItf4MAj1E7kuXVyPs8bo9nWk2wIVTEieclVuwOeHE3EAxebwA).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ŒJṁ⁸ịⱮ⁹,Ụ¤œị⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU6xDcMwDHtFB2iIrDhtX@gLhscsRR7o6Llb@0LmAt0SZCuQQ@xHVCoFTEiiSNG3cZruZvvzWtfSylK3R/u8W1m5bvN33l9OlMXMUtLIJEwDUwDkgtpnpqRMGphOmLEOGEM8eEwuwnP4vnP@jAZQCAWkdMDfgA4Z2oOAQ7wOvkCjHotr4i64RXI2j47HjxAFUcg/)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
(]/:~"1/:)"_ 1],:/:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYqxCoNAEAX7@4rhCBhB79zdbsEqYJUqvQSRiNjkD/Lrl@UxMDDvarl0B7PTMTDhwVh4vJ5Lu6/Vf1mq9/mNrINXb31K21yw2A0RRBEDFVTRMBNMMUvps59fNo64Rm1/)

- Main verb `]/:~"1/:`

  - The right most `/:` sorts the left arg (matrix) according to the order that would sort the right arg (specified order).  This sorts rows.
  - Now that result get sorted `/:~"1` again according to the order specified `]`.  But this time we're sorting with rank 1, ie, we're sorting each row, which has the effect of sorting columns.
- `],:/:` We apply the above using both the order specified `]` and the *grade up* of the order specified `/:`.  This gives us the 2 results we want.

Comment: Nice! I was thinking about applying sort+transpose twice, but will end up longer.

Comment: `u` is allowed to be 0-based, so sort (`/:`) could be indexing (`{`) with swapped args

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>17 16 15</s> 14 bytes

-1 thanks to @Jonah

```
([{"1{)~(,:/:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZCxasNAEET7/YrBGGwR27ndlU6nA1WBVKnSpgjGxIQ0rlwZ8uvKrC8WQoi7Zd68/VlWh815rptdQk37w8v72@uy/bit9Nb9bnf1uXZLJ8e5ZuS1D1BkWIZOsB5wuGGEKcxhAw8UvIHx5XECCqzAHTpCEzRGEgZ4DzUovxno4QydoBwrUJXrXD/1yTlHEq9Nvk7fFxxxxlXaf7SVPR8RPGCEE4xJIv0eTRYxGCTSIzpgxHgWPCQoRSGoRMtWsURdKxJq/17h6CYSHm0iNTOJ1i23NA9hXMslgP2RJVxbGy4t7CVW1nLvO8QosbPmMNIBlO6WPw)

Comment: Nice! You can get down to 14 with `([{"1{)~(,:/:)`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZCxasNAEET7/YrBGGwR27ndlU6nA1WBVKnSpgjGxIQ0rlwZ8uvKrC8WQoi7Zd68/VlWh815rptdQk37w8v72@uy/bit9Nb9bnf1uXZLJ8e5ZuS1D1BkWIZOsB5wuGGEKcxhAw8UvIHx5XECCqzAHTpCEzRGEgZ4DzUovxno4QydoBwrUJXrXD/1yTlHEq9Nvk7fFxxxxlXaf7SVPR8RPGCEE4xJIv0eTRYxGCTSIzpgxHgWPCQoRSGoRMtWsURdKxJq/17h6CYSHm0iNTOJ1i23NA9hXMslgP2RJVxbGy4t7CVW1nLvO8QosbPmMNIBlO6WPw "J – Try It Online")

Comment: Btw, random question: I noticed you golf (very well) in J, APL and K.  Curious which you prefer overall?  Also I seem to recall you saying you used K professionally, am I remembering that right?

Comment: @Jonah if i must choose one, that would definitely be k (pls ping me in the [k chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90748/the-k-tree) if you wanna know the reasons), but i do enjoy golfing in all array languages. sadly, i'm not one of the lucky few who can have a k-language job

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>77</s> <s>70</s> 68 bytes

```javascript
a=>g=(u,v=[])=>[u.map((i,x)=>u.map(j=>a[i][j],v[i]=x)),v&&g(v,0)[0]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPBjoIwFLzzFc0eDCRdpS0qhtTbfsEemx6qVoNxRUGI2Z93sVM21MjlZfKm03nzytF0ptnW5eX2ea529rGXDyPXBxm3tJNKJ3Kt2umPucRxSe89AjjKtVGlVkdNu77Ke5LQbjI5xB1NE5Vq/TBNY@ubrO21LWsbfwB/JEVkpIoUEXNKnh9DWbjCUdgKKNO0ZxLhkOBgLtHDOY4enzum8GI4TnCA@@LPpdDMgVAEVBgoLEXxmkAEdkWGHjSZRwtoAgk/CkwwL42LGNORLqJWqqe5nt@r9vo9h@mCzGbk19YVKc87e7e7aOOCIi/@cQkbz0ZWsJqFrsBMx44JhhrMDa7Qy8aOhR/qZSPozcfb6r2720WYHnr5OFmeQ3MZ7g5MMd6r4C6orUtg2EsomYYbdMpD2uFAebgXJLB4M5Cf8v9NQpO/izMLXwU02buBXl4vmPzdMpfh60UC1bmpTnZ6qg7xPjZJ3CbPX8j9TNOdtZfvW11ub1/X1pwGAiVqQ7c6KR5/)

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out what `v` was. It's neat how you found a use for non-strict mode silent failure of property assignment to a primitive value, and used that for your recursion base-case.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Prompts for \$u\$ and then \$A\$. Prints \$C\$ next to \$B\$, separated by two spaces

```apl
⌷∘⎕¨⍋¨⍛⍮⍨⍮⍨⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY49DoJAEIV7TvFKKUiYmeXvOCQQG6IUFnoBJVFILEhMvACVrb1HmYvgLJK4xcvu2/m@TNk2UXUqm/02qo@HelfV1azdpZ319tbuocP4mbS/@nhq/9J@WnMY/dyM5bSBgMCBnu8bIhCDJMSGrWOwvwpBGCJh8CcSpEa5lZPEHinYugLsPOORDN4i4ORnsb9Fan1sTQ7OTQvKQDFoGYrNLG7ZwjK1ykHMXNhWoBxE4Rc)

`⎕` prompt for \$u\$; `[3,1,2]`

`⍮⍨` juxtaposition-selfie; `[[3,1,2],[3,1,2]]`

`⍋¨` permutation-inversion of each; `[[2,3,1],[2,3,1]]`
`⍛` then
`⍮⍨` juxtapose with itself `[[[2,3,1],[2,3,1]],[[3,1,2],[3,1,2]]]`

`⌷` reorder
`∘` the value of
`⎕` \$A\$ as inputted
`¨` using each pair as a set of orders, one order per axis

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
Ｅ⟦ηＥη⌕ηκ⟧Ｅθ⪫Ｅθ§§θ§ιμ§ιξ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDNCsIwEITvPsXiKYEIblL/8ORFUBC8hxyKChZr1VKkbx83nQjay9fZnZmkPV3L9vQo6xiPbdV06lA@lb8aShRsq@aceNM6YPgytH9Ujcrvm27XnC@9@vJnVBm6a/2ne50GYxoL9TpG70ee3MxQehiYD7AAr6CKYMRJblDOwrnADjmLnZ0NTpfLECcEbEbOTdG5hAIcWhgWngK5E4pwXVdgh07Oao5OKJc/BZfgXI2DmMNI/qiXuJilUsrFwCHEybv@AA) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Note: Trailing space. Explanation:

```
    η                       Input `u`
   Ｅ                        Map over elements
     ⌕                      Index of
       κ                    Current index in
      η                     Input `u`
  η                         Input `u`
Ｅ⟦      ⟧                   Map over `u` and its inverse
          θ                 Input `A`
         Ｅ                  Map over elements
             θ              Input `A`
            Ｅ               Map over elements
                θ           Input `A`
               §            Indexed by
                  ι         Current vector
                 §          Indexed by
                   μ        Row index
              §             Indexed by
                     ι      Current vector
                    §       Indexed by
                      ξ     Column index
           ⪫                Join with spaces for readability
                            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 213 bytes

```
{a:List<List<Int>>,u:List<Int>->val s=u.size
for(l in List(s){r->List(s){c->a[u[r]][u[c]]}})println(l.joinToString(" "))
for(l in List(s){r->List(s){c->a[u.indexOf(r)][u.indexOf(c)]}})println(l.joinToString(" "))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVjbbtw4En33V1SMBaYFtNuW5PvGBhzv7CJABgEmARaLTD/Qana3YjXVESlfJuP3fd6X@aD5k/mR7KkiKcmXycTYNWy3RB7W9RRZ7MvaVaX5sr1Nr826dcdkarcszYLmdUNuqWmm56qtHDltHRXKarsBMCYNYaG2VM/xaNeq0GT1WjXK6RmVxumFbgQbJa2Ua8qbMa2r1pKS1YPFjHy8HguVI9Voak35qdV0od211obRP@umJmVmVENQpa2ADZnJBs@eN1okee2lpaKeaVrU1ZyKpaoqbRb6mIFL59b2eHub53l6Yp0qLvUNUIBMinq1/Wk7PcqzvV2G/6jrZqYbOBD9cdclfBel/6pbMXZRXmkDiP3U8qv57Vcj834JnY3Fbo4BgjqChVe6cHWTUIuIMJDNc0vEpqiNU6XhjHAMTbu64LCkeGvqdrFksBERO3GIzO///k@aTNga@K7sJcF9VzO0CdazrKKu2pWxYkpTX0smMT60k1RRYIFor2WRX27XuijnpZ4xuDTUToif3nOySjumW8ThuqwqNt@6pi1cFy96xcjrpUZcWOCoHH9MtuCrrvRKGye28ng7KpMxY9vRx@QeAnaeiXdkl3VbIZCVFe/q1oHDsrw0V4iT9j5BpCpcWZu/Cp/EaFj5pHoW7m3XRtxr1wSv1rUtWUKwS2xizxUZfT0I2bln39@REH2jVutKjwMbZPyMTugDP6QpZSnlqTxnlGWUZ/KcU5ZTnk@96wzPke1syq8ZkuxX8KMIlJx4t0MwLgIXX0VVee6lynPqNctz5jV7VecRLqZgRp5zv1qeU7962jF9pW5Br0sONuuXUowZ8ExU5lbyMr@3lbzefksr7Zb1zPo0zmredmiproR9oJon2C14UhbLGFuk8RXvPOcoH0tVbRaMxiPTLWi@wPY16axT1rYrjajXphJLQjnZkM8r3e00YVGLgrTtel03rstqgV0OLIBZIEKlFUPKnzXt7/726/6uT/j3PtnyfMI/fj/1z/cyn@8R8kf7lO1TekSZ7CqUc9DpgKOMoGd7IVl0RCTsyDC1I8hDyg4lKweUgg4euUO0R/kuJzTF/31B7lIOLUec/fRQMtdTag8GpEB4YomZ9NaHsDO5YxAF/WwRbKEj0bnrVbFyqCUxhLWxKlYOtbk3JDjKrsNpT2H2gM1nh@BKdijIA@89x4P55q3rqMku@wU7PgihYoK@Q@@v2LEf9EGxRDvUWTB314cr0DroCykINRC8PfApmIYkr0FyPlRaI/tJZHalVhczhW3DLT3LVryX2MkGgGQxXCxH6pjeYLt/Kf9eG3d6OqY2jPFrQp83Noiw/B/a72FCMmjgbTyUANdYCRNuPNK2F9aVrhVb@DCZYLHRfIbKqldhnUe3Nh4jcu6Az/NSarYBO4fAK1W1GhUhu5hCAcpZjd2O1zbaooghyWPjKQifLxjFkLCXWi4uFE2wFTioZw9mpV1XKM/STTAHbd7VE5wj/IAxPrVHUSuHaMQTCBGfVLR1em8MeP7x5xlPqg/tB@CmU3z60emU7uguEeQadrjKiPjJx7o07@t3YttokzaTpEvCII7nMf59CAdZ4LSX5o@DGuPp0V8Paoynx34lqIN4euz9oP7PAZyIg2/nI@CT6YcA6Yc9OHlGXO@EBVIM/oyMRQR3ovEcNjlNLIvj1k0O9gFzfaVhybqpC9/06ZUvtDDyjEp700vTDUK28o1R7A8n9E5L8D1ax/Ln1oIN5yD3tR6YTCcenWFjurhF2/zlszp@aE973L1sncqyk8B9yBxVfdKSz83WaXwstk6F2p7Y0@ndXdIF/amI/7msPsvI8SC5yZ/Jvvvyx2Sum3JRGjj1/@AynT@1zu@KHixG398Kv0UscvyAUWHaY5mJvirto3pS30b4HrH5k/nL5/Yx5u4ns8k4cBYUHa4I5RIoLfXyAxqX/uTp7zUdW6UIVkCNVLOwx3TWNOr2pVc3IP375haeKenqn3G00LypfX20VjccEwdBIlQW/C10dwORiKlerd1taA2bCJXdHpO4uI3pn8uy0nStpf0z3znc0ZzDDS9gOU3xlJX7ZiBZPHfYk4iVG5K@cSx4IoNXHQtxuvzQOnVRaamAHd4K2S2wHc93Ad3EkyiVgWuxbeQlSH3SS4qbZtgS5U6oZp2FYzSvVYl7DJrRW3@3teMey6FAF4otJBzynqPMVxOb0UkPP1eINk/hQqrXvucwfDXhoMxhXQ/lO3ndyaCZcioK4jDwOxzjeL2BmaPkxYuJWCpMnKzUujsI@Ac14mrsTyMOTq/kdbhP4ZcTPS8bMMO7ze/h@I75qNGl15fC1ZC2eeta3Pz8Ja9H@nst@9Td/MGIj9yNs8ExfuX8fjLQtO4kndEhdeK4GNLLfwttzXVpYWYZPJBintXagnM9kEk4uGk/sKjHNfpTWzYQVzxKUAy6rjDBFncG0YsTz57OZL4oXdNrFPBCVWfNouXt7fsoaTTIB9HmKzXzh@OLzWTg29msJ1@8pocgBVB4U7OZ2OLVy/4iBO9KeMBj67zrD7dWO9l4HumfRflvIXwn9iHZx/ESGXqFja9yq0vgYF9alaZctSvfr4m0C83C@Jum@0B18yQwfhPVb0hwJNbFeBgIH4AuQmTR84@kXuD9rEUwCzSfNmFTMeYiMp6A/fb2rLq@V9Wxoh7xk375pVshkwgMVmB25/GUuvFTvHArfTTv6nca6p7k/7ezX7jPrOyoz9cxBPKW/NeVxVIXl1q@gCBbc9QK1Z0hg1ZRDq/vrKRfWzcJB7lvHEOduFqOiGRMvlr8gfh2QEm57qBX4F4AOY3yu5ak@7I0fglk@9NzcF5zESLNaJ9Gumnq5pjec0T4kIpdeddBdMUfmuHwZYp9sZnc8yGcaeEjTcdoRMe4ysKbMNaFNc0wib886yfTHGP4y/MkGXfIMAnszpjS5Gsa8z0gxrQPMfhLj/C5@1gSa4C0A28dK8z2eiPytF/AAryZGaN3etQhXg/ZUqg56BekbOJQGN5hU747FodT/tx/bBGGczYa@jgGKSSn8PRx1CBjVyRCbh6jIZsp@iHftXEP9uW/)

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 21 bytes

Prompts for input of u followed by a. Outputs b immediately over the top of c with no separator:

```
(a←⎕)[u;u←⎕]⋄a[⍋u;⍋u]
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##JY4xCsJAEEX7nOKXWgiZmWRNyBX0BCHFokSEgIKksBcVQsTGm3iivUj8G5vP7OfNm/XnbrW/@u50WO06f7kcd1N4fbabcH9bEp6Pdlp4zuyWdV/1/7EJw83XYRz6KkYzEZzaxCBQpoXxKwJRiEHZKZStwBRmSQRzOMIZcQdH3HI@HZRtCc1gkV3Py1TkcZn9bGKbooAWdEHWkBRCIKXTsvko09Ft9JXxC1JA5Ac)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 79 bytes

```perl
sub{$[=1;($A,$u)=@_;@$v[@$u]=(1..@$u);map{$x=$_;[map[@$_[@$x]],@$A[@$x]]}$u,$v}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc3BCsIwDIDhe59ilBw2iMO0eAqVzkfYtZah4EDQOaYdg7Fnr53i0UPgI/kh/WW47SK0Jj7DeQZniHOoEEJhbMMWRmcheJNTWSYUfD/1M0wGGnaJ6dikmbxHC9VXCwSEcYksbG2g3exz54iQFJL26BShUqhWakKtUGu/GtPeFyxEP1y7VyYrIyR/LNOTYyez9jFkdobabf3Cv@zwP6M1i28)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12 11</s>  13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

+2 :( to fix cases when B = C

```
ṭþ`œị¥@Ƭị@2,0
```

A dyadic Link accepting a list of lists, `A` (`n` by `n`), on the left and a list of the first `n` integers on the right, `u`, which yields a list of lists of lists, `[B, C]`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY69DQIxDIV7pvAAKWL77oDu9ogi0dCgW4AZKJmBDgZASBQg2OMmCZ@P4un5531xDvtpOrY232/v5@5znh@n12X8XvHRUm6tleJ9ElE0JDGkW7yrq1TEk7ixWTMhYfTWx8YjT07YWigSeWE2VMjJKlPN6M9QCbe8YwKj4cPCUHlc50UNDl611lZoIOJTKUJWfw)**

#### How?

```
ṭþ`œị¥@Ƭị@2,0 - Link: A, u
       Ƭ      - collect up while the results are no longer unique, applying:
     ¥@       -   last two links as a dyad with swapped arguments:
  `           -     use left (u) as both arguments of:
 þ            -       outer product with:
ṭ             -         tack
   œị         -     multi-dimensional index into last result (starting with A)
                ...at the end of the Ƭ-loop we have [A,B,...,C]
                                                 or [A] if A=B=C
                                                 or [A,B] if B=C but A!=B
          2,0 - literal pair [2,0]
         @    - with swapped arguments:
        ị     -   index into (1-based & modular) -> [B,C]
                                                 or [A,A]=[B,C] if A=B=C
                                                 or [B,B]=[B,C] if B=C
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>148</s> 142 bytes

```cpp
#import<queue>
#define q[o[i/z]*z+o[i%z]]
using V=std::vector<int>;int f(V m,V o,V&r,V&R,int z){int i=z*z;for(r=R=V(i);i--;r[i]=m q)R q=m[i];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZTfjppAFMbv5ylOdtMGdMwyA6Iu4EX7AE288MY1jVHczGb54whtg/HZ7TeAFbXbpCQDwznfnPM7ZxjWeT54Xa9Pp0eV5Jkuwl0Zl/GUPW7irUpj2i2yhXqqlr2qj8mnarlk5V6lrzSP9sXm@flHvC4yHaq0mAa40daaU8LnlPH5Z40x48Za2QfzUFHVq4Jtpi0dzaK5pexADQaBXqhllNDOntEuSvASHE@3wSlZFVr9IoroQCQ4SU4uJ48zur6GnHxOI07jO9eEC4cLwYW8dQmXC4@LIRf@MbjxsTuUTG9iTdFBcizjDlawe1EiG1QXQMD1iUtwiQme19AucVcSH8FhykJRctgVuIL4BEb4zTA65yrAGBYMF4EE6hYOmUq6EWAZQuDBgRDCPMHTjQGTaxCBh16QGGMIU9hdXaUpC1E8blrt1LsgCNKnHotw0beyyMuCovqFfYEc7MCWjikFNUyozgwckAAEeMAaNlYQiDFyg0i45PoNpG8aJz00kyTmbQDX1CqGaIBA@HFjJUxdtBB9lYLQ2cbKvgIEskbuGDnWs2bz23ww@QagAfHbhMgsANBI5RnYAzAqaKSizeeafKPWKM8Vj1CxZL0nfCWPKl2/l5uYQpXtCx2vkumVLVmlKp@2JyxdJfE@X61jwiZgK8wJyjXu3xOLcMqIU322yD4wwqEiq35XKNShAM8QvoD6fVUrOpK3VvL2R/JGtqFeZ9i5MKR9XPy0XNtMkwWpXkV9iJfm/YEezAlhF/HDS2pMR3bsMmaGMfsfxk7IDEm76a5TtXmSlUotmw6sbQpitz8J/BfIRseul7VckDUHuFXdfeGazwK2tc6xWjGs3IPcxAzDON28B5fE2rj@6rksakFe0sHN1YGra8Dhwvf2L/7yrAAl1GVD539M539IZxax@oPVcVHqlBzT39Nv)

Thanks to @ceilingcat suggestion to use #import <queue> instead of <vector> which mysteriously brings std::vector

Comment: @ceilingcat now I see that import queue gives me access to vector.. Is it compiler dependant? I'm trying to search information about this but found nothing

Comment: [Tips for golfing in C++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132/tips-for-golfing-in-c/150895#150895)

Answer (score 1):

## q, 26 bytes

```
{Y:iasc y;(x[y;y];x[Y;Y])}
```

`iasc` returns indexes to sort it's argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 91 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$a u=map(\l={{a.[i,j]\\j<-l}\\i<-l})[u,[k\\i<-[0..]&_<-u,j<-u&k<-[0..]|j==i]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBfS8MwFMWf209xwTEU2tI029SxPAz0YeDbHpMgoauaru3G1ihS89WNWW9mIDmc3HN/@VM2lepce9iZpoJW6c7p9ng49bDtd8/dZzxRYFirjreiYcOgMq6TWgpRr9LGCqEvcsdNwvej4XmWyenrKjWJT5jpPmz91IxpKd22Vx69XAIfhk3XWytj3GIwgTWY@OujOlVxtAYWR9FwMy50nsBlEJTFKAUKeUQ3s8mYBTp6WmD2HqvYWWCtmIcsDUBEALYUQUJnfuU@oEehSCIYIjnKPxc94LXpDKvIJcEtrlz0NDwKr0ICHg8jxPqon8b/EvcY3@LR/hAfI9L9lm@Nej@7dPPinr471ery/Ac)

Defines `$ :: {{a}} [Int] -> [{{a}}]` (used with `a = Int`) taking an array of arrays and a list of zero-based indices, returning a list of arrays of arrays containing B and C.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 91 bytes

```python
lambda a,u:[[[a[y][x]for x in t]for y in t]for t in[u,[u.index(i)for i in range(len(u))]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVJda4MwFH33V2S@qOMwTGLVFhz0YYPBHgZ9zHxwbdyEzkobof313U1i60BCOPfc8xEcLubn0MtrW31e983v165hDcaVUqpRl1qd6/ZwZGfW9cy462W@GrqqEWp86vqdPsddYtHOEo5N/63jve7jMUnqug6uO90yo08m7vphNCcwfR701uhdsgoYa7ZmbPasYm386AkJocOx600cfqw3m5B17Z1V3ZeZ3p80C1/Xb@/hvHGziKrnaEajtVtfRZiE7GhWfZhVbaL71ssNjP5lJkLg2sRKyQU4cogcfAmR1QiUhBQoIDiEhFg4iIOmEPTRILVQCVFCSvACPAX3tBQLyAxcgNOZWyyDJPklOFFLcF4TGCiBjKgpCKwTCyg1aYO8yGfp9DKvAxImTedhpawOCZCkdB5TeFAZW8StSh8LpU0oSosVvhCZUjcpfBJlCzha6htZpg3rHEqf3hnnkwV50ZM5mriFy1xxR@OThX9GB4lbr8I@I/1RyfUP)

Takes parameters as a 2D and 1D list and returns a list containing two 2D lists B and C. I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way to do all the for-loops.