# Stack Exchange Answerer

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

Oof! You've been coding the whole day and you even had no time for Stack Exchange!

Now, you just want to rest and answer some questions. You have ***T*** minutes of free time. You enter the site and see ***N*** new questions. To write an answer for each you'll need ***t<sub>i</sub>*** minutes. Of course, as a dedicated reputation gatherer, you want to answer as many questions as you can.

Can you write a program to calculate which questions do you have to answer to write maximum posts in ***T*** minutes?

### Input

First line of input consists `T` minutes you have for answering, and `N`, how many new questions are on the site.
The second line has N numbers: time you need to answer **q<sub>i</sub>** question.

### Output

Write either an array or numbers split with space: indexes of questions(counting from 0 or 1 - what is better for you) you should answer in order to write as many answers as you can. If you can't answer any questions, write nothing or anything to express that it's impossible. If there are several variants, write any.

### Examples

#### Inputs               Possible outputs

`60 5`
`30 5 10 20 3`    `0 1 2 4`, `0 1 3 4` or `1 2 3 4`

`10 5`
`1 9 5 7 2`         `0 2 4` or `0 3 4`

`5 5`
`1 1 1 1 1`         `0 1 2 3 4`

`60 5`
`48 15 20 40 3`  `1 2 4` or `1 3 4`

`5 1`
`10`

`1 0`

And of course it's [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>81</s>, <s>79</s>, 75 bytes

Using the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) `:=`:

```
lambda k,l:[i for j,i in sorted((v,k)for k,v in enumerate(l))if(k:=k-j)>=0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYrLCsIwFET3fsVdJngXqaU@SvMltYtIE0zTPIix4NfHtCCKMMPAORNe6e5dfQ4xK37Ns7C3UYDBGS1nba9B@QgTatAOHj4mORKyoKErNrisWLqnlVEkSWZKtSK25XY/0Y6bIYeoXSKKHBn2NUNoEKoyh9J6oHT38QX2FcJle5zK4Vc2m/vm37EC8hs)

-2 bytes thanks to @JoKing

-4 bytes thanks to @justhalf

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>158</s>, <s>137</s>, <s>136</s>, <s>130</s>, <s>127</s>, <s>117</s>, <s>103</s>, 95 bytes

```
def f(k,l):
 q=[]
 for j,i in sorted((v,k)for k,v in enumerate(l)):k-=j;q+=[i]*(k>=0)
 print(q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RclBCsIwEAXQfU4xy4mOkFqqWIkXCVkITTBNTdsYC54@pl0o/OEz70@f9BhDnXNnLFj0NPCWwSyVZmDHCD05cAFeY0ymQ1zI85U9LSub8H6aeE8GB85bf5D9dd5L5fQO/U0KzmCKLiScebZ4EqRqQdAQVKWO5WrNmcXyqYrgsk3nsmzabPjPD4Xm@Qs)

-21 bytes thanks to @79037662 by limiting indentation to 1-space.

-14 bytes thanks to @ mypetlion

-8 bytes thanks to @justhalf

Both solutions ignore `N` parameter.

Comment: One easy golf is to use only a single space for the indents: https://tio.run/##TYxNCsIwFIT3OcVbJvgoqaWKxZykZBFJgmmb9C9Ci3j2GrtQYYZhvoEZ1njvQ7Ft2liwtMWOVQRG9KKWyAnYfgKHDbgAcz9Fo@nTVc0/NuHhzaSioR17ZS4aP1OGrVlFp/xNK1iqpc7l5xb8QTQpnAV/FW01ZmoYTNDUMQLD5EKkI9ssPXGsC45QIuQpjsmFZMTS1Ooc4bJP57TstNzhT1/IJdve

Comment: Wouldn't that be -7 bytes?

Comment: @game0ver Oh, nvm...you originally had -1 total in the message. I only counted -1 byte per indent level instead of -3.

Comment: You can replace `dict(enumerate(l)).items()` with just `enumerate(l)` to save 14 bytes. You're converting a `list` of `tuple`s to a `dict`, then iterating over the `dict_item`s, and converting each one back to a tuple, which is pretty roundabout.

Comment: @mypetlion Good point, thanks!

Comment: @JoKing Thank you very much, that's better now!

Comment: In the Python 3 answer, why is the function only taking two arguments instead of 3?

Comment: @justhalf Simply because it doesn't need the 3rd parameter and as per the [rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/12442#12442) it can be omitted. Actually almost none of the answers provided use the 3rd parameter.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that. Here's [-5 bytes](https://tio.run/##RclBDoIwEAXQfU8xyw7MokjQiPYkhIUJbSylBWol8fS1sNDkT37m/eUTn7OvUxqUBs0tTdgycFSsUhADPQcYyYDx8JpDVAPnG1nc2dK2s/Jvp8IjKj4htq6U420tZWf6gru7tMhgCcZHvmLS/CyoqwVBQ1DlOuWre2Sa56@rCK7HdMnLoc2B//xQ9Ji@) for you by modifying the if into array multiplication :)

Comment: @justhalf Thanks! That's a cool trick!

Comment: Another [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##RclBCsIwEAXQfU4xy4mOkFqqWIkXCVkITTBNTdsYC54@pl0o/OEz70@f9BhDnXNnLFj0NPCWwSyVZmDHCD05cAFeY0ymQ1zI85U9LSub8H6aeE8GB85bf5D9dd5L5fQO/U0KzmCKLiScebZ4EqRqQdAQVKWO5WrNmcXyqYrgsk3nsmzabPjPD4Xm@Qs) by modifying `k` instead of `m`. This trick can be applied to the Python 3.8 solution, too. Reducing it by 4 bytes by removing `m`.

Comment: [Python 3.8 75 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYrbCsIwEETf/Yp9zMIKqaFeCvFHah8qTTBNm4Y0Fvz6mBZEEWYYOGf8Kz4mJ84@JC1vaWjHe9eCpaGqDegpQE8GjIN5ClF1jC1kccWWlhUr9xxVaKNiA6LRzFbS7nu8St4kH4yLTLMjp1pwgpKgyHPIFQ3i7uMzrAuCy/Y45cOvLDf3zb/jGaQ3)

Comment: @justhalf That's brilliant, never crossed my mind to modify `k` instead :) Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>9</s> <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ā<æʒ¹sèO@}éθ
```

Takes the inputs in the order: \$q_i\$, \$N\$ (which is mostly ignored, see explanation below), \$T\$.
Uses 0-based indexing.

+4 bytes as bug-fix for test case `[1,1,1,1,1]` resulting in `[0,0,0,0,0]` instead of `[0,1,2,3,4]` (and now switched from 0-based to 1-based indexing).
-1 byte thanks to *@Grimmy* (and back to 0-based indexing again).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9vc2FiaWX//8SBPMOmypLCuXPDqE9AfcOpzrj//1sxLDksNSw3LDJdCjUKMTA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgpFPpcmi3DpeSf2kJUAQoYJ9waGWRS@j/I402h5edmnRoXXFE8eEV/g61h1ee2/Ff59A2e82Y/9HR0YY6ljqmOuY6RrE6CqY6CoYGQDo62tgAKGhooGNkoGMcC2SaQYQNdaAQJGYKEQLKGELZIJZBbCwA) or [get all possible outputs for the test cases instead of just one](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgpFPpcmi3DpeSf2kJUAQoYJ9waGWRS@j/I402h5edmnRoXXFE8eEV/g61h1fqHVqYXntux3@dQ9vsNWP@R0dHG@pY6pjqmOsYxeoomOooGBoA6ehoYwOgoKGBjpGBjnEskGkGETbUgUKQmClECChjCGWDWAaxsQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
             # Take the (implicit) input-list qi
ā            # and push a list in the range [1, list-length] without popping the input itself
 <           # Decrease each by 1 to make it 0-based: [0, list-length)
  æ          # Get the powerset of this list of indices
             #  i.e. [0,1,2] → [[],[0],[1],[0,1],[2],[0,2],[1,2],[0,1,2]]
   ʒ         # Filter this list of lists by:
    ¹        #  Push the first input-list qi again
     s       #  Swap to put the current list of the filter at the top of the stack
      è      #  Index each into the list qi
       O     #  Sum these values
        @    #  Check if the (implicit) input-integer is >= this sum
             #  (The very first iteration it will use the second input, which is the length N;
             #   every other iteration it will use the third input, which is the total time T.
             #   Since the very first inner list of the powerset will be the empty list,
             #   this causes no problems; which is how we ignore the mandatory length N input)
         }é  # After the filter: sort all remaining inner lists by length
           θ # Pop and leave the last one, which is (one of) the list(s) with the most items
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: You can go back to 0-based indexing by using `.ā` instead of `āø`.

Comment: [Here's a 12](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9vc2FiaWX//8SBPMOmypLCuXPDqE9AfcOpzrj//1sxLDksNSw3LDJdCjUKMTA)

Comment: @Grimmy Thanks! And I had no idea we had the builtin `.ā`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt),   <s>22</s> <s>21</s> <s>16</s>   15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ð à ñÊÔæÈxgU <V
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8CDgIPHK1ObIeGdVIDxW&input=WzQ4LCAxNSwgMjAsIDQwLCAzXQo2MAo1)

```
ð à                 combinations of indexes of 1st input
    ñÊÔ             sorted by length and reversed
       æ            get first element returning true when passed throug...
        ÈxgU        elements of input at X indexes reduced by addition
               <V   less than 2nd input
```

Takes input as [times...], time , amount

Saved 1 stealing from @Shaggy ÈxgU

Comment: Well, damn! Wrote my solution up hours ago but got distracted by work and only now, after posting it, do I see this, which can be golfed down to my exact solution. Sorry. One of these days I'll learn to reload before posting!

Comment: Your sorting method can be golfed to `ñÊ` but isn't actually necessary as `à` sorts by descending length. And `r+` can be just `x`.

Comment: I regolfed a bit by myself to 16.. You still beaten me @Shaggy, thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Shaggy it seems like à doesn't sort by length 
 https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVE&code=8CDgIA&input=WzQ4LCAxNSwgMjAsIDQwLCAzXQo2MA

Comment: :o Crap! You're right! Where did I get the idea that it does?!

Comment: I supposed it too! But when I tested with [48, 15, 20, 40, 3]
60 ... I realized that was something wrong

Comment: Ah, I think I might have been thinking of `ã`, which sorts by *ascending* length.

Comment: @Embodiment of Ignorance it is valid too because we don't have to maximize the time, it was specified in the comments.

Comment: Not that it matters, but the length input \$N\$ is mandatory for all answers (even if you ignore it..). If I understand Japt correctly, you can just input it at the end and not use it, since you use \$U\$ and \$V\$ explicitly in Japt programs anyway, so it won't change the code in any way.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen you are right, sorry forgot to add 3rd input, anyway it won't change the code like you said, I fix now

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>117</s> <s>113</s> <s>110</s> <s>105</s> <s>85</s> <s>71</s> 63 bytes

*(-3 thanks to Ver Nick says Reinstate Monica)*

*(-20 thanks to Arnauld)*

*(-14 thanks to Shaggy)*

*(-8 thanks to tsh)*

```javascript
a=>g=t=>(a[y=a.indexOf(i=Math.min(...a))]=t)<i?[]:[y,...g(t-i)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcpNCoMwEIbhfU8yA2OIiv2jY09QeoCQxWDVRqyWGqSePg20qyLf7n2@TmaZqpd7@mTeh4aDcNmy5xLELCzKDbf6fW3A8UX8XT3cAEopQbTs8eTOxh7NQjG14BOHNlTjMI19rfqxhQZMrqmgVFOmKbcIW424@bukdIifHWXR01X/LXqxwvrbwwc)

Could probably be golfed some more...a function which takes input in three arguments: time, number of questions (not actually used), and an array of question times.

It will repeatedly find the smallest element in the array, and set it to the time available, removing it from the possibilities for the next iteration. It puts the index of the value into the output array.

Thanks to everyone who's contributed to golfing this answer...54 bytes shorter than the original!

Comment: You can replace `true` with `1`

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks! I forgot you could put variable assignments as arguments like that...

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcpNCsIwEIbhvSeZgWlIW@ofTj2BeICQRahtjdRU0lDs6WNAV1K@3ft8DzObqfH2FbJ5HzuOhuueIZBnpZFrMGphI6y7te9rB5YvJtzF0zoQQhhEzQFP9uyPPYTMkkrV06IxNqObxqEVw9hDB6qUVFEuqZBUaoStRNz8XXI6pM@OiuT5qv@WvFph@e3xAw). On my phone so can probably be golfed a bit further.

Comment: Maybe [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcpNCoMwEIbhfU8yA2OIiv2jY09QeoCQxWDVRqyWGqSePg20qyLf7n2@TmaZqpd7@mTeh4aDcNmy5xLELCzKDbf6fW3A8UX8XT3cAEopQbTs8eTOxh7NQjG14BOHNlTjMI19rfqxhQZMrqmgVFOmKbcIW424@bukdIifHWXR01X/LXqxwvrbwwc)? I'm not sure if this is correct (since previous comments does not suggest this with no reason)

Comment: Good shout, @tsh, completely missed that.

Answer (score 5):

## [dzaima/APL](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```apl
+\∘<⍛≤+/⍛↑⍋⍤⊣
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OApHbMo44ZNo96Zz/qXKKtD6LbJj7q7X7Uu@RR12KQWqAaYwMFUwVDAwUjAwVjhTQFMwMuiLihgiVQwlzBSAEI0oAq4OIwCBZXMIWKa@gYGmgqQAGSuLqurq46ml50NYYgB8AINAhW9x8A)

```apl
+\∘<⍛≤+/⍛↑⍋⍤⊣  train; left arg = ⍺ = t, right arg = ⍵ = T
     ≤         ⍺ <= ⍵
    ⍛          with ⍺ modified to
   <             sorted
+\∘              and then, cumulative sum
               so, cumulativeSum(sort(q)) ≤ T

          ⍋    the indices required for sorting
           ⍤⊣  applied on ⍺
               so, the output, sorted by question time, if T=∞

         ↑     take first ⍺ elements from ⍵ (⍺ is `+\∘<⍛≤`, ⍵ is `⍋⍤⊣`)
      +/⍛        but summing ⍺ first
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṢÄ>¬TịỤ{
```

A dyadic Link accepting the question times on the left and the total time on the right which yields the 1-indexed indices.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//4bmiw4Q@wqxU4buL4buke//Dp8WS4bmY//9bMSwgOSwgNSwgNywgMl3/MTA)** (footer calls the Link and prints a formatted version of its output.)

(If we *must* take the number of questions, [this works as full program](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//4bmiw4Q@wqxU4buL4buke//Dp8WS4bmY//9bMSwgOSwgNSwgNywgMl3/MTD/NQ) accepting: question times; total time; number of questions.)

#### How?

```
ṢÄ>¬TịỤ{ - Link: ts; T        e.g. [1, 9, 5, 7, 2]; 10
Ṣ        - sort ts                 [1, 2, 5, 7, 9]
 Ä       - cumulative sums         [1, 3, 8,15,24]
  >      - greater than (T)?       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
   ¬     - logical NOT             [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
    T    - truthy indices          [1, 2, 3]
       { - use left argument:
      Ụ  -   indices by value      [1, 5, 3, 4, 2]   (i.e index 4 has 2nd largest value)
     ị   - index into              [1, 5, 3]
```

---

Alternative 8:

```
ỤṁṢÄ>Ðḟɗ - indices-by-value moulded-like (cumulative-sums of sorted(ts) if not greater than T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//4buk4bmB4bmiw4Q@w5DhuJ/Jl//Dp8WS4bmY//9bMSwgOSwgNSwgNywgMl3/MTA)

Comment: Does Jelly have a single byte operator for `<=`, which would allow you to skip the `NOT`?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Shame. It looks like some solutions are assuming that the result must be *strictly* `<T` rather than `<=T` so it might be worth asking for clarification on that.

Comment: @tsh Ah yeah, that's a bug, I should use `T` not `M` (since if no cumulative sums are not greater than the right argument the zeros will be the maximal values. `T` will instead get truthy indices, so non-zeros). Thanks for spotting that. (FWIW the alternative 8 byte solution works as-is)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <strike>44</strike> 41 bytes

```r
function(m,t)order(t)[cumsum(sort(t))<=m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYnLCoAgFET3fYXLe@EuNLEI8kuilSW0UMHH95tZEMwwzDmxWqarLd7kK3hwlDHE44yQcTPFpeIghZjbxVW7vVqYOBmQnJgiJtqMrRJxsCAeI4gt3c1Ndaxe@uejgmO9AQ)

Takes input as Time, times.
Returns numeric() for empty output.

Order the times, take cumulative sum and then select the times where the cumulative sum is less than or equal to total time.

-1 in the end to get 0-index

-1 byte thanks to Giuseppe
-2 bytes since 0-index is no longer needed

Comment: The OP seems to indicate 0 or 1 indexing doesn’t matter.

Comment: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYlJCoAwEATvviLHGRgho6gI5iXiKRrwkASyvD/GBYRumq4KxQhVTHY6nd6BpYQ@7EeAhKvONmYL0YdULy7Kbi0XA6MkDb0kMZDgOl1tj9gY4NswiflxU1UPHl7656MssVw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Assumes `0` is not a valid unit of time.

```
ð à ñÊfÈxgU §V
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=8CDgIPHKZsh4Z1Ugp1Y&input=WzMwLDUsMTAsMjAsM10KNjA)

```
ð à ñÊfÈxgU §V     :Implicit input of array U=q and integer V=T
ð                  :0-based indices of U
  à                :Combinations, which, fortunately, includes the empty array, covering the last test case.
    ñ              :Sort by
     Ê             :  Length
      f            :Filter
       È           :By passing each throughout a function
        x          :  Reduce by addition
         gU        :    After indexing each back in to U
            §V     :  Less than or equal to V?
                   :Implicit output of last element
```

---

Or, if we *have* to take `N` as input (or `0` *is* a valid unit of time).

```
o à ñÊfÈxgV §W
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=byDgIPHKZsh4Z1Ygp1c&input=NQpbMzAsNSwxMCwyMCwzXQo2MA)

Where `U=N`, `V=q`, `W=T`, `o` creates the range `[0,U)` and everything else is as above.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>68 64 60 59</s>  58 bytes

```ruby
->t,q{q.map.with_index.sort.reject{|x,|0>t-=x}.map &:last}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165Ep7C6UC83sUCvPLMkIz4zLyW1Qq84v6hEryg1KzW5pLqmQqfGwK5E17aiFqRMQc0qJ7G4pPZ/gUJatJmBTrSxgY6CqY6CIZAyAmLj2FgukBSQH22oo2AJljQHykHFTcHCCIQkbBAb@x8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 133 bytes

```
func[t b][s: 0 sort collect[foreach n sort collect[repeat i length? b[keep/only
reduce[b/:i i]]][if(u: s + n/1)<= t[s: u keep n/2]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc3BDoIwEATQO18xR40HCgSNROM/eN3sAcpWG5tCSjn49RUSjSFze7ObCdKnu/TEmWmQzOw1RXRMUwOFaQgRenBOdCQzBGn1E37LQUZpIyyc@Ed83tDRS2TMB@/eWZB@1kJd3lhYZiZrdnODCQf4vNhfrojr0oz1ZaFyueE0BusjDI4KVCnUKBRKhYqzX7MAFTgv1Qnln@tVv9mq4vQB)

1-indexed. Ignores `N`

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES10),  <s>78</s>  75 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Neil*

Takes input as `(T)(list)`. [Ignores `N`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12442/58563).

```javascript
t=>a=>a.map((...x)=>x).sort(([a],[b])=>a-b).flatMap(([v,i])=>(t-=v)<0?[]:i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYpBDoIwEEX3nmQmGSYFgkZj8QSeoOliQDAYpAQawu1rMW6MMf@v3nsPWWSup270yeBuTWh18LqUeH7KCMDMK@pyRZ7d5AGMWDKVjUiSCrntxV@3zizUbRR8ohc8q4uxpw5D7YbZ9Q337g4t7BWCyRUVlCrKFOUWcfedpFuS0jE2B8p@ffHWn/3RKvLwAg)

Comment: +1 for outgolfing me by 27 bytes...never would have thought of anything like this!

Comment: -3 bytes: `map((...x)=>x)`

Comment: @Neil Nice one! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 44 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔ＥＮ⟦Ｎι⟧ηＷ∧η¬‹θ§⌊η⁰«≔⌊ηι≧⁻§ι⁰θ≔Φη⁻⌕ηιλη⟦Ｉ⊟ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU5NC4JAED3rr5jjLBhYEBGdJAiCiugqHiylHVhXc3criH77NmZSNIeBN2/ex0nm7anOlfdr3Ti7c9WxbPEiFmFiDJ01bvMGfykRQfqHKeMlWXKTpErARBcoI9jVFjelMXiJILFrXZR33JKmylUoWRGLbuARBkPUD0lsF3B2Tx3oLG3HO/P1os4igq7r4LAiZbkTh79/GfdViP@U@LQM9i1pi@kyNxb3dYMkRMb3p/fjGKYwhjnvGUz86Kpe) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `T`.

```
ＥＮ⟦Ｎι⟧η
```

Input `N` and make a list of `N` questions with their original index.

```
Ｗ∧η¬‹θ§⌊η⁰«
```

Loop until there are no more questions that can be answered in the remaining time.

```
≔⌊ηι
```

Get the shortest question and its original index.

```
≧⁻§ι⁰θ
```

Subtract the question's time from the time remaining.

```
≔Φη⁻⌕ηιλη
```

Remove the question from the list of questions.

```
⟦Ｉ⊟ι
```

Print the question's original index.

Comment: You have 3000 posts by now, congrats :)

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica wow, I'm actually first at something ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes

recursive solution, generating line separated console output

```python
def f(T,L):
 if L:M=min(L);I=L.index(M);L[I]=T;T<M or(print(I),f(T-M,L))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcvBCoMwDAbgu0@Rmw20o7VzYzofQGhv3sSblvWwKuJhe/ouOESF/ATyf5m@y2sMOsZ@cOBYww0WCXgHprDV2wdmsKwrc/GhHz7MYmnauquasnlaGGc2zT4srEZOr8LSM8b/KRVCKEqKiWM3yVstOeQcFK2MojtMdpltkupWcXis9k70xPTG8lXtc1LXo5KnKj9UHcYf)

```python
def f(T,L):
 if L:            # do nothing if input is empty
  M=min(L)
  I=L.index(M)
  L[I]=T          # set found list item to remaining time (item will be ignored next iteration)
  T<M or(print(I),f(T-M,L))   # if the found question can be answered in the given time output and find next
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 16 bytes

```
(>:+/\@/:~)#/:@]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NeystPVjHPSt6jSV9a0cYv9rcqUmZ@QrmBkopCkYGyiYKhgaKBgZKBhDhA1BwoYKlkBxcwUjiJgpWAgKkXSbWCgYmoL0msC1g5UaQI0CstXV/wMA)

Attempt at an explanation:

```
>:                create mask of left arg greater than or equal to...
  +/\@/:~         cummulative sum of sorted right arg
         #        copy where true
          /:@]    from permutation that sorts right arg
```

Comment: any explanation?

Comment: @Varad Mahashabde: Here is an attempt. If you need more context please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

## **C++11, <s>293</s> <s>[221](https://localhost)</s> [219](https://localhost) bytes**

Here to decimate the competition I am not.

Notes :

1. g++ allows for variable-sized arrays. It saves bytes, so that what I did.
2. the range-based for loops needs a reference to write correctly?!

```c++
#include<iostream>
void f(int t,int c,int*a){int m,i;int y[c];for(int&b:y)b=0;for(;;){for(m=-1;y[++m]&m<c;);for(i=-1;++i<c;)if(a[m]>=a[i]&!y[i])m=i;if(t>=a[m]&!y[m]){y[m]=1;t-=a[m];}else break;}for(i=-1;++i<c;)if(y[i])std::cout<<i<<' ';}
```

Expanded version :

```c++
#include <iostream>

void AnswerMostOfTheQuestions(int time_left, int question_count, int answer_times[]) {
  int minimum_term;
  bool is_answered[question_count];
  for(bool& b : is_answered) 
    b = 0 ; // No questions have been answered
  while (1) {
    // Find the first unanswered question
    for (minimum_term = 0; is_answered[minimum_term] and minimum_term < question_count; ++minimum_term);
    // Find unanswered question which takes least time to answer
    for (int i = 0; i < question_count; ++i) 
      if(answer_times[minimum_term] >= answer_times[i] && ! is_answered[i]) 
        minimum_term = i;
    if (time_left >= answer_times[minimum_term] &&  not is_answered[minimum_term]) {
      // Answer question (which consumes time)
      is_answered[minimum_term] = true;
      time_left -= answer_times[minimum_term];
     } 
    else break;
  }
  // Print index of every answered question 
  // 'cause returning them is a waste of bytes to implement
  // Just echo it to a file or something
  for (int i = 0; i < question_count; ++i) 
    if(is_answered[i]) 
      std::cout<<i<<' ';
}

int main(int c, char** v) {
  int question_count = atoi(v[2]), free_time = atoi(v[1]);
  int answer_times[question_count];
  for (int i = 0; i < question_count; ++i)
    answer_times[i] = atoi(v[i+3]);
  // Run solution
  AnswerMostOfTheQuestions(free_time, question_count, answer_times);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9ha4MwEIa/@ytuDFqjlmrLNmi0P2JfRUq0cTtmkk5jSxF/e5aksNGyL2@4J@@9d9ecTqumY/LDmGeUTTceeY5q0D1nYh@cFR6hDVFq0InTxmnEyOQKkSCtlergWjYVbVUfumpR766kLlIPKCWTe0Wxyui1jGNRLUTeUOJ/0dE4RgewDVkpqn3BSqwWT1erRBRILdcOCg9FRSanRUb1ylM6827gUNuFv@j8T6pPGvRxt2vUqPMc83wJSzoHgb@BoQxvl0HzyfoogjOBKQBw8Hvkg0YlD7bVlgUwrTA8l5uKJND2nB80Cv7Hs4rQW2sETA4X3nvDYB2SXxwv7yMrZ7dLg98BrS@l9skfJlOw9xBrhbtYe9nfbIy3t@nrNbyPEgbVjS7BDQh/d00ekpO7QNs/B8aY7ca8miw1m9Tpi3kz2/QH)

Comment: Welcome to CG&CC! I can't really help you golf this program, as I am not a C++ golfer, but I suggest you to look at [tips for golfing in C++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132/tips-for-golfing-in-c). Additionally, submissions don't have to be full programs, they can be functions taking input and outputting through their return value, which may or may not save bytes in this case.

Comment: Also, `while(1)` can be `for(;;)`. I suggest adding a [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##TY9BboMwEEX3PQVVJWInWAKxY@xcBLEwjtOMYuMInFQW4uzUJo3S3fz5b/Q06nZjysjhe12/cFDmftIc3eRHLe3xAwefWYkDSYMq1EWO@/2Dzil6Ib1D8mirjhZYWOidM1loFas7OLuRbLlvAu1FCT8XNJpUdE6NFTWE1kYwzy1XcDhYup1gLHBbIMUz@RPYjh5fMuxonn@GFuMxtQIhYp79B8t3Pz8logLPxJuBRZtJZ3388QrL01smL6tf5pBEkz81jXJ3zzlyvst2sKzrLw "C++ (clang) – Try It Online") link for future submissions

Comment: `for(i=3;i<c;++i)` can be golfed to `for(i=2;++i<c;)` saving a byte.

Comment: `if(t-atoi(v[m])>=0&&!y[i-3])` can be golfed to `if(t>=atoi(v[m])&&!y[i-3])` saving 2 bytes.

Comment: @Noodle9 Thanks for the tip! the second one was obvious tho 

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Thanks for the tips! i might actually contribute to the link

Comment: np :-) Also think you can golf `bool y[c];for(bool&b:y)b=0;` to `int y[c];for(int&b:y)b=0;` saving 2 bytes.

Comment: @Noodle9 Really torn between the neatness of bools vs the golf.Gotta go with the golf tho :-)

Comment: [190 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVDdboIwFL73KU5cZlqoETXbEgvzHXZLCMFS5klocVA0RH32rpVsRm/OaU@/n/NVHA5zURf629pjgyVUBLUBw3wVvgYFPfs2JFqewJ1SkRHKFENeNueqaYlKIj6kKpupWHAVhpT7KSaC43zOqUoK9xgXKWaXwZWt2iC/nvZYS2Ji/3bx7G20GVIzv4GZypLlKMPDEJ0s9czZLM93PdYGdX5o3SoVmb6WMGVI@dW@oBZ1X8pYdKascfc58RlUgZqMYUDsizYI4EjhPAEfBX562RlsdC6a3l0TKEyD5JiuMsqgaqXMDSp5ny8zykdqAIXuTrK9ATqH@PudR8nMw10OuO2ADhdx1@InZw4uJnVQeJB1me/eGK5H98UCvnoNXVP3XsEbkP9d2ZMyexB0/Ku165V9t8vIriJf3@yHXUe/ "C++ (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
↑#≤²∫O¹ηÖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f6/aoqfH/o7aJyo86lxza9Khjtf@hnee2H572////aA0zA51oYwMdUx1DAx0jAx3jWE0dDSAz2lDHEihormMEEjAF8aEQxAdpMrHQMTQFaTGB6gIpMgBr14mO1YwFAA) Outputs an empty list if no solution is possible.